# Revisiting the "Hot Network Questions" feature, what are our shared goals for having it?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

### Thanks for your input here and elsewhere on Meta.

Please see the results of this discussion on the update post:
[Updating the Hot Network Questions List - now with a bit more network and a little less "hotness"!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325060/updating-the-hot-network-questions-list-now-with-a-bit-more-network-and-a-litt)

---

Some things happened yesterday that caused a need for us to (quickly) remove a site's eligibility to contribute to the [list of hot network questions](https://stackexchange.com). For those of you not familiar with what we've come to call the 'HNQ' list, please visit the link; the list of questions shown as 'hot' on stackexchange.com are displayed in the sidebar of *most* Stack Exchange sites. Here's an idea of what it looks like:

[image: Screen shot of hot network questions in the sidebar]

It's a list of titles, with their origins vaguely identifiable by the presence of the 'favicon' element that identifies each site. We're *extremely* proud of the quality of content that can be found on every single site in our network. The *titles*, however, when shown out of context, can be problematic. Anything out of context can be problematic.

This isn't a new problem. We've dealt with trigger words in titles that occur naturally *through good-faith questions* on sites like Parenting, Gaming, Christianity, Islam and more. While we probably deserve some egg on our face for relying on regular expressions as a go-to quick fix, *they've been sufficient* for ensuring trigger words and *overt* clickbait was kept out of the list for the most part.

Then we launched a site that tended to have 3-4 hot questions asked each *day* (by any way one could conceivably measure velocity and good reception). The titles of these questions, out of context, are just *too* likely to be inappropriate on our professional and academic sites, so we took the site out of the contributing list. Still with me? Thank you, because there's no way to open this discussion without background.

This is one [of many times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hot-questions) we've talked about problems with hot network questions. This isn't a new problem. What escalated the problem is that we had to take an entire *site* out of the mix, which isn't ideal, and I'll explain why.

#### What goals do we have for the hot question list?

1. They help with discovery. User interviews continue to reveal that folks simply *don't* often discover just how big of a resource we've become collectively. The list boosts engagement in quite a few ways (we'll admit some of them aren't optimal)
2. They often remind communities to have discussions about scope. If folks see a clear demand for certain kinds of questions, it's worth revisiting conversations about how valuable finding ways to meet those needs might be.
3. Hot questions are *extremely* great fodder for evangelists, the kinds of people that reach thousands of folks that are likely to identify with the way we do Q&A.
4. Let's face it, they're a jackpot and a curse. A little patch of chaos that grows pumpkins and poison ivy - just usually more pumpkins.

#### What's broken?

The list of questions is generated through a *very* expensive query, cached, and refreshed on a set schedule. Giving moderators or even community managers the ability to 'evict' a problematic title while keeping the system in check with what we consider performant and sane are .. mutually-exclusive goals.

Now that we have gotten to the point where we've gone from saying "Let's ignore titles with these words.." to "Let's ignore sites with these titles..", we're seeing a pattern of scale that starts to suck if you think about it protractedly.

#### What do we need from you?

We want some ideas on ways we can continue to meet our goals of getting the right sites in front of the right people who are likely to appreciate them and participate.

Automatic selection simply *will not scale* if we continue to push the limits of subjective topic spaces, and we need to continue to do that for the network to grow and remain relevant to the issues folks want to use our software creatively to solve.

#### We don't expect to solve this problem in one post right away.

Let's say we agree to take out the hot network questions entirely. *But*, we want something else in its place that continues to pull in some of the benefits, without being such a mindless pain in the neck.

In order to find out what that could look like, we need to consolidate what *we* want out of it. And that could be "Just turn the darn thing off and be done with it", or "I found my favorite site through that list, you gotta preserve that somehow!" -- all of this input at this stage will be equally good.

Suffice to say, the HNQ (as we know it) is now looking at numbered days, but that number is probably kind of high because it's going to take some work to figure out what voids would be worth filling if we yanked it as we know it now.

So, let's talk about it. And, if this seems like it's a continuation of a conversation, it is, from the moderator chat room. Even though the scope of the discussion is still rough, I wanted to get it out 'in sunlight' early, this isn't something to be settled in an all-mod room.

Thanks for your time, we look forward to finally (at least committing) to settle on something we can all like a bit more than what we've currently got.

And in the spirit of causing tons of people to flood into a single discussion, I'm going to feature this; I just can't help it.

Comment: You are aware that by doing this you killed off some 75% of the site's traffic, yes?

Comment: Can you please respond to [the relevant meta question on the site in question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/what-caused-this-site-to-be-excluded-from-hot-network-questions), with what exactly those "things" were?

Comment: *"the HNQ (as we know it) is now looking at numbered days, but that number is probably kind of high"* You mean, 42-56 days?

Comment: Unrelated, but perhaps we should allow Meta Stack Exchange to be placed in the HNQ list. This can draw attention to important discussions here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the performance issue. Can't you query for more results than you intend to use in the HNQ and then apply the manual filter in a second step without executing the expensive query again?

Comment: I don't understand the performance issue either. [Here's a query that runs the HNQ algorithm](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/912736/hnq-algorithm) (the version of it I could find on MSE, anyway). It's expensive, aye. What's _not_ expensive is adding a `WHERE Posts.IneligibleForHNQ = FALSE`.

Comment: [Filter "Hot Network Questions" by excluding sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225297) - 2 of the top 10 [tag:hot-questions] questions ask for this (and half of the 10 aren't even feature requests). Enough said.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog That's what Featured is for?

Comment: @Dukeling Important community discussions that the SE team may not have chosen to feature. Generally they only feature official posts.

Comment: I love titles that sound wacky when they're out of context. Promoting questions because they attract controversy ... not so much.

Comment: @NicolBolas I had no idea what site it was, and so it made for a very annoying post.

Comment: I fail to see what's so problematic about the two posts in question. Sure, the topic does not seem to be particularly professional, but it's not vulgar, obscene, offensive, or anything like that. Is the problem that two posts in a row are related to sexuality? Are we really so puritan as to get offended by _that_?

Comment: About "We're extremely proud of the quality of content that can be found on every single site in our network." --- Actually the questions that get on HNQ are the ones that are easy, entertaining to read, and not necessarily high-quality. For [so], easy usually means duplicate. (I don't have statistics, but I'm pretty sure that it's not very uncommon.)

Comment: @forest That's probably a separate discussion, but somebody who comes to SO to find answers to questions they have in the course of doing their job may not want to see those questions an inch away from their work. A desire to not have certain topics popping up in the workplace doesn't make someone puritanical.

Comment: @ZachLipton Almost every single question on HNQ, with very few exceptions, are not something that you'd care to see when you are doing programming work. Why would I care one bit about player drama in a DnD game if I just want to learn about efficient radix tree design? Why would I care how someone's children are misbehaving? As far as I know, the only _bad_ questions are against the ToS anyway, i.e. those that are vulgar and inappropriate in any professional context.

Comment: To clarify, I absolutely support a profile option to disable HNQ, or even disable questions that are not related to programming (I might not want to get sucked into politics while I am working, period), but to declare an emergency and disable it for _everybody_ because someone on twitter who doesn't even use the site is a puritan who tries to see hidden subtext in everything they read? That's just silly.

Comment: @forest If people are talking about their RPG drama next to my desk, it's a noise problem. If people are showing up to talk about resolving their love triangle situation because an algorithm has determined that it's good clickbait that will attract my attention while I'm trying to work, that's a much bigger problem. I'd encourage you to Be Nice and not declare a member of this community to be a "raving puritan" even if you disagree.

Comment: @ZachLipton I do not believe this person was a member of this community. But you're right, and I have removed the "raving" accusation just before the 5 minute period expired. However, by RPG drama I meant drama of the clickbait variety, i.e. the kind that makes it to HNQ. Right now on HNQ I see: 1) Trump drama, 2) flat earther crap, 3) financial drama, 4) racial politics, 5) Islamic drama, 6) terminology regarding the phrase "ass-kissing", 7) more political drama, 8) even more political drama, 9) more racial politics. This is all clickbait from different sites that is not relevant to SO.

Comment: Is SO ashamed of the HNQ now?

Comment: This metapost is strange, there is nothing to fix. If someone is ashamed of a community, you hide the community ? Politic done via twitter.. but the fact is people like click and bait questions, and the HNQ show that trend.

Comment: @forest I would encourage you to duly research the twitter thread that sparked this incident, and to re-evaluate your claim that the complaints were raised by "someone who doesn't even use the site" in the light of what actually happened.

Comment: @E.P. The only thing I know is that someone made ableist accusations against a question there in the start. I know twitter won't do anything, but to respond to that at all is weak.

Comment: @Magisch The tweet by an SO dev which describes pushing the change to the HNQ code is **not** a response to the ableism thread. It was in response to other complaints (look them up) by (at least) two twitter users who are obviously SO users. There's plenty to complain about in terms of how the dev team managed the response (including e.g. how they didn't immediately go to the meta.ips site to talk about what happened), but raising ill-researched accusations and mangling the facts about what happened doesn't advance this conversation - it sets it back.

Comment: @E.P. The complaint about the two questions was also very much ableist from my perspective, but that's splitting hairs here, I agree. If anyone of those people had actually read the second question, it would have become apparent that that was someone with a mental disability trying to learn to navigate social situations. I can personally not construe it as "inappropriate" and find and such notions to be ableist.

Comment: @Magisch You're missing the point (as did several SE users responding on twitter). Once a question gets on HNQ the content of the post is irrelevant: the title of the post is content, period, and it's content that's getting pushed to all sorts of other sites. If the title contains ableist or sexist or whateverist tropes, then that's whateverist content in other sites' pages.

Comment: @E.P. That's not true in my opinion. Just because something is a trope doesn't mean it's sexist. Context matters everywhere, and the title on itself was nothing of the sort. "How do I tell someone that they might be autistic" is not an ableist trope, and suggesting it is is in and of itself quite ableist. "How do I stop people from flirting with me at a school I volunteer at" doesn't even mention either person's gender, and inferring any would be a biased inference and also sexist. I don't understand your line of argument here.

Comment: Can I just take this opportunity to ask to have Serverfault categorically excluded from HNQ? Unlike most other SE sites, we are not a general public site (we are only about pro system administration)  and I strongly dislike the influx of clueless users that have no business being on our site whenever we have the bad luck to have a question appearing on HNQ.

Comment: @forest *"I fail to see what's so problematic about the two posts in question"* - the original Twitter thread was complaining about the discussion of "female treachery". The idea, I think, is that any discussion in which a *man* asks how to deal with some problematic *female* sexual behaviour is inherently hostile to women; that is, the objection is specific to the way round that the genders are and there would be no issue if they were reversed.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It is very very sad to see that People on Twitter who do not bother to read the posts they are complaining about are more important for SE now than Mods who care about their communities. That person didn't even mention DMs and yet there's SE employees scrambling to rescue her from the "trolls", who actually did nothing more than replying to her tweet to explain the post respectfully. If SE keeps doing that to become a brand, they will lose the users who made them the valuable product they're. All they will be left with will be the people who like to create fake controversies

Comment: like the HNQ capability in general to increase exposure of Q/A (aka "virality") but it tends to fail in edge cases. wish there was a similar/ corresponding way to drive traffic into chat rooms for discussion also on hot topics. have noticed tendency of high-rep site regulars and even site _mods_ to dislike some HNQ questions. suggest maybe a "fast veto mechanism" by high rep users and/or mods to just take the questions off the list might be acceptable for many sites. would like to see sites have ability to manage their own home banners more somewhat like the community advertising model.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder until we all collectively quit, SE employees will continue to act the same way towards us (as users) as they have in the past. That is to say, condescending and disrespectful. The bright side of seeing SE folks on Twitter is... well it's unfiltered. But the attitudes there reflect how I've _felt_ that SE feels about me as a user for years now.

Comment: For those who want the HNQ gone *now*, you can use `###hot-network-questions` as a filter in your favorite ad blocker.

Comment: This is hilarious. During _years_ of asking for changes to and/or mod tools for managing HNQs (e.g. during "Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project" which ... just died), _nothing_ happened. For [cs.SE], the feature is, plainly spoken, crap, and we don't get any good traffic from it (afaict). Removal of the site from HNQs would have been an attractive option, even. But some Twitter outcry gets things moving in under an hour? Come on.

Comment: Well, I tried to edit in a link to what happened and to which site was removed, but for some reason someone thinks that is supposed to be a secret... ? Or is supposed to sit in an answer rather than the original post itself...

Comment: I've downvoted this because users have been asking for years to make changes to HNQ and you've done nothing, while a single tweet is enough for you to take action. Way to spit in the face of the SE communities.

Comment: I searched for the incriminated tweet and, honestly,  I don't understand what's this fuss is about: in general, I feel that you SE guys, in this kind of meta posts, spend a lot of words without being able to explain the core of the problems.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Would you, or anyone else, be so kind as to link to the twitter thread and explain what’s so offensive or problematic about the titles in the screenshot? For the life of me I’m not seeing it.

Comment: @DanBron The only recent tweet I've found is [this one](https://twitter.com/fvrmvn/status/1052312605627490305) and, as you, I really have no clue where's the problem, and this post certainly doesn't help.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Here, I found one of the answers cleared it up. Nothing in the screenshot Tim posted has been cited as offensive, so that’s what confused me. It was a different set of titles: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316976/273503 . There’s actually two sets of tweets which caused the response. I think you can find links to them in the edit history of that answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I assumed that it was Arqade producing one too many questions about cooking meth or killing one's children.

Comment: @MarkAmery See my previous comment wrt trying to find hidden subtext. None of the questions were about "female treachery". They were about interpersonal relationship issues. None of them said or even implied female treachery. Asking how to handle inappropriate flirting is _absolutely_ acceptable, even if (gasp!) a man asks it.

Comment: For a lot of users on Arqade, [Out of context question titles](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2196/28182) that get pushed to HNQ are a unintended feature. But other than a few instances where we've had to [reign in](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9956/28182) a few of the more [excitable supporters](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9947/28182), generally the questions are positively received. I'm actually a little surprised that HNQ is being talked about as a 'mixed blessing' feature - I've never seen it as anything but a positive for cross-site collaboration.

Comment: @forest even more, on first sight assuming it is about *female* treachery... is kinda sexist.

Comment: On the other hand, the Twitter user might be an experienced [se] user and is well aware what IPS is about, but just want to have some fun with the out-of-context titles. The result is that there is no fun anymore. *(yes for this particular time it's probably not the case, but some user on SE may want to do this)*

Comment: @TimPost I mentioned this [in TL (♦ only)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47250268#47250268) and should also say here: One of the breakdowns here is that community members have been asking for change to this feature, and pointing out problems with disturbing titles, *for years*, but have been consistently met with silence and inaction. But it took *one person tweeting* and now there's suddenly lots of action. Why did no internal community feedback ever receive this response? That's worth introspecting on as staff, because there's an untenable problem to be found there.

Comment: I read the related Twitter thread yesterday. Seeing how unreasonable and toxic the poster was being towards other people trying to calmly explain the situation at hand, I just muted that profile and hoped no one else would fall victim of a disrespectful exchange from there. Seeing that the company chose to listen and drive this entire Meta discussion out of that only makes me sad.

Comment: @forest I'm assuming the "female treachery" phrasing was inspired not as much by the flirting question as by the question about a friend's girlfriend asking to sleep with the asker. But honestly I don't really understand why it would be sexist to ask how to handle such a situation *when in fact that is a situation that has actually happened*.

Comment: This is a storm in a tea-cup, The person in question tweats are full of useless irrelevant garbage, and so was her retweet. There was nothing sexiest misogynistic or anything else wrong with those HNQ titles and to say there was is baffling. The only click bait that was happening here is the tweet.

Comment: Believe it or not, I haven't cast my vote on this feature as I am feeling ambivalent about the scope of this post. On the one hand, I think there was a sincere request for assistance, asking users to brainstorm ideas and focus on what is important and useful about HNQ  and what can be sacrificed. On the other hand, I cannot help but think this was a PR gesture, intended to distract users away from the poor (*abysmal* IMO) decision undertaken and instead steer users onto a debate focused purely on the merits and demerits of HNQ. A perhaps conciliatory announcement which has badly backfired.

Comment: "Anything out of context can be problematic." This has something to do with Gaming SE, hasn't it? Because those kick on [question titles completely inappropriate when considered out of context](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2196/93118).

Comment: @KyleStrand: Pretty sure they consider it sexist to feature such a question as being "hot", which of course implies that it's the sort of issue that a lot of people are interested in handling. (That doesn't really fix the problem with their reflexive solution, of course: censorship of sociographic data for ideological reasons is scarcely better than censorship of biological or cosmological data for ideological reasons. If a lot of people want to know how to handle "female treachery", you'd best find out why, so it can actually be resolved on a societal level.)

Comment: Don't HNQs become such by being upvoted? IOW, doesn't the upvote count toward their being HNQs. If not, shouldn't it? What does HNQ mean, if not that users think the question is interesting and helpful? Does it just mean that lots of people have visited it? If that's the case then yes, it sounds like asking for (some degree of) click-bait-like trouble.

Comment: Why should we believe that any input here is going to have the slightest bit of impact, given that this has been kicked off by at least the second demonstration in six months that our input has no impact?

Comment: Whatever else you do, if you're working on it, make sure the exclude the question *currently being viewed* from the list. Can't tell you how many times I've been reading an HNQ and seen the question I'm currently reading in the list.

Comment: I'm also downvoting this post despite agreeing with the need to work on HNQ because A) I really don't like how this just kicked a whole site without any real notice B) Ignores SE users for Tweets (or at least ignores channels to get feedback within SE) C) because you have again taken action *then asked for ideas* - ideas don't help when SE's minds are already set

Comment: I feel as though this is the wrong question to be asking as it bypasses the core issue of what's gone wrong here.  SE needs to learn how to manage and communicate it's change process before this specific issue is addressed.  It's clear from previous community discussion that nothing happens quickly (if at all).  This question, as things stand in SE right now, will go to the same nowhere as all of the other change discussions did.  Fix the process before you fix the site.  Please.

Comment: I didn't expect to spend the whole morning reading one topic. I trust this will get lost in the noise, but here's my idea: Did the _juxtaposition_ of the two questions ignite the fury?  Don't put two questions from the same site in HNQ. If someone chooses to click, the rest of the site's content will be revealed.  I am amused by the irony that this discussion could just as easily be on IPS.

Comment: The thing that drives me up the wall about this is the implied message of "We care more about our public perception than ensuring our users have a quality experience on the site." Which is in exact opposition to the site's goals and the very message this post is trying to send.

Comment: A comment I did, that it's the second time a tweet storm make SE make a change in a hurry was deleted. How come ? it's not false, a tweet maked a user getting banned and the CoC was introduced. (The CoC was a good thing, but the point was a tweet do make the network move, like this time again)

Comment: I don't understand. Is this expensive query run everytime someone refreshes a page? Why not creating a separate table containing only hot questions and then run a query that pulls questions from there? Make that table refresh, uhm, like every 15 minutes.

Comment: @yagmoth555 guess by now it's just noise

Comment: Wait, is the problem the HNQ or twitter?

Comment: "We don't expect to solve this in one day".....but you go and remove one site from HNQ without any real feedback despite the people who actually use SE on a daily basic screaming about it for years, all because of someone who is too sensitive making a post on Twitter without knowing the whole story. What's happening to this network lately?

Comment: I found the RPG and worldbuilding community through the HNQ, so I’m very happy that the feature exists (I find most other stackexchange sites via Google). That said: It often diverts my attention from the question I’m trying to answer at that moment (how to get this <whatever> done NOW). If the goal is to show other sites on the stackexchange network, then "hot questions" is the wrong tool, because it selects for very specific (and likely controversial) content, not for the typical content of other sites.

Comment: I'm downvoting the post because it takes a clearly arrogant (look at the rude responses) Twitter user's opinion who is trying to stir up controversy by cherry picking over that of hundreds, if not thousands of SE users own views. Political correctness at it's finest.

Comment: @alephzero I think an IPS site is fine if done properly; it just requires way too much moderation to stay that way.  You can get genuine good practical answers to questions that deal with interpersonal things.  Practical approaches that are based on the experiences of others to achieve a specific goal.  The tough part is trying to remove or acknowledge as much bias as possible.  Even sites like Home Improvement will have biased answers or multiple different solutions in some cases.

Comment: Why in the *hell* are you people listening to ***Twitter?***  Congratulations;  you've just given the entire world an *enormous* lever.  All someone has to do is put a post on twitter implying that your website is not inclusive or offends someone's delicate sensibilities, and they can get anything they want here.

Comment: Other posts twitter users might find offensive by taking things completely out of context include programming questions about killing parents and children: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440691/killing-parent-process-doesnt-kill-child. As such dangerously suggestive phrases exist in any language, the only viable solution is to either close SE or ban the English language.

Comment: How can we possibly respond to this without clear definitions of what you consider to be "triggering" or "problematic"?

Comment: I'd love for sites to be able to opt-out of HNQ. I can't think of a single time Academia has been on the list where I thought it was beneficial.

Comment: @SSight3 A slave process could have one of its children `abort()`ed and `KILL`ed by its master, orphaning its other child. So abortion, slavery, orphans, parricide, filicide? Where will the trigger words end?? But seriously, taking things out of context and getting upset over them is _so_ low. Forks and dongles, anyone?

Comment: I find it interesting that after the attention on Twitter, all of the fuss by objectors about how question titles stand alone in these circumstances, all of the examples given by defenders, and a week of discussion read by hundreds if not thousands of people, no-one has mentioned that every page on every StackExchange site currently sports, in similar fashion but even _more_ prominently and labelled as a featured question, a reference to farting, posted by Tim Post.

Comment: I feel like we're stuck in a loop of SO being something we want, but then SO does something that hardly anyone approves of and the experience of using the site takes a hit. It's at about 30 HP left. It's like they can't get out of their own way

Comment: Just to check, am I missing some sort of response from SO on this matter?

Comment: @Slater: Catija did [respond](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3335/4008) on IPS.meta, but AFAIK they've not responded to the broader MSE community yet.

Comment: @Slater they have not responded but Tim and Jon have tried to give some kind of answer at least: [Tim basically saying don't use Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317221/297125) or at least don't expect anything from Meta & [Jon's response to Monica](https://jericson.github.io/2018/10/24/lost_trust.html) on Medium (cause again, it seems Meta is just not a thing anymore and nobody told us)

Comment: The fact that some people on Twitter misunderstood / misinterpreted / mis-whatever-ed the HNQ feature and that had a knock on effect to kick IPS off the HNQ is absolutely ridiculous. A precedent is being set that you can just make a fuss about nothing and if enough traction is given you'll get your way. A stand should've have been taken and can still be taken. The blog / podcast can be used to clarify the error on the part of the Twitter users and explain the situation as it is with the raw facts. Stop just bending to sensitive (or people pushing agendas) people and let the facts speak.

Comment: I'm not a contributor of IPS however I avidly read questions from IPS that popup from in the HNQ as they are generally interesting and this is just disappointing. As far as the HNQ system goes as a whole and its future, that should be a community driven decision that *shouldn't* have (and still shouldn't be) been influenced by arm chair critics. Either be a part of the community and influence change or just '*sit down and shut up*'.

Comment: @Fomite Don't worry, we can go look at the logs of all the Academia questions to go on HNQ, see whether there are good ones, and take it out of the list if there aren't any. Wait - what? There are no logs?

Comment: @Fomite Well, maybe it's not a great example, but I joined Academia after noticing it in the HNQ ;-)

Comment: This is the question with the 4th lowest vote score ever and counting. The other 3 are also SE announcements, but about licenses, terms of service and layout - they were never about functionality and the sites themselves. I hope SE understands this someday.

Comment: @SSight3 Don't suggest Banning the English Language, there are so many offensive things you can say in English that they just might do it!

Comment: Personally I find HNQ often looks like the spammy "Outbrain" links some sites have. Why would you want to see irrelevant links on a page about a specific question? The HNQ page itself is sometimes fun to visit, though.

Comment: This question receives a lot of drive-by downvotes. ([Vote graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StBkl.png). [Code as text](https://tio.run/#%23bc47CgMxDEXRPmtRjPXkb5cFTJEthBCIIZ9iphu8do@NY1fpjpAQ933bnum@lrKkdVvS53F9fbfLvnNQgazJtHNUQhZVgGLi2BUc6SZR2tGZ2yWs0qGa0QeWNvw2qIbuttXCzV75audzPv0LYMEoYGdGAqyZDQhxViCGWSHWzYhpkDgeCdIftgKjkXMpBw). Data collected from [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/*/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha?cb=1).)

Comment: @user202729 300+ downvotes on this featured question (ie advertised network wide, like HNQ), probably mostly from users having [only association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286150/165773), make me wonder how hot questions would look like if users arriving at these would be able to express their dislike ([there is a feature request about that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238514/165773))

Comment: @neverMind9 https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20score%3a..-175

Comment: If anyone's interested, Jay Hanlon (the 'Welcoming' blog post author), posted a reply to this controversy... on twitter

Comment: I assume with the unfeaturing of this the discussion is concluded. Will there be an official follow-up for any of the suggestions posted here?

Comment: @Magisch Keep an eye on Twitter for official announcements.

Comment: @Magisch *"You are aware that by doing this you killed off some 75% of the site's traffic, yes?"* **What evidence do you have to support this claim today**? Unfortunately, Jad's recent edit failed to answer this vital aspect. It appears to me that the number of questions asked per day has actually risen, not drastically, but significantly. Sometimes IPS gets as many as six questions per day, which is reassuring to know. IOW is there life after being kicked off HNQ?

Comment: @Mari-LouA you are right that there has not been shown to be a 75% decrease. However, *traffic* is not determined by question asking it is the sum of people visiting the site (and really can only be determined by employees looking at the site's full analytics unless mods have access to that). The best we can do is pretty much what Jad did and find similar results to him - its a drop off but how much and if it is just a process of normalization remain to be seen. Drawback is this is still being looked at which also *drives traffic* and can cause people to post more to "fight it". Time will tell

Comment: @JGreenwell it wasn't my intention to suggest that the quota of Qs asked is indicative of traffic/views, I was merely pointing out that the number of Qs asked on IPS, since they were excluded from the HNQ, seems to have risen.  Now what seems to have caused this rise, if it is proven, is very much up for debate.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Site analytics privilege tools show about a ~50% cut, JAD made a seperate analytics post on IPS meta about this: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/on-the-hnq-and-its-effects-on-the-site-stats

Comment: I think this is just as bad as the tweeted questions but it’s still in the list for HNQs, has been for quite a while, yet site isn’t removed from the list... https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/39983

Comment: @Notts90 that's a really good example of double standard. Did the original  title (*What is a subtle way of mentioning one got an erection?*) actually bypass the system? Shouldn't "erection" be a trigger word? That is a much much worse example than the three IPS questions.

Comment: @Mari-LouA from Cat's comment [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/what-caused-this-site-to-be-excluded-from-hot-network-questions#comment11249_3335), it sounds like additional cases were added to the blacklist to prevent that question specifically from continuing to appear on HNQ (with either title).

Comment: Tim, could somebody who was part of the decision please answer [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318792/162102)?  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @gnat.  Sorry we still don't have the authoritative answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 543):

The PR and optics of this discussion could not be worse and less fortunately timed if someone tried to orchestrate it that way.

> Some things happened yesterday that caused a need for us to (quickly)
>   remove a site's eligibility to contribute to the list of hot network
>   questions.

What happened was that someone called SE out on Twitter for something you could conceivably see as problematic (two questions with out of context bad titles showing next to each other in that list). After that, not only was that change done within 40 minutes of it being pointed out, this happened after MONTHS of engaged users of that site [asking](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/should-we-edit-titles-that-are-not-sufficiently-descriptive) [for](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/should-we-step-up-our-voting-culture/1294#1294) [the HNQ to be adressed](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1314/moratorium-on-hot-network-questions-until-we-have-greater-control-over-content).

Yet, this happens only after Twitter outrage from non-users of the site. Why is that? Even if you have the very best of intentions and had this cooking internally for a long time (which I'm going to just assume for the purposes of this argument - good faith and all), this couldn't possibly have had less fortunate timing.

I'm not trying to rag on Stack Exchange for doing this, but why was such a massive change made without consulting, collecting feedback from or even notifying the site's active user base? Why does an engaged user of IPS have to visit twitter of all places to find out SE has cut out more than half of their site's traffic overnight?

Why wasn't the community consulted on this? We had discussions on it before, a lot of people came down in favor of restricting IPS from showing up on the sidebar in some fashion or another, and now we get this. No feedback, no discussion. Someone that apparently SE wants to placate made a stink on Twitter, and somehow that's more effective than months of constructive reasoning in driving change. What reason, if at all, does an engaged user of the site have to trust the community governance model with this?

If it sounds like I'm really annoyed by this its because I am, yes I was in favor of removing IPS from HNQ before, but the circumstances under which it happened is making me lose all hope I have for SE's leadership's ability to formulate concrete plans to make changes constructively.

Comment: It's possible that they've seen those posts, and that tweet was just the "last straw". But SE needs to at least comment on those requests indicating that they're being considered. Not doing so makes them seem like they were ignored altogether, and makes the outward situation you pointed out happen.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog Exactly. Even if that's the case, they should have learned at least the *tiniest* lesson from the very recent and very messy Twitter debacle that went *exactly the same* (where it was allegedly also a problem they've been working on for much longer than the Twitter drama suggested).

Comment: FWIW, your hope in SE's leadership seems to be holding out longer than many other peoples'.

Comment: I feel bad for the veteran users.

Comment: [Twitter-driven development](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316904/is-there-a-list-of-se-communities-excluded-from-the-hot-network-questions-list/316906#comment1038247_316906), "Sites are excluded only after a twitter demand, from someone with at least 1k followers. That's how it works. Feature requests here regarding those things are 100% ignored."

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog If that were the case, why wasn't IPS alerted earlier that the straws were almost gone, so to speak? Why stay silent?

Comment: Bah. [These](https://twitter.com/aalear/status/1052322898252304384) weren't even *"out of context bad titles"* at all; they were perfectly reasonable interpersonal problems to ask about. You accepting the idea that there's something inherently offensive about men asking how to avoid or deal with unwanted sexual attention is ceding far more ground to the feminists than we ought to be; the company blocking an entire site from network exposure for permitting such material is pandering to bigotry. There's nothing wrong with somebody of *either* gender discussing such things.

Comment: @MarkAmery: If your first exposure to IPS is just that title (without even an explanation of what "IPS" stands for), I don't think it's a big stretch to imagine that IPS is the Q&A equivalent of "r/redpill" (and therefore that the SE network endorses such things). Especially if you already believe that SE is somewhat female-hostile. Yes, that's an incorrect assessment, but that's why first impressions *matter*.

Comment: We've been asking for something to be done with the HNQ for the better part of a decade over on Workplace, so... while months is fun, we're sitting back here amused you're still in the first year of lamenting the HNQ...

Comment: But seriously though, this is a giant slap in the face of the actual contributing users to Stack Exchange.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't see it. Neither question title that caused the offence here was "how do I convince my coworker to leave her beta boyfriend for me?"; one was a man asking how to *avoid* uncomfortable sexual attention, and the other was a man seeking help to deal honourably with a third party's infidelity. (Going by the titles alone. I haven't read the posts themselves, but their content is irrelevant to this discussion anyway.) While I'm not going to pull up /r/redpill right now in the middle of my office to check, I'm pretty sure that if I did I wouldn't see questions anything like either.

Comment: @ElysianFields what they don't realise is that acting this way tempts contributing users to [slap them in return](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46698862#46698862) so to speak. 2-3 determined voters with bonus rep can probably bump this whole HNQ circus into more noticeable trouble that they had with this poor pair of IPS questions

Comment: Ah yes, "*We've made these changes in a way that seems erratic, arbitrary and motivated by some non-users being meanies on twitter. But I can assure you this has been long coming and we've been discussing this internally for a very long time*". Where have I heard this before? Oh yes, here on MSE. And this is the _good-faith_ scenario.

Comment: Why do you describe this as "Twitter outrage from non-users of the site." It's pretty clear that the people tweeting are users of the site. They were on SO, presumably using the site to help them do their jobs. I'm not sure why that makes them any less of a user of the site than you or me.

Comment: @ZachLipton That's fair - and it's generally worth us remembering that most "users", broadly defined, are just readers that arrived through Google. and that such people's views matter. I don't think these feminists are *right*. but I agree that "you don't answer questions here, so you don't get to have an opinion" is not the right rebuttal.

Comment: @ZachLipton The *user* might be on the site, but the account is not. The correct way to report a problem is to use a Stack Exchange account and report on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @user202729 That's not the correct way! The correct way, if you want change, is to complain on Twitter! Meta discussions do nothing.

Comment: How does this answer the question? You state why/how you disagree with the way this situation was handled, but nowhere do you have * ideas on ways SE can continue to meet their goals of getting the right sites in front of the right people who are likely to appreciate them and participate.* Especially since this is the highest-voted answer, I find it troubling that it's just a shout at SE and not really constructive.

Comment: @Narusan questions tagged with [tag:discussion] get exactly that: a discussion. Magisch is discussing how the company has been consistently taking a dump on multiple communities this year. Would you prefer a strict answer to the question, one that can be ignored the exact same way (and has probably been posted on many of the relevant per-site metas)? The communities are getting _really_ fed up, hence the votes here. And the question is at +100/-68 right now. I believe this answer is perfectly adequate and constructive.

Comment: @Narusan _So, let's talk about it. And, if this seems like it's a continuation of a conversation, it is, from the moderator chat room. Even though the scope of the discussion is still rough, I wanted to get it out 'in sunlight' early, this isn't something to be settled in an all-mod room._ I took the liberty to interpret that a general commentary on the situation wasn't off topic for this.

Comment: "Yet, this happens only after Twitter outrage from non-users of the site. Why is that?" Because SE no longer cares about how they treat their use base. The welcoming push and "New Contributor" flag have made that clear.

Comment: Maybe, [SE needs to hire a liaison](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317096/213575), so at very least it doesn't come as a surprise.

Comment: @jpmc26 Maybe they wouldn't be a non-user if they didn't have valid concerns that SE wasn't a welcoming place to large groups of people, something I don't find to be in question. SO has even admitted it isn't welcoming in an abundance of ways recently: Publicly declaring it, changing chat moderation expectations, changing the Code of Conduct, publishing site data analysis, changing survey questions, and most recently changing HNQ. And in response to this criticism, the Twitter user has become one of the most villainized people I've seen SO users and moderators set their eyes on. How welcoming!

Comment: @WebHead Whether an external person has valid concerns is unrelated to whether SO is treating their most engaged veterans with respect or dignity. They are two completely separate issues, especially when the community's similar concerns fall on deaf ears. Besides that, having "welcomingness" as a core value is fundamentally stupid. SO cannot be welcoming to people who post low quality content and simultaneously be a site filled with high quality content; they are mutually exclusive. SE is not perfect, but how the community treats you is more often than not based on the quality of your content.

Comment: @WebHead this isn't really about the person starting the drama on twitter, but since you pretend like that's the case I suggest that you read [their corresponding twitter thread with replies from the twitter user](https://twitter.com/justkelly_ok/status/1052868453164437504). Then tell me with a straight face that they're a victim here.

Comment: @Andras Deak If you read what I replied to, you can see that I'm not the one making it about them. But if people are going to argue that non-users opinions aren't relevant, I provided evidence to the contrary. I've also read the thread on Twitter a plenty and IMO the only people in the wrong here are the employees AND moderators that engaged either hastily, inappropriately, or at the very least with a complete tone deafness to the issue at hand.

Comment: @jpmc26 Your last comment, to which I was replying, was about invalidating someone's opinion because they don't use SO, which I was countering. The insistence that SO can't curate high quality content while also being welcome is a concept I fundamentally disagree with and I think many, many of the SE Stacks are currently proving your idea wrong. They are open, kind, welcoming, self-moderating and actively improving Q&A quality... But I agree that many users are not being treated with respect and dignity, not just veretarns and not just newbies.

Comment: @webhead How can the moderator's reply be inappropriate!?

Comment: @webhead As I've said above, the correct way to report SE's problems are through SE. Whether the Twitter user has an SE account is irrelevant.

Comment: @webhead You need evidence for that (the last) claim, otherwise you are insulting a large part of the users. Besides, if it's really a problem, leave that for a meta post (of there is no existing duplicate), not a comment.

Comment: @WebHead No. You don't understand. Being "welcoming" is not the same thing as being "polite" or "professional" or "respectful." Being *welcoming* means encouraging people to stay and keep doing what they're doing. Saying or implying, "You can stay if you change to meet these standards," is not being welcoming; it's being polite. A downvote is fundamentally unwelcoming. A close vote is fundamentally unwelcoming. They both mean, "We do not welcome this behavior. Change or leave." Even edits are unwelcoming to some people. We know this because they feel unwelcome when these things happen to them.

Comment: @WebHead And if you're thinking this is just a semantic difference, it's not. The welcoming push is rooted in a social ideology that rejects systems based on merit. It instead emphasizes class membership and demands greater inclusiveness for certain classes, even if they're not currently being treated any differently than anyone else. (You can see this in the original blog post, where they bring up racial classes *feeling* unwelcome.) The people outside SO who raised this stink to begin with are absolutely looking to undermine content quality as the basis for whether you're welcome here.

Comment: @WebHead Furthermore, that's a 100% misinterpretation of my original comment here. I said nothing about the concerns of outsiders being invalid. I said SO doesn't care about their veteran user base anymore. I think this is objectively true. The entire push has been based on the feelings of outsiders, but SO has shown absolutely no concern for how their actions made the user base feel. The user base has made it abundantly clear that we're very upset and concerned by all this, but SO has flat out ignored that feedback.

Comment: Yes, I do understand what welcoming means, and I still disagree that it means quality has to suffer. It might not be as *easy* as being unwelcoming, but it's doable and requires a cultural change. `Not currently being treated differently than anyone else` is not a valid counterargument, and I'd invite you to look into "indirect discrimination" to get an idea of why. While I'm done with the back and forth, I stand by what I said. I addressed you specifically, but there have been numerous comments since the event having the sentiment and I felt at least 1 deserved public opposition.

Comment: @user202729 Social media as a contact point for customer service issues is not only a "correct" way to reach out, but at this point practically an industry standard for modern businesses. It's the gravitas that the business gives to those complaints and how it handles responding to them that's more significant, and where I see most of that unhappiness coming from. But forcing unhappy users to post on Meta isn't a good strategy for a company, any more than it'd be for a retailer to only require complaints to be made in store at the location with the issue instead of digitally or by phone.

Comment: @WebHead About "it's doable" -- as [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha/316941?noredirect=1#comment1039418_316941) explained, it's impossible, can you point out how? About "indirect discrimination" -- *evidence please*. Besides, you can just flag the comments/posts that you think is discriminative....

Comment: @user202729 I believe you missed my point. I wasn't calling any comments in this thread discriminatory. That's not what indirect discrimination is. It's a specific term with a specific meaning.

Comment: @WebHead If I'm understanding your definition of indirect discrimination correctly, would that mean that when I'm playing football on a lawn but accept everyone who wants to play, I'd be indirectly discriminating against people allergic against lawns?

Comment: @WebHead Anyway, if you think it's a problem, make a meta post (or a tweet if you want `:/`), plus improvement suggestion. The community votes will helpfully determine whether you're correct or not (unfortunately, this feature is not available on Twitter.)

Comment: @Magisch It's not my term, it's a sociological and legal term with clear definitions. If you're unsure, there's wealth of resources available online

Comment: @WebHead Yes, I know that, this was my attempt at trying to find out which of the several conflicting definitions you follow for the purposes of your arguments. I'm interested in what you have to say. From what I found online indirect discrimination refers to a circumstance which is not intended to or directly discriminatory but ends up discouraging certain groups of people by virtue of other external factors (in my example being played on lawn). Am I correct with that assumption?

Comment: @Magisch The exact definition doesn't matter, it's the concept that policies which treat everyone the same way are not *intrinsically* without bias, and that it's necessary to ensure you're not accidentally (or intentionally) exclusionary with said policies. Monica's post makes a good example of how the general concept applies to other things: HNQ "optimizes for controversy". All questions are *technically* treated the same way, yet controversial posts float to the top. Ergo, "not treating them differently" is not a valid argument for a system being without bias.

Comment: @WebHead Ahh, now your prior comments make more sense. I agree generally that this is kind of a thing on stack overflow, e.g. the strict culture of peer review optimizes for people who are confident to stand by their work in the face of criticism.

Comment: @MarkAmery To defend the third party: What *actually* happened was that she suggested sex, *and then texted her bf to ask if it was OK* (before the questioner had a chance to say "no, no, no").  The bf then said "No"

Comment: [Jeff Atwood's latest blog post](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/) actually covers some of this discussion, tangentially, and I agree with many of the points. After reading it, I did want to clarify some of my previous comments: I'm not suggesting SO need be welcoming to _everyone_, which I see now that I may have implied. There is a target group (Atwood proposes "professional and enthusiast programmers") we should be focusing on, and I don't disagree with that.

Comment: @WebHead "Not currently being treated differently than anyone else is not a valid counterargument, and I'd invite you to look into 'indirect discrimination' to get an idea of why." I just looked it up. It's utter nonsense. Of course a policy or rule doesn't affect all groups exactly the same. The idea that it *would* affect all groups exactly the same doesn't make sense because it assumes absolute uniformity across different groups, which would imply the groups don't exist in the first place! Exactly equal outcomes across groups don't exist anywhere in the world, in any arena.

Comment: @jpmc26 [I explained my intent more clearly in my reply to Magisch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha/316941?noredirect=1#comment1039519_316941), and my most recent comment above yours clarifies that I don't think _all_ groups are of our concern.

Comment: @WebHead Your following comments actually make your position *worse*. You're effectively arguing that having any values system that ranks some content or behaviors as preferred over others is discriminatory. While that might be technically accurate in the broadest sense, it's a position that inherently justifies all sorts of mistreatment and injustices, as long as you consider discrimination to be a bad thing. The only thing you *can* do is make sure you're basing your policy on achieving a goal that doesn't involve disadvantaging some target group, which SO's policies have never done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1258/discussion-between-web-head-and-grumpycrouton).

Comment: -1, not because I disagree, but because this is not constructive and doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: @WebHead It's possible; I know I'm running that risk. But I'm also saying that that you have to follow your position to its consequences. If you argue that some groups should be treated preferentially because they're starting off from a worse place (which is *exactly* the point your comments are making), that has consequences, most of them negative for everyone. It makes systems produce worse results overall, and it doesn't actually help the disadvantaged groups improve. You can't argue that we need to do something beyond having an equally applied standard without it creating these problems.

Comment: @jpmc26 I suggest continuing in chat as requested [for the sake of Magisch](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7319426#7319426)

Comment: `I'm not trying to rag on Stack Exchange for doing this, but..` I'll [rag on them for you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha?cb=1#comment1039828_316934).

Comment: @msh210 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha?cb=1#comment1039114_316941

Comment: @user202729, that seems to have been deleted (or my browser isn't jumping to the anchor for some reason).

Comment: @msh210 The comment is still there (it's earlier in this comment thread)

Comment: My post just received an upvote, so I read your response and it took me waaay back in time: pre-infamous SE firing,  pre-COVID, pre-Russian Ukrainian war, pre-everything. I'm not going to say happier times, but nearly. Since this disastrous treatment of IPS, the number of visitors, but even more importantly the number of new questions per day has plummeted. Something like one question every two days. It was a flourishing site, lots of activity, lots of nice users, and now it's like visiting a tiny patch of grass on a massive lawn (i.e the network) which hasn't seen a drop of rain in months.

Answer (score 427):

First and foremost, I don't understand Tim Post's reticence to say which SE post or posts were "responsible" for the Twitter spat. Which, if I understand correctly, lasted a relatively short time.

The tweet that started the controversy was this

> **stack exchange: the #1 site for your questions about dataframes and female treachery**
>
> [image]

The second tweet, which I believe is the one that caused the SE team to internally groan was a retweet by a female developer.

> **When people seem confused about why Stack Overflow might not be the most welcoming/comfortable place for people to find answers to programming questions, show them this**
>
> [image]

She then tweeted this

> **Cool ableism on the front page of a website for dev questions**
> *“How do you tell a Facebook friend that they might be on the autism spectrum?”*

The accusation that SO/SE is not inclusive was retweeted... once. Yes, it spread like extra mature cheddar.

The SE developer who removed the site from the HNQ list (Since when has the term "flirting" been unethical?), replied [emphasis mine]

> Woof, yeah. I agree **that's entirely inappropriate for SO**. I just pushed a change to remove questions from that site from the Hot Network sidebar. I'll ping folks internally to review the site's content more closely as well.

Now, here's my main point. If I had been that developer, I would have DEFENDED that question and EXPLAINED that the question is not taken from Stack Overflow, but from a site called [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/). I would have also explained the site's scope and informed the twitter user their sanctimonious reflection and supercilious attitude was based on false presumption. Well, maybe I would have refrained from using the terms sanctimonious and supercilious to soften the tone.

The same twitter user (Twitterer?)  point blank refused to engage in any civil discussion when they realised that their [high horse](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-get-off-your-high-horse) didn't have [a leg to stand on](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-a-leg-to-stand-on).

In other words, the management's reaction and the action taken was excessive and unnecessary.

### Bring back IPS to the HNQ. They did nothing wrong.

<sub>Disclaimer: I am no longer a member of IPS, I left that community several months ago. But I bear no grudges to its users, many of whom I secretly admire.</sub>

Comment: Why do you believe the Twitter user has an obligation to engage in civil discussion with anybody? She just sent a Tweet. Other people showed up on her feed after this meta was posted. If she wants to talk about it, she can come to Meta like anyone else, but people showing up to argue in her replies is unhelpful when the discussion is taking place on the site here, and I'm not sure why you believe she's done something wrong if she doesn't constructively engage with with the people who turned up on her Twitter uninvited to argue about it.

Comment: @ZachLipton people on Twitter were polite, they explained the person's error and hasty judgement, but she rudely dismissed them. It was rude. She didn't engage at all. If I want to express an opinion on the Internet, that's my choice but  I have to accept that I am open to criticism and/or correction(s) from outsiders. Just as I am now replying to your comment, acknowledging your dissent and trying to explain myself.

Comment: Strangers on the internet do not have an obligation to engage with all comers or anyone at all in fact. She dismissed people who, instead of participating in the discussion on Meta, went to go bother her on Twitter because they were upset at about SE community management decision. Blame SE for its actions all you want, but don't take this out on a Twitter user who you insult and demand must have a good attitude after she's had 10 different people show up in her mentions to argue about it (in tones ranging from civil to downright rude) when there's a perfectly good discussion here on the site.

Comment: It looks like the Tweets are in the wrong order: The retweet of 'normal website' (that got a reply) happened before they added their own tweet about the autism question... Also, very much appreciate the sentiment of your post. As the person who wrote the Tweets has been very clear in not wanting to engage further, I'd like to conclude by asking a small favour from everyone here and respect that wish by focusing their energy on constructively cleaning up the mess and moving on, here and on IPS meta :)

Comment: @ZachLipton where am I discussing the issue, here or on twitter? Which I wouldn't even be able to do b/c I don't have a twitter account. One social media account is more than sufficient, but I see many people who have several accounts, etc. and some are more eager to express their opinionated viewpoints than others. You are criticising my position just as I am criticizing her reaction, but my main beef is with the mod who removed the IPS post from HNQ because of *one* tweet. A post that was not in the slightest offensive or disrespectful. A post that SE should not be ashamed of.

Comment: The problem is that a single moaning tweet from someone who doesn't even use the site got something to happen almost instantly, whereas this discussion has been going on for years on this own site and nothing has happened. That's what people are upset about.

Comment: It's twitter. It's designed to filter nuance from any discussion topic. The more troubling thing here is that SE devs apparently care about the opinions of non-members on twitter more then about meta consensus.

Comment: About that "ableism" tweet. That tweet is actually doing exactly what it accuses the question of. How about some self reflection on that user's part. I'm autistic and I find the tweet significantly more offensive then the question could have ever been. Do I get to remove that user from twitter now? I don't think so.

Comment: @Pyritie it's worse than that, an entire site has been made the scapegoat for SO's poor reputation online. It's an absurd and ridiculous situation, the tweet should never have been taken seriously. As for fixing HNQ, if you get rid of it, sites with a dwindling user core base will inevitably suffer.

Comment: [this](https://twitter.com/fvrmvn/status/1052304251219791873) was the original post that got thing started... a request for a feature to block HNQ

Comment: This information (what happened) should be in the question rather than an answer. I tried to edit it in, but the edit was rejected. Maybe i should use my twitter account to suggest the edit instead..

Comment: @DeNovo better not. If the edit was rejected it just means that some users didn't think the exact circumstances was worth mentioning. It's been a long day, sometimes it's good to take a break, come back the next day, and see things with new eyes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that was a joke about what tends to get a response here. I have a pretty high follower count on twitter. It's good to know that's the appropriate channel to suggest changes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Can I ask why you're repeatedly asking for IPS to be reinstated to HNQ? As noted elsewhere, the removal is something that IPS has [explicitly asked for](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1314/2120). The problems how IPS was removed aside, how exactly would reinstating it help things move forward?

Comment: @E.P.that's an exaggeration, saying I am repeatedly asking IPS to be reinstated. As for the meta post you provided a link, a cursory glance tells me it was posted over a year ago and the community did not seem to reach a unanimous decision. As for moving things forward, the decision taken by the SE employee was bad, made in good faith no doubt, but bad all the same.

Comment: Looking at chat, I think that there are a few people that read you answer and take it at face value, and are thus convinced that the ableism tweet is the one that started it. Since you now understand that it is not correct, could you please fix the answer? I know it doesn't change your point, but it affects what people understand of the situation. Thanks!

Comment: @Federico it's more complicated than you think. It will mess up the presentation and the wording, but I'll give it a go

Comment: I understand the difficulty, but thanks for trying! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "*They did nothing wrong.*" SE never accused IPS, or the posters of the questions themselves, of doing anything wrong. Indeed, the OP here makes it clear that the questions and titles are fine *for the site*. What they're saying that isn't fine is divorcing those titles of all context (including knowledge of what IPS itself is) and then shoving them in everyone's faces. That is, SE doesn't agree that these questions or their titles are bad. Nobody from SE has gone to ISP and edited the titles or unilaterally closed/deleted them.

Comment: @NicolBolas that's not entirely true. In Adam Lear's tweet: `I'll ping folks internally to review the site's content more closely as well.` This heavily implies that IPS should have done something different in this case.

Comment: @NicolBolas so why were the question titles described as being "entirely inappropriate for SO"? Why has IPS been excluded from HNQ? Why was there no pre-warning, why did no one have a word with the  IPS mod team, and ask them to monitor dubious question titles? Why was action taken so swiftly without consulting the community? Obviously, they felt the earnest need to repair the damage, but there was no damage in the first place.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Because they are inappropriate *for SO*. The titles are fine for IPS, but they were showing up on SO. Excluding IPS is for that reason: so that inappropriate titles don't show up on SO. Not every title is going to be read the same way outside of the context where it is intended to appear.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: To give a hypothetical example, imagine that we has a Sex.SE site. And a title was "How do I deal with my Erectile Dysfunction?" On that site, this is a perfectly OK question; everyone seeing that title on that site knows what it is. But when you're browsing a supposedly professional-oriented site like SO, seeing that title on the side makes the whole site look decidedly unprofessional. Professional sites don't have links to pages about ED; that's the stuff of spam, ad-heavy porn sites, and the like. It would make SO look bad.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: My point was to give you an example of a question that is *clearly* perfectly valid in context in which the question was asked, but is just as clearly *not appropriate* to the context of a "professional" site like SO. Your post seems to suggest that if the question and its title are perfectly fine in context, then it must also be perfectly fine to put them on any other site outside of that context.

Comment: @NicolBolas  [Previously...] *I think you should transfer your observations onto [your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316966/223820). There's nothing wrong about defending the dev team's course of action, it actually might help users get a more even-keeled/balanced/impartial viewpoint of the situation.* [And] *If you do decide to transfer your comments/thoughts onto your answer, could you then please delete them from here?* [Update] in case users are wondering, I've deleted two responses and united them in one comment.

Comment: "_I don't understand Tim Post's reticence to say which SE post or posts were "responsible" for the Twitter spat._" Two reasons: (1) this is applicable to way more than one site, it's been an on-going problem for _years_. When video games started letting people kill prostitutes, we realized we had a problem. (2) I needed this to go out _immediately_ and drawing more people to the fray on Twitter wasn't, by any stretch of even the most drunken of imaginations, optimal.

Comment: @TimPost  You're comparing a few question titles on IPS  to videos that glorified sexual violence. That's a bit extreme. If the problem had long existed ,SE's responses didn't seem to acknowledge it. Or maybe they did? Can you please show me responses from SE management that answered or responded or explained or defended the several questions and issues raised about HNQ over the years by users. I have tried looking, but I probably have missed them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA thank you thank you for adding the context and timeline. It helped me clarify my thoughts and opinions on the topic.

Comment: "a retweet by a female developer." "she then tweeted this" I'm not sure that specifying the person's sex/gender is relevant here. That information has been used in other posts/comments here to slander the tweeter as well as equal rights groups already.

Comment: @TylerH How is using the pronoun "she" and describing her as a "female developer" slandering her? I think her sex is pertinent, she claims that SO is hostile to women computer programmers. That was why, she claims, [she posted the IPS titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317087/se-needs-a-better-social-media-policy-and-could-us-experienced-users-get-a-litt#comment1039447_317087) in the first place. Quote: *…annoying mansplaining stack exchange mods in my mentions while I was offline. Helpfully telling me why I'm so wrong about their precious forum site being unwelcoming to women*

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't think using "she" and "female dev" is slandering her; I am saying other people have maligned this person based on her sex in this very Q&A and am questioning the wisdom of specifying that; I simply think the criticism of 'unfriendly environment' is equally valid criticism regardless of the sex or gender of the person reporting the problem.

Comment: @TylerH you said *That information (her being a female developer] has been used in other posts/comments here to **slander** the tweeter* If that is true, I condemn their actions and words (w/o knowing exactly what was said)  but I am not responsible for what they say. My main criticism is with the SE developer who rushed in where sensible people fear to tread.

Comment: @TylerH and Mari-Lou A, as a matter of law it is impossible to slander or otherwise defame a female developer by calling her a female developer, because a statement cannot be defamatory unless it is false.  Perhaps you are using the word "slander" loosely, but I don't understand exactly what you mean by it.

Comment: @phoog Again, at no point have I said people are slandering the woman by calling her a woman. They are taking that information and applying other labels to her in a pejorative way insulting to her and to the true group that uses those labels, e.g. "oh, she's a woman, she must be X", etc.

Comment: @TylerH ok, lets back track a bit. Where did Mari-Lou start labeling people. Please, **cite examples**. On this answer I see only descriptions of what happened and later how it made feel the author. In no way, I see metaphors that implies generalization. I see that Mari-Lou properly abstracted itself from the events it was describing for the audience, until it decided what was its issue with the handling by the staff.

Comment: Gasp, every time I look Tim's post gets deeper and deeper in the negative score. it's now a mind-boggling -32. People are really pissed off...wow.

Comment: What's really noteworthy about the score is that it's not just being downvoted; it's also **lost** a bunch of upvotes in the last day.

Comment: @Braiam For the third and final time, I did not say that Mari-Lou was the one labeling people. Please read carefully.

Comment: after the last edit that unlocked voting it _lost_ some 20 upvotes that converted into downvotes over night

Comment: I understand moderation and management of a giant network of sites is hard, but why was this something done so quickly, in response to a person on Twitter, while tons and tons of highly upvoted feature requests have been ignored for years?

Answer (score 331):

The HNQ implementation has at least three problems:

- **It optimizes for controversy, not quality.**  Sensationalist questions draw lots of rapid response, which feeds the HNQ algorithm, and then once it's on HNQ it gets *even more* rapid response, which keeps it there (and also distorts Q&A on that site).
- **It's completely automatic; sites have no way to intervene and remove a question short of closing it.**  But closure is frequently the wrong answer; the question is perfectly valid, but controversial.
- **Everybody sees it, all the time.**  If that list on the side of the page has even one or two "exciting" questions, we can pretty much guarantee that some readers will be upset.  (There is a regex filter on titles, but it comes with all of the usual regex challenges.)

If we want to have something like HNQ -- and I've heard enough people on smaller sites saying they value the promotion to go with that for now -- then we need to find a way to let communities curate the content.  We should also consider user controls for those who need them.  (I get it; I don't want my coworkers to see that question about Klingon mating rituals either.)  We should also adjust the algorithm so it doesn't so strongly prefer controversy.

Here are some ideas along those lines:

- To aid curation: provide a way, from the question page, to see if this question is currently hot or likely to become so.  If automatically displaying that would be an expensive operation, let's add a way to check.  Perhaps checking the hotness score and comparing to the minimum score from the HNQ is good enough; we don't need to actually do the lookup.
- Automatically exclude questions that the community has signalled have issues: protected questions and questions with two or three close votes.  (Probably we should make that number adjustable.)  More thoughts on this [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285001/162102).
- Give moderators and high-rep users a menu item for "exclude from HNQ" so they can be proactive.
- Suggested in comments: [allow communities to review hot questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298396/162102) (also suggested on other answers here)
- Factor downvotes into the hotness formula.
- I don't have concrete suggestions here, but let's review the velocity part of the formula.  Lots of answers isn't necessarily a good measure.  Lots of *quality* answers might be, but that's hard to measure.  But let's factor answer score and length in more and number less.
- Allow users to (persistently) collapse the HNQ, and [start in the collapsed state](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316930/162102).

As noted in comments, we should also review the effects of visitors bearing association bonuses on hot questions (should they be able to vote? comment?).  I've been focusing here on how questions get (or don't get) to HNQ visibility, and with all the voting that's already happened I don't want to expand the scope of this answer now.  Let's use other answers for that part of the problem.

Comment: I've seen at least one case where a site closed a good, on-topic question to remove it from HNQ, then reopened it once it became 30 days old (and thus ineligible to appear there).

Comment: Also, there exists a user script to check the "hotness" level of a question, which I've installed. As the HNQ list is cached while the script calculates it live, there should be some time to stop such questions from appearing there.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveWerehog userscripts are all well and good, but it would be nice to have that sort of thing baked in, so we don't have to chase it down. Userscripts aren't possible for everyone, for whatever reason (even for mods etc who might want to keep an eye on such things)

Comment: @Ash My point was, the user script could be used as a stopgap solution before such a thing were to be implemented.

Comment: I particularly like the recommendation allowing moderators to exclude certain questions from the HNQ.  This seems like it would be a useful stop-gap until a revision of the formula could be worked out.

Comment: +1 The HNQ absolutely optimises for controversy. On RPG.SE the effect of a HNQ is often also pretty bad: if we've got a controversial, difficult topic it needs careful community cultivation, expert answers, and highly knowledgeable voters more than ever... Then it hits HNQ and we see an influx of dozens of votes upvoting poor advice in exponential proportion to whatever the scores already were, amplifying the fastest gun and drowning out up-and-coming better advice completely. That effect is a disservice to everyone and degrades the quality of help RPG.SE provides.

Comment: @doppelgreener: Philosophy has this problem as well. Controversial questions that have "God" in their title are regularly on the HNQ, even if they are ill-stated, unclear, etc. and attract a high number of opinionated comments and answers of which two-thirds have to be deleted. The only other things popping up there are similarly bad questions on evolution and quantum mechanics/free will. I have yet to see a well-stated question *on philosophy* in this list. Yes, it helps with traffic for smaller sites. But I doubt that it is traffic we *want* to have on these sites.

Comment: The whole time reading your post was the thought going through my mind was, "Give mods a method to be proactively remove questions from the HNQ." When I saw that in your list, I was pleased. Great write up, btw. Very well stated.

Comment: [Feedback loop, indeed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286020/breaking-the-hnq-feedback-loop-on-bad-questions). Though then again, if performance is such a stumbling block, the question does become more complicated.

Comment: Would +1 again for 'factor downvotes into the hotness formula' - indeed, factor them *heavily*. And the same with close votes. A question on the list gets three close-votes? Take it out of the sidebar *before* it blows up, and give it time for the site community to put it into shape, and once it gets fixed put it back on the bar if you want.

Comment: I regularly found the HNQ list to be distracting and borderline offensive. Since I found no way to edit or minimize it, I finally broke down and just removed it with my browser default style sheet.  Please make it optional.

Comment: I like this except for excluding protected questions - being on the HNQ list is often when you most need protection.

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm not sure I understand (maybe I was unclear?).  I'm suggesting that questions that are protected or have (enough) close votes should be excluded from HNQ.  Protection, in particular, generally means it *already has* some bad (deleted) answers.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Right, and I think that would be a mistake. Even good questions that don't overly attract controversy on the HNQ just attract crappy answers. I'd even say it would be good to preemptively protect all HNQs, at least temporarily while they're on the list.

Comment: @curiousdannii one advantage of my approach is that if a hot question gets those bad answers and the community deletes them, the question will be auto-protected and thus kicked off the HNQ list automatically.  On the other hand, "well-behaved" hot questions (I've seen some) can remain without pre-emptive protection.  (SE has in the past pushed back against pre-emptive protection; that's why community members can't do it until there's actually a qualifying deleted answer.)

Comment: @doppelgreener Perhaps when a question becomes hot, additional protections kick in? For instance, maybe the association bonus doesn't count towards upvote/downvote/comment privileges for the question.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy keep in mind that the HNQ isn't the only source of influxes to specific questions.  Reddit or a tweet from Joel will also generate a lot of traffic.  And while we can count on Joel to not tweet terrible questions, we can't say the same about Reddit.  So if there are any special protections they should be a function of velocity of activity, not just hotness.  And that's hard to get right (and confusing for users).

Comment: @MonicaCellio I don't think this would necessarily be more confusing than protected question status. Maybe a combination of both automatic + human control? It makes sense to me that under certain circumstances, you'd want to restrict all activity to people who have demonstrated expertise within a specific community.

Comment: @Wowfunhappy for protection, all the information about why you can't answer this question is visible on the question.  Plus it's durable; if you come back to that question six hours later it'll *probably* be in the same state.  Hotness changes rapidly and is not logged on the question at all, so that'd be pretty confusing I think.  (Plus, as I said, it shouldn't just be hotness.)  It sounds like you have ideas about HNQ that should get more visibility than this comment thread; consider adding an answer.

Comment: +1. I'd just change one thing: not only mods but also other high-rep users should be able to (vote to) exclude a question from the HNQ list. There are only so many mods to go around. I'd see anyone with at least 10,000 rep as understanding enough about a site and having seen their share of HNQ blowups to meaningfully vote on this. (Giving this right only to mods might be easier to implement.)

Comment: About "Automatically displaying that would be an expensive operation" - since the system already calculates the scores, it would be pretty easy to just record the score each time a question is analysed. Sure, it'll be a few bytes (or maybe just a 1-byte indicator storing a few levels from 'not HNQ' to 'HNQ') multiplied by many, many questions, but it shouldn't be computationally expensive if done in-situ when the HNQ algorithm runs.

Comment: I agree with wowfunhappy that HNQ has a bad interaction with the association bonus. I would honestly be in favour of something like auto-protecting/disabling comments from association bonus users. It just leads to massive amounts of off-topic discussion. Maybe they shouldn't even be allowed to vote, to try to defuse the votes -> more visibility -> more votes, feedback loop.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I agree that high-rep users should be able to prevent HNQification of a question too, and have updated.  I focused on mods originally because mods already have a user interface for this so it's easier, but I agree we shouldn't stop there.

Comment: @mbrig I added a comment at the end about this point.  I agree we also need to look at what people with only an association bonus can do on these questions (and I've written elsewhere on MSE about both voting and comments), but I don't want to expand the scope of an answer that already has 90 upvotes now.  If there aren't already other answers that cover this, please add one. Thanks.

Comment: One way to handle the discoverability of a collapsed-by-default HNQ list would be to add something like [the placeholder Watched Tags box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VasdC.png) with text along the lines of "See great questions from some of our other nice sites!", with the added advantage that you can then link directly to a customizing checkbox list that puts the which-sites-do-you-want choice right in front of new users.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Maybe [as a 30k-rep privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300866/184688)?

Comment: Agreed from [cs.SE]'s perspective. Mostly bad-ish and/or low-hanging-fruit questions become "hot". Neither do those represent the site well, not are the incoming laypeople any help. All HNQs do for us is skew the voting landscape and create a "highest voted" list that ... sucks.

Comment: @E.P., most of the sites with an HNQ problem don't have *any* non-mod 30k users.  IPS has one.  Politics has one.  Christianity has three.  Philosophy has two.  Skeptics has six.  The only sites likely to benefit from making this a 30k privilege are Roleplaying Games (28 users), Arquade (18), The Workplace (23), and Worldbuilding (22).

Comment: I would also like to see a method for mods and high rep users to _promote_ a question to HNQ. Some good questions just don't quite get the views/answers they need to make the list. If X votes from the upper rep users of a site can push a question to HNQ, and if that can trump hotness score, then that could help promote the content the site _wants_ to see out there.

Comment: @Mark presumably 30k in that post is for "graduated" sites.  Privs are scaled down for "beta" sites.  Probably the "trusted user" privilege (20k or 4k) is what we'd want.  But these are details that can be worked out if SE actually goes down this path; we don't need a full spec now.

Comment: @Mark Thank you for pointing out those numbers - they do change the status of the linked answer (and it would be good if you can post them there as a comment). But yeah, we don't need a full spec at this juncture.

Comment: These are great suggestions. Someone should post them on Twitter.

Comment: This is definitely 100% on point, optimizing for controversy / clickbait is hugely dangerous on the SE network. I wrote about this in 2012, same thing applies https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/31/the-trouble-with-popularity/

Comment: Reddit has a "controversial" sorting for posts. Just implement something similar and only include the least controversial questions? Or change the query to detect only the questions where users are collaborating on the same answers (high level of agreement on the best answers, not more than X answers, several people editing some posts together).

Comment: When you say velocity, are you talking about timing/age of the question? One potential solution I see, and that would solve the issue @doppelgreener summarised very well, is to just not push new questions to HNQ. By all accounts this list exists to promote other sites, not to get people to answer questions, yet that's exactly what happens now. If we delay HNQ by 24 hours or more, the site has the chance to curate and properly answer a question, and it allows use of much more reliable metrics to identify high-quality Q&A.

Comment: @Lilienthal timing of the question, answers, and votes all factor into the formula, as I understand it -- a new question that gets five upvoted answers in the first couple hours is almost certain to hit HNQ, for example.  We should stop counting that kind of speed as a positive; on some sites, if a question gets that many answers that quickly it's because the question is either too broad/opinion-based (which can be put on hold) or controversial and many of those people are soapboxing.  A delay before a question could even *enter* the HNQ would help a lot; it lets the community respond first.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, that seems to be one of the strongest factors in pushing something to HNQ, and I agree that it's a bad metric to use, automatically favouring easy/popular/opinionated topics over others.

Comment: What about the converse (if that's the right word) of moderator (and possibly high-rep user) exclusion from the HNQ: Only putting questions **approved** by a moderator (and possibly high-rep user) on the HNQ in the first place? There could be an HNQ per site where hot questions on each site are reviewed by that site's mods + optionally high rep users and questions that get approval for HNQ are the only ones eligible to appear there. Sites that are less moderated will naturally not appear in the HNQ. Downside: yet another review queue.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I think a review queue for questions that show signs of becoming hot has a lot of promise.  I think there's another answer here that proposes that too; just gotta find it in this pile.  (Just found a question about that and added a link.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio The idea could even be simplified to adding a tickbox that says 'Exclude from HNQ?' when creating a question (the creator can also tick it in edit but can't undo it once ticked and confirmed), allowing the users to exclude their own questions. It would also allow mods/admins to edit the post and tick the box. Still, I don't like the idea of censorship, but if users want to avoid drawing attention to a difficult question then they can.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking : a similar problem is often found on politics.se, with "questions" like *"Why did [politician I hate] decide to do [controversial thing]"*, so that they can upvote answers which bash that politician and argue in comments with others who fail to do so.

Comment: [This answer of yours](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245355/397504) is almost four years old but I think it is a perfect answer to the question on this page. I [have tried to summarize it here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316997/397504)

Comment: Another possibility is to require a specific reputation _on site_ in order to vote. People coming through the HNQ often upvote the question massively which keeps the question on the HNQ longer. If only people experienced on the site were allowed to vote (even with 5 on-site rep!), then _actually good_ questions would stay on the list for longer, and we would not optimize for controversy anymore

Answer (score 279):

### As a user

I **love** the HNQ list because I really enjoy learning about all manner of diverse topics. A jaunt through the HNQ can see me hopping from Christianity to Physics to Parenting to Aviation to Skeptics to Worldbuilding and so on and so forth. Without the HNQ I wouldn't put in the effort to check for interesting questions on two dozen sites.

### For a site

For some **beta** sites in particular, the HNQ very often brings in a great deal of that site's traffic. Removing an entire site from the HNQ necessarily means taking a road to that site and turning it into a trail. I don't think isolating this or that site for any reason is in keeping with the spirit of the Stack Exchange **network**.

---

All that to say: **please don't *remove* the HNQ list from the sidebar**. There are certainly ways to improve it and I'm all for that; I'll let others cover that.

Comment: This, big time. The HNQ is a source of absurdly great reading on any given day. Please keep it if you can.

Comment: As a possible addition to this post: one of the sites that I *most* enjoy reading questions about on the HNQ list is the one that has just been taken off it.

Comment: As a user, at work I often get lost in following those links from a SO question where I looked up something, so there I would like to hide it. (I used to have a stylish script for this, but stylish was then banned, and I didn't set up an alternatives.) At home I often enjoy just clicking from hot question to hot question.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann Yeah, I've seen that sentiment (HNQ being distracting on SO is undesirable) in a couple other answers and comments, which suggests that perhaps it should be hidden on SO specifically. But on the other hand, SO is likely the biggest source of traffic via HNQ (it would be nice to see actual numbers on this!), so there's a bit of a Catch-22 there.

Comment: Just allow a user to fold it away, and remember this in a cookie (not a user account), that should be enough.

Comment: +many: HNQ-discovery is how I landed on the site I now *moderate*. I hope the idea of "a selection of interesting stuff from around the network that you might not otherwise see" never goes away.

Comment: I was just about to add an answer to say exactly this - it would be a great shame if this feature were to go away, and it is a shame that IPS is now excluded from it.

Comment: Totally agree with this sentiment. Why not let users pick which **sites'** "hot" questions show up? Then you know what you're signing up for. I loved IPS, just as I love Workplace, just as I enjoy seeing interesting Math and DBA content. It would be similar to ignoring tags on SO (except they wouldn't be highlighted, they just shouldn't be in the list)

Comment: Thanks to HNQ, I have joined sites I otherwise wouldn't have known about and ended up contributing to either the hot question itself or other questions on the site because of this. So I agree 100% with this answer: HNQ should stay.

Answer (score 173):

Let's stop over-promoting some sites at the cost of other sites rarely making the list at all.

The network has more than 170 sites.  Some of them are small and rarely make an appearance on HNQ at all.  Others are large and active and can have five or more questions on the list (of 100) at once.  That's working against the goal of broadening people's horizons and, on those small sites, can feel kind of crappy (what do we have to *do* to get some attention already???).  Let's fix that.

There are 100 questions at a time on the HNQ, with a random subset shown on each page load.  100 < 170+.  Therefore a site's "fair share" of the HNQ real-estate is <1 -- round up to 1.

No site should have more than one active HNQ at a time.  Yes, that means that a question might need 50 hotness points on SO and 5 on Astronomy; that's ok.  Show us the best hot Astronomy question anyway.  And cycle them more quickly, so it's not the same Astronomy question that was there yesterday.

I know that on some sites (most notably SO) the HNQ gate rises with each question already on the list (it's harder to get HNQ #3 than it was to get HNQ #2).  I'm proposing a simplification of that: each site gets one, period, and it shouldn't stay there for a week like some HNQs do now.

Comment: I think that's a good idea overall. I have nothing against limiting how often TWP, PPCG, and IPS get on HNQ, since they are most definitely overrepresented. But *Only one no matter what forever?* I think that's too harsh. Maybe limit it to 2-3? Or perhaps even increase the total number of questions that can be *"on the HNQ"*

Comment: +1 for "cycle them more quickly"! If a questions does not interest me today, it won't interest my tomorrow or in a week

Comment: @DJMcSpookem I won't object if they set the limit at two rather than one.  I proposed one to give smaller sites a chance to show up there at all.

Comment: The problem I see is that some sites get *less than* one question per day, so I'm not sure if they're getting enough questions to have something new and interesting for the list at the frequency that you're suggesting.

Comment: @Laurel those sites would then be among the 70+ that aren't currently in the HNQ list, then.  When a small site *does* get a good new question, though, it can actually hit HNQ, which rarely happens today.  I don't think we have dozens of sites in the category of "less than one question per day".

Comment: It's actually less than 100... if I remember correctly, only the top 50 of the full 100 list ends up in the sidebar, which is where I'm guessing most of the traffic comes from.

Comment: Monica, you can find some more details on that issue [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312719/165773), there is a little analysis based on snippet of stats shared by Shog a while ago, "top 5 sites (Workplace, SO, SFF, Worldbuilding, Code Golf) get 50x to 200x(!) more clicks than bottom 10 (Hinduism, Android Enthusiasts, Latin, Chess, French, Law, Board Games, Russian, Mi Yodeya, Christianity, Motor Vehicles). It gets even worse if you take into account that mentioned snippet lists only 70 sites of total 130+, meaning that about 60 sites get even less views..."

Comment: Thanks @gnat.  Clicks are affected by both the presence of the HNQ entries in the first place (you can't click on what you don't see) and interest.  I'm not surprised that more people are interested in some questions from SO or Workplace than they are in ones from French or Latin.  Do you have any data on distribution of HNQ questions, as opposed to clicks, so we can isolate these variables?

Comment: @Catija In my experience that's not the case.  I've had several borderline HNQs that got (relative) spikes in traffic while never getting into the top 50, and I'm pretty sure I saw them on the list.

Comment: one of MSE regulars collected fairly representative sample of distribution data and reported their findings [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315017) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315525). Back then I briefly skimmed it and there were some interesting differences supporting your idea that clicks and distribution are not the same. It felt a bit troublesome that  clicks seemed to depend too much on distribution. Kind of self fulfilling prophecy when clicks are mainly caused by questions presence in the sidebar and not by them being genuinely interesting

Comment: To make a parallel, this answer is going for the US Senate approach of "X representation per community, no matter the population(/activity)." Is this really a good approach? Small communities may have very few questions, and of them quite possibly no great candidates, while a large site might have many to choose from. Should our metaphoric California get the same number of questions survived as North Dakota?

Comment: @NexTerren fortunately, the HNQ changes its representatives more frequently than the US Senate does.  Also, the SE equivalents of DC and Puerto Rico get representation.   And there are only 100 slots, so if a site doesn't have any good questions at the time, somebody else gets that slot.  We can still set minimum thresholds (if we can decide what they should be).  One of the points of HNQ is to get exposure for some of those small obscure sites.  Because they're small, they don't already have tons of votes -- but that doesn't mean the questions aren't good.

Comment: I love this idea. To take it a step further: if the list doesn't need to be an arbitrary 100 questions long, it could be changed to be 3N questions long, where N is the number of sites in the network. Then HNQ could always be the "hottest" (by whatever measure) 3 questions from each site. The sidebar could then show a selection chosen uniformly randomly from that list.

Answer (score 117):

Just to start, I'm going to run down a few of the problems I have with the HNQ, as it currently stands:

- **It does a *terrible* job of promoting good questions from the really small sites that could use the exposure the most.** I can count on one hand the number of HNQ questions Astronomy has had within the last three months, I think.
- **It's optimized for hot questions, not *good* questions.** There's a difference, and arguably, question quality and activity can be orthogonal in some cases. I'll claim that the very best questions *don't* get 10 answers within an hour. The problem is, what makes a question good can be hard to objectively determine.
- **It doesn't look at the actual content of the questions.** At all. It's blind to what topics are represented, and that, too, can be a problem, skewing the HNQ questions of a given site to certain subsets of its scope.
- **We, the users, have essentially zero control over whether a questions makes it to the HNQ or not.** We don't have control over how a prime tool for evangelism and outreach is used.

So, here are some point-by-point solutions:

- Guarantee every site, no matter what the size, one HNQ question per period, by essentially adjusting the requirements on each site for a question to make the HNQ. And I mean making *big* adjustments to thresholds, whatever they may be.
- Maybe let the community choose certain questions to get more attention - i.e. let each site create a "Best of" list of questions from the past X days they might want promoted (maybe with X=14?). I'm thinking of some sort of voting process on meta. An issue with this, of course, is that it probably requires some manual work, but - and correct me if I'm wrong, since I've got no technical expertise here - we could use a system similar to the one that determines whether community ads are displayed.
- Urg, I can't really think of ways to get around some topics being overrepresented among a site's HNQ questions. Maybe that's not an issue?
- See the second bullet point, here. I'd love a "Best of" list, with a couple questions to be shown on the sidebar every week.

Basically, I care about the HNQ bringing attention to sites that need it, and doing a good job of representing site scope. By ensuring representation among all the sites - or as many as possible - we can cultivate growth. Heck, the HNQ is how I found Worldbuilding four years ago, a site I now moderate. I also want more control over what questions we feature, which is why letting sites collectively pick the best questions from the past 1-2 weeks would be nice.

Comment: But if they do all that will the questions be *hot*? Would anybody want to click the links?

Comment: @user000001 I'm not quite sure what you mean; can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: I was talking about the proposals for having users select the hnq questions, and about the equal representation if all sites. I'm afraid that the selected questions wouldn't be as interesting as they currently are. But now I noticed that they're going to remove it completely, so anything is better than that :(

Comment: I think this is a good solution. If the goal is to get eyes on other network sites, I'd much rather have good questions than questions that may be a flash in the pan.

Comment: I think regular voting should be good enough to select good questions. Show questions that exceed a site’s median vote count by a certain proportion. I like guaranteeing that every site gets at least one question on the list every so often.

Comment: @user000001 Content should be "good", not "optimized for clicks". I firmly believe such a focus is better for everyone over the long term, including raw business/traffic for SE.

Comment: Exactly. Optimizing for clickbait is one root cause of the problem here. If a community legitimately believes that a question is one of their best questions that highlights what they're all about, that's something that should be showcased more than a question that happens to generate clicks because it's salacious or eye-catching.

Comment: Guaranteed slots will cause problems with slow sites such as Community Building or Windows Phone: the single-digit-per-month question rate means that *every* upvoted question on those sites will show up on HNQ, and will spend considerable amounts of time there.

Comment: @Mark That *could* be a problem; there definitely needs to be a workaround in cases where the site get's ~1 question per week. Some people have suggested promoting old (or unanswered) questions, which could be a nice substitute in those instances.

Comment: @Mark could the time-frame from which HNQ candidates are drawn be scaled to question-rate? I.e. on Mathematics (huge site) HNQ draws might come from only the last 24 hours; on sports (1.3 Q/day) the draw comes from the last month? 0.1 Q/day... I dunno. Not exactly sure how that site exists, to be honest.

Comment: Perhaps squareroot(Q/day), or [erf(Q/day)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function) Something monotonic, smooth, but still less-than-linear.

Answer (score 109):

## Please, *please* get rid of the clickbait

When you say this

> they've been sufficient for ensuring [...] overt clickbait was kept out of the list for the most part

y'all are just utterly fooling yourselves and/or burying your heads in the sand. HNQ *absolutely* selects for clickbait. It's what makes it tick — it wouldn't be what it is right now without it. And it's what fills it with terrible posts instead of picking stuff from the vast barrels of useful content on the network.

And, frankly, it's an absolute shame.

- Stack Exchange shines because of its quality content.
- Clickbait just isn't quality content. (And even if it *was* quality content originally, if you just slap a clickbait title on it and show it to enough people, that deluge of traffic that's uninterested in the real qualities of the content is just going to skew it so much that it ceases to be.)

So what on Earth is clickbait doing on Stack Exchange? We've been calling the sidebar the SE-Wide Advertisement for General Enlightenment for some time now.

(Which isn't to say that it is always dreadful, and indeed I'm not above hijacking some of the HNQ mechanisms if it helps produce an effective piece of science communication. But it's a mistake to put the cart before the horse, i.e., to emphasize the make-HNQ-do-good-things aspect above the don't-let-HNQ-do-awful-stuff part.)

The key problem with HNQ that causes it to select so strongly on clickbait is its intrinsic dependence on a positive-feedback loop:

- If a question is on the list, it gets a bunch of traffic which brings with it a bunch of upvotes for the questions and the answers.
- The 'hotness' score that determines whether a question stays on the list is a direct measure of how many upvotes it gets.

The clickbaitier the title, the more traffic, the more upvotes, the higher the question and answer scores, the higher the 'hotness' scores, the longer the question stays around, the more the traffic, and round and round it goes until the votes saturate. You're basically trying to fight a positive exponential with an algebraic time decay, and if you were paying attention in math class, you know who wins that fight. And, moreover, the exponent on that exponential is basically just how clickbaity the title is. Way to go.

This isn't a new observation, either — by sheer coincidence, [Breaking the HNQ feedback loop on bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286020/breaking-the-hnq-feedback-loop-on-bad-questions) is on the brink of turning two years old, with *zero* attention or engagement from the SE community or dev teams. If you guys had turned up and said "but perfooooormaaaaance" at the time, then we'd have had the opportunity to convince you that you're wrong about that.

Anyways, I stand by my proposed solution to the positive-feedback problems from two years ago:

> Let association-bonus users vote on HNQs, but don't count those votes and views into whatever algorithm does the decision that a question is Hot.

Cut the feedback loop, and see the exponential die out.

And of course, since you've spent a great deal of time detailing how performance constraints are a real solution-buster in these parts, let me spend some time detailing how those constraints don't apply to this solution. The modified-hotness score is indeed a much more expensive construct, absolutely, but here's the thing:

> You only need to calculate the modified-hotness score for a few hundred questions at a time.

Internally within each site, use the regular hotness score. (Or tweak it, if required.) You only need to start discarding association-bonus votes from the hotness scores *after* it gets on the list, and those are a manageable set.

This comes down to a point [made by gnat earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316960/184688): the dev team's attitude over the past few years has consistently had notes of looking at the fanciest way to implement the requested feature, saying "that's not doable", and then shutting down their involvement with the discussion. Instead of, as gnat suggests, looking at the resources you do have and then looking at what can be achieved with those.

Comment: *…fills it with terrible posts…* a bit hyperbolic, there have been some very interesting questions that have piqued my curiosity, questions on SE Workplace and Accademia to mention but two. If questions are always so bad, people would stop visiting HNQ

Comment: Of course it's not "full" of terrible posts in the sense that 100% of what's on the list is terrible. But would certainly put down money on that 90% of the time, 5% of the list is stuff that really shouldn't be there, and it's those posts that persist the longest.

Comment: And as for that last sentence - that's not how clickbait works. The internet is full of sites that use misleading titles to funnel audiences to content that the audience itself knows it probably doesn't want to see. It's a pervasive and well-known problem with the internet. SE generally strives to be better than the average but in this aspect it's dropped the ball significantly.

Comment: What would you say if the title was clickbaity, but the content was more than valid? Good questions sometimes need a hook in the title to catch people's attention. SE developers do it all the time! See the cheese question that is still attracting new answers as we speak,  have you seen the number of views on that Q?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The cheese question is Featured and not HNQ - it is a straw man. I'm happy to discuss but I won't discuss straw men.

Comment: There are plenty of meta posts that use clickbaity titles but whose content is valid and deserve our attention. I'm not going to condemn someone on a smaller site who wants to attract visitors to their question b/c they have created a catchy title. It's the content that matters in the end. Great title but sh**ty content gets closed pretty quickly in my experience.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It sounds like you either don't understand what clickbait *is*, or you do understand it and you don't care about its presence, in which case we'll have to agree to disagree. I *do* condemn someone who is happy to write a mis-representative title in order to draw traffic, and I think that should not have a place on SE. There's a difference between "catchy" titles that are honest about the question's contents even when taken completely out of context (it *is* possible to write them) and clickbait. The latter should have no place on SE.

Comment: OK, maybe my understanding is flawed. Can you please give a few examples of clickbait titles that hit the HNQ and enjoyed unmerited upvotes so I may understand better.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Try "By 18 years of age, I want a brand new car that's $43,668", or "I slept with my advisor's daughter and she is blackmailing me now. What can I do?" or half of the posts [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4410). But providing a good listing is hampered by the fact that there is no reliable HNQ log (which we've complained about for years).

Comment: if I understood correctly, and I won't bother you any further after this, the meta post is implying that one user is making up scenarios in order to win rep. So, it's not just the titles which are suspect but entire posts, and maybe the user themself is "fake". I agree, knowing how many Qs actually entered HNQ would be useful to know, as it is only the number of views accumulated gives some kind of indication.

Comment: *If a question is on the list, it gets a bunch of traffic which brings with it a bunch of upvotes for the questions and the answers.* and *The 'hotness' score that determines whether a question stays on the list is a direct measure of how many upvotes it gets*: That can be circumvented: once in the HNQ, no longer consider this question as a *future* candidate. Together with limiting the maximum period (as Monica C suggested), it will drop out earlier. This may be what you mean with "cut the feedback loop".

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't see the difference between what you're saying and keeping a strict and short timeout, but yes, that'd be another way to cut the feedback loop.

Comment: I can't say I ever remember seeing a clickbait entry. Clickbait would be a link that lies about its contents. As titles on every site are usually edited to reflect the question, I don't see why clickbait would be a problem.

Comment: @trlkly Out of curiosity, would you consider a title like "Ten terrible SE question titles that nevertheless made the HNQ list" (where the question contained exactly that) to be clickbait? (Or, to make this explicit: your definition of clickbait differs significantly from any widely-accepted ones.)

Comment: @EP No. I would consider it a listicle, and would consider those also undesirable. That said, I've also never seen those in the HNQ list.

Comment: Re: "Let association-bonus users vote on HNQs", are you referring specifically to people with a rep score of 101 on that site? Just because someone got the association bonus doesn't mean they're not actively engaged with the other site.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy I don't understand your comment. I am *not* proposing any changes to who can vote on what. I am proposing that the hotness score disregard any upvotes that come from users who, absent their association bonus, would not be able to upvote, i.e. the same sort of deal as with protected questions - you have to earn 15 rep in the site itself for your upvotes to be counted towards the hotness score.

Comment: @E.P. That's exactly what I wanted to know. +1

Comment: I think this answer is right on target. Featuring clickbait on the HNQ just attracts new users that enjoy clickbait. These shouldn't be the people we are trying to attract. We want users that actually care about the site and will uphold the quality standards. Showing clickbait just makes other users think it's ok. I think we should dispense with view count. Views just focus on who clicks the link. What we really need to do is sort by new questions with a high score, a few highly voted answers, none upvoted by the OP, and no accepts. That way we get good questions that we want people to...

Comment: ...join the site and answer, instead of taking a look at it and then leaving or posting a spam answer. Those kinds of questions actually need answers and are important to the users of that site (we know because of the upvotes)

Comment: @JohnLocke Note that views don't enter into the current 'hotness' score - [only votes do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/184688).

Comment: @E.P. Ok, maybe we do need some more advanced filtering than. I guess click-bait-y answers get a lot of upvotes by virtue of having more views. Maybe it could be based on the proportion of upvotes to views. Then again, because it's clickbait, people would upvote it more frequently. Maybe I should ask if clickbait answers get more upvotes compared to views than normal posts. That will be important in determining how to select non-clickbait questions.

Comment: @trlkly well, sometimes factual title can also still be clickbait without knowing context... like, [How can I kill adorable animals?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24345/), which I believe it's also upvoted because of the title (interesting), not because the voters play the game (usefulness).

Comment: I think the SE concept dictates this: if a bad question goes to the HNQ, then it should get a lot of downs, which should expel it from the HNQ. However, not this happens: HNQ questions typically get a lot of ups, independently from their quality. | Note also, that the SE needs clicks. I see that as an inherent conflict of interest between the high-rep, typically deletionist users of the sites and the SE. The OP couldn't mention it explicitly on obvious reasons.

Comment: @peterh Part of the reason for that is that HNQ visitors with no other site activity CAN upvote, but CANNOT downvote. So there's no way for me to express "this is actually bad" unless I'm a prior member of that site.

Answer (score 99):

I wasn't going to go out on a limb but since a statement has been made...

> The list of questions is generated through a very expensive query, cached, and refreshed on a set schedule. Giving moderators or even community managers the ability to 'evict' a problematic title while keeping the system in check with what we consider performant and sane are .. **mutually-exclusive goals**.

...I would like to address that.

This is technically inaccurate up to the point of being totally misleading, as was explained in multiple prior discussions, eg [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247195/165773), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273288/165773), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247948/165773) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196204/165773).

Whatever feedback from community / moderators we would want to take into account, reasonably close "approximate" solution can be achieved with negligible (constant time) performance impact.

Specifically, system can first pick larger than 100 (that is 150, 200, 300 etc) amount of "candidate" questions for the hot list using *the very same query as it uses now* - and this step will be as performant as it is now.

And at the second step, system could take into account whatever feedback / adjustments we would want to make on these candidate questions (fixed amount of them, meaning it's a *constant time cost*) and filter out 100 final questions to pass to the hot list.

---

While we're at it, there is another myth that hasn't been mentioned yet but is quite likely to pop up in further discussion, namely that it is prohibitively difficult to track and share meaningful information about questions that get to hot list - such as changes in views, votes, "hotness score" etc.

This is based on a statement that hot questions change way too frequently (every few minutes) so that retrieving, storing, and using much details about 100 questions at such a high rate is not feasible. While compelling on a surface, this reasoning is not really bulletproof because if you think of it, it is not absolutely necessary to catch up at such a high rate to get usable tracking data.

It is entirely possible to get reasonably solid "approximation" by [sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)) at much lower rate - we could retrieve desired details once in 1, 2, 5, 10 etc hours - and that would give us totally manageable amount of data that would be close enough to use in whatever way we would want.

For example, this "downsampled" tracking data could be used to inform site moderators of questions that likely entered hot list in a few recent hours. This data can be also stored and later used for historical analysis, and since sampling rate is low, this won't be too hard resource wise. Etc etc etc.

---

Speaking of goals for having HNQ, as of now I don't have strong preferences about this. Main point of this answer is to explain that whatever goal we set here, there will likely be *technically feasible* way to implement and track things "approximating" it with reasonable accuracy.

You know, it sometimes looks like SE team invents artificially complicated problems as if to justify doing nothing when it comes to hot questions. The starting post of this very discussion seems to be yet another case of that kind. Here I am talking about obsession with problematic titles and how it is difficult to deal with these.

But really, this seem to be missing one simple question, what makes clickbait titles stick so much in the hot list? For those who know how system works the answer is obvious: these titles by their very nature tend to attract multiple answers and the system is currently configured to make it count most.

Titles are totally secondary here and those who pay attention to stuff that gets to hot list can remember examples proving that - specifically "big list" questions (at sites allowing these) easily get and stick into the list despite having fairly bland titles - purely because of many answers.

[Two IPS questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdh5S.jpg) that started recent turmoil make good example: one of these was fairly old but system still kept it in the hot list because it had ten answers. This is because question with that many answers can easily have "hotness score" many times higher than one with, say, 3-5 answers: ["The benefit of many answers is capped at 10"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/165773).

- <sup>Visitors of hot questions and maybe especially regulars of the sites that contribute most to the hot list may wonder why system is configured that way, why it keeps accounting for answers up to 10 and not to some other number. To understand that you need to realise that this was set many years ago when hot list was totally different, it was almost exclusively dominated by questions from about handful technically oriented sites. Back then, this parameter didn't really matter much so I guess it was picked without much thinking - and worked fairly well until SE network has grown and much expanded with new topics.</sup>

You see, above suggests that thing worth trying is to change that old parameter in hotness score formula from 10 to something like 3 or 4 or 5. This has a good chance to tame artificial domination of clickbait titles. Especially if you take into account that *per se*, these titles are more likely at disadvantage because many active regulars at hosting sites consider such titles poor and vote down for this reason. It is only that outdated setting in the system that sticks them in hot list, totally inorganically.

Though given how two issues mentioned before were handled I would expect this natural approach to be ignored. Instead we will probably see team wasting efforts on something like inventing regexes to detect possible sexual interpretation of the title or trying to involve target site regulars in cumbersome race to catch and edit this stuff manually before it starts bothering [our Twitter overlords](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/318341/165773). Maybe they will even block other sites besides IPS, "because titles".

Comment: ...whatever goal we set here, there will be _technically feasible_ way to implement and track things "approximating" it with reasonable accuracy - so that the only reason that it won't be achieved will be lack of desire of Stack Exchange team to do anything in that regard :)

Comment: +10 for your middle section. We've been heading towards HNQcalypse for years, and it's been obvious for a long time that the more we waited, the bigger the trouble would be. Many of us have been yelling as hard as we could for a way to get data on HNQs, to absolutely no avail despite the obvious solutions presented and linked here. And now that the trouble's erupted, we have no reliable past data on what's actually been on the list. The whole thing just blows my mind, frankly.

Comment: Well said. There are certainly technical constraints on any solution, but this needs to be addressed from first principles to come up with what we think is the right approach, and then worry about whether that can be handled within the bounds of reasonable performance. As [SE staff has straight-up said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199006/346672), the HNQ system was cobbled together based on what's easy to query rather than an actual design for what's right for the site. Maybe it's worth investing in dedicated infrastructure, if necessary, for HNQ given its apparent importance to the site.

Comment: "many active regulars at hosting sites consider such titles poor and vote down for this reason" - except those downvotes don't have anywhere near the weight that they should have for this. If the formula were changed from `Score` to something like, say, `UpvoteCount - 5 * DownvoteCount` then the opinions of those community members could count all that much more. (That multiplier is a bit arbitrary, but remember how an upvote gives you five times more rep than a downvote removes?)

Comment: I'd upvote again for the titles thing if I could, though.

Comment: Over sampling and then filtering on a per site basis (no questions from IPS on SO for instance) would seem to make this technically a minor issue.

Answer (score 89):

I submit that HNQ is fundamentally broken. Why? Because it is about *Hot* Network Questions. That is, questions which are getting lots of attention.

Just look at your #1 goal: increase site discovery. Questions which get lots of attention rarely represent the best of a site. Controversial questions are "hot", and therefore will attract people attracted to that controversy. But are such people going to become regular users of the site?

No. Or worse... *yes*. I say that them staying is worse because people who are attracted to controversy are people who will inevitably *create* controversy (or at least fuel it). And that's not what we're supposed to be doing here.

Worst-case, controversial questions can give people the wrong idea of the culture or scope of a site. This is also why your #2 goal is problematic. Reassessing the scope of a site should not be done due to a mob of people who randomly showed up thanks to an algorithm. It should be done carefully and deliberately.

And all of this comes down to "Hot" questions. If we want to attract the right sort of people to a site, then that can only be done by promoting questions that demonstrate the best face of the site, not merely the one that has attracted lots of attention.

Comment: *I say that them staying is worse*. People **can** come to different insights, maybe especially so if they see what the quality of the site is.

Comment: interesting analysis of implications if we choose discovery as a goal of HNQ, this looks worth a bounty

Comment: The fact that "Hot Network Questions" does not correlate with "Good Questions on Other Sites" or even "Typical Questions on Other Sites" does call into question whether users are getting the right impression when they discover a site.

Comment: Some sites could end up blocking all external traffic by trying to 'demonstrate the best face of the site'. On Physics (and most science/math/programming sites), the community inside loves the deeper posts which deal with more technically intricate concepts, but the HNQs are usually popular-science which is really basic (basic enough for outsiders to understand; surely you'll empathize) and took authors (including me) very little effort and knowledge to write. To show the best face of the site, I'd try to stop most of that from going HNQ.

Comment: @Thunderforge that's a good point, I've seen bunch of comments under other answers where users complained about how hot questions misrepresent their sites. This strongly indicates that current way is poor for discovery. Stack Overflow folks also appear to unhappy about these matters, see eg [Why are so many useless questions ranked highly, and vice versa?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287163/839601) and a bunch of other meta discussions linked to it. Though it is probably less of an issue over there because system was hacked to push SO questions off the hot list after 7-8 hours

Comment: @Chair: "*Some sites could end up blocking all external traffic by trying to 'demonstrate the best face of the site'.*" I trust the users of a site to be able to determine what represents their best face better than an algorithm. And if that best face isn't the popular face... so be it. That allows the community to define itself, not be defined by one random question that attracted a bunch of people one time.

Comment: @NicolBolas Exactly, the community's defining itself and everyone's happy with what's displayed and voted on, but is that what SE wants? That doesn't align with the people saying they want to find new sites where they like the content.

Comment: @Chair: "*the community's defining itself and everyone's happy with what's displayed and voted on, but is that what SE wants?*" Um, what? The current system does not allow community's to define themselves; they're defined by an algorithm that, by design, tends to select for controversy, not *quality*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh, no, I was ambiguous. That stuff about the communities defining themselves is a description of what would happen _if_ the system where communities make a conscious decision to send some questions for HNQs is implemented.

Answer (score 81):

I hate sounding pessimistic since it's really not my style, nor do I want to tread in already covered ground that Monica and Magisch have already broached.  But I will say this much:  I'm not sure that we're really having a "discussion" about this.  This is more of a venting period, and then we all move on from it.

As evidenced by...

> Suffice to say, the HNQ (as we know it) **is now looking at numbered days**, but that number is probably kind of high because it's going to take some work to figure out what voids would be worth filling **if we yanked it** as we know it now.

We're going to talk about this feature before we remove this feature.

Okay.

To be less sarcastic about this, I'll give you an outsider's perspective.  I was contemplating joining the IPS community *because* of the seemingly interesting topics that were being discussed.  I've even perused a handful of them and many of the answers provided seemed insightful and useful.  Some of those titles wouldn't be ones I would *want* to click at work, but even then, I'm an adult and I know that the Internet is full of content which may be inflammatory or spark a heated discussion, so I've worked around this by...simply not paying it much attention while at work, and leaving an open tab to come back to it when I have a quiet moment on break.

Kinda like browsing Facebook or Reddit.

<sup>And no soul here can say they've never done either of those activities while at work.</sup>

But it seems to be fairly standard practice nowadays with Stack Exchange that someone from outside of the network decides to point out a flaw or two, and changes happen overnight whereas well-thought discussions or communities willing to talk about these issues are simply...well, abandoned.

The Stack Exchange network's greatest strength is its community.  Brushing that aside is proving to be the greatest single mistake that's been made.

[I get it; we're not the most pleasant bunch of people to solicit feedback from.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373218/1079354)  We're passionate, obstinate at times and think we know better.  But shutting out an entire community from the discussion around this whole thing was a backhanded move, even *if* the whole HNQ flow is broken and even *if* it was going to be the right thing to do.

---

And I know I said I didn't want to sound pessimistic, but that's kind of how I feel about this whole thing now.  You're going to do what you see fit with this feature.  I could come up with some new ideas as to what the actual point of this whole feature is, and prove where it's strongest and weakest, as well as allowing people to see this content if they opt in to it.

But I'm not convinced you'll listen to me or anyone else in this discussion.

Prove me wrong.  Please.

Comment: +1 for "But I'm not convinced you'll listen to me or anyone else in this discussion. Prove me wrong. Please."

Answer (score 73):

## Please don't listen to Twitter

It seems that SE management is giving tweets a higher priority than community feedback. Just as an example: the Code of Conduct has been triggered by tweets, not by community discussion or by management decision. It seems, that if we want change on SE to happen, we have to tweet our wishes, and SE management will listen. One tweet has obviously more weight than 1000 meta posts.

## How should we deal with complaints from Twitter?

If you think a complaint from Twitter is right, just post about it on Meta and resolve it from there. A tweet must not hold more weight than a comment or question or answer on a meta site.

**I think it is a big shame that tweets have so much power upon Stack Exchange Management.**

It seems like the priorities of SE management are:

- make feminists on Twitter happy
- make new users feel welcome
- listen to the community

in this order. SE says that they value their long term community members. **But actions speak louder than words.** I ask for a change. I'm angry and annoyed. Would you listen to my anger if I posted it on Twitter? My trust in SE management has just gone away.

Comment: Yes. Even though a lot of the detailed criticism which provoked the CoC was on Medium, it's the tweets which directed all the attention in that direction. Tweets should only be treated as evidence for the existence of certain opinions outside. It fits with what IPS members wanted: they wished that the decision had been made on meta, even if it's an SE person saying, "hey guys, this is what people are being made to think. Perhaps we need the change after all.'

Comment: Downvoted for two reasons. 1) Being attractive to new users is important to SE, especially for beta sites.  It's important for SE's management to pay attention to how the sites are perceived outside -- potential users and new users give us valuable insight that long-term users can't have because they've become too close to the site.  2) Your comment about 'feminists on Twitter' is hostile to those of us who use SE *and* Twitter and are feminists.  Feminists have every right to participate on SE as much as you, and I don't appreciate you implying that you are normal and feminists aren't.

Comment: @JanMurphy While feminists have rights to participate they have to play by the rules. If they start twitter wars instead of going thru defined process they do not deserve to be heard here (unless they complain about unfair bans and thing like that).

Comment: If Stack Overflow was dripping fabric softener all over people, and a feminist said STOP DRIPPING FABRIC SOFTENER ALL OVER ME, listening to them isn't catering to feminists. Nor is listening to someone reporting content on the site that we must assume is inappropriate for work or a shared family computer until the user expressly says it's no big deal (by visiting those sites). Our reaction would have been the same if you had reported it on Twitter _and_ we saw it. The fact that Kelly's voice is amplified had a lot to do with us seeing it, but not the decision.

Comment: @TimPost The backlash isn't so much from the fact that it seems to be listening to someone with an agenda outside of SE, but the fact that these problems have been brought up for *years* here, and they've just been ignored entirely.  Are we happy that it took someone that seems that hostile to SE to actually get the changes made?  Nope.  But we're less trusting than ever, because it seems like there's no way for us to actually effect positive change, using the very platform you've given for that purpose.  Communication and trust are very much on the wane.

Comment: @talex Feminists are not some separate/special group of beings; it is just a label applied to humans who think men and women should have equal rights and treatment. Also, one person does not make the rule, rather they are an exception.

Comment: @TimPost So are you saying Adam Lear is the employee who has to see a problem report before the company can act on it? And are you saying he doesn't read MSE/MSO ever? If the decision to remove IPS from the HNQ list is based on you guys *seeing* a problem report about it, then I expect it would have been removed a *long* time ago.

Comment: @TylerH: I think that men and women should have equal rights and treatment. And I don't consider myself a feminist. In fact, *because* I think that men and women should have equal rights and treatment, I chose not to be one. And furthermore, there are two types of feminism: type 1 is about what the recent nobel peace price winners did to get the price. type 2 is what we see here. I think it is bad that we don't have two separate words for two totally different phenomena.

Comment: @TylerH: Do you have any idea how rude *you* actually are? Anyone who doesn't claim to be a feminist is misogynist and sexist in your eyes.

Comment: We're losing track of the main issue here. There are times when it is useful to pay attention to what the outside community said. It's like this. You are living with your dad. You've taken a fire safety class and you know that your dad shouldn't have a bunch of greasy shop rags lying about because it's a hazard. You tell him, but he's set in his ways and doesn't want to listen.  Now the rags are on fire, and your next door neighbor is yelling at your dad that the garage is burning.  At this point, do you really want to say your dad shouldn't listen to the neighbor because he isn't family?

Comment: You said, "It seems like the priorities of SE management are:  Make feminists on Twitter happy.   Make new users feel welcome.   Listen to the community."  Yes yes yes! That is EXACTLY the feeling most of us have. As an added bonus, you have the "new contributor" label right now so your voice counts for more than mine.  Doubt they'll listen either way though :/

Comment: @TylerH there are lot of different groups that call them self a feminists. Those groups have completely different views. You represent one of those group. Why do you think only your group have copyright to feminism? But that's off-topic here.

Comment: @talex There are many different groups that call themselves feminists like there are many different people who misuse the term as Michael did. Misuse of a term does not validate it.

Comment: @TylerH: it is also about priorities. You seem to think it is more important to keep the name of feminism holy than it is to condemn the behaviour of these women. This just makes me assume that you think that what they did is actually not that bad. Or that you think that my misuse of the word feminism is worse than actually harassing a man over a sexual issue. Maybe I'm wrong though, but then why not just saying "I am a feminst and I think what these women did is totally unacceptable" - such a statement would have more weight for me than any wikipedia articles.

Comment: @TylerH if you didn't notice there is more thing associated with feminism then just "just a label applied to humans who think men and women should have equal rights and treatment". You can try to ignore that, but it will only lead to miscommunication. For example: you may not like it but a lot of people associate "everything is sexist" with feminism. You can say that (at least I hope you do) that people who say "everything is sexist" is not real feminist, but I suggest you to think about why that happens first. And you are sure that you don't misuse that term after all?

Comment: @TylerH You would struggle to find a single living person raised in western society who wouldn't characterise themselves as supporting gender equality. By your definition, then, we all here are feminists, and the word is essentially useless. Yet we all know that in reality somebody described or self-identifying as a "feminist" predicts many more political positions than merely approving of gender equality in the abstract. An extensional definition of "anti-feminist", consisting of "opposition to the positions that mainstream society typically labels as feminist", is therefore more useful.

Comment: @TylerH Or, to come at it another way: when me and Michael mean when we say "feminism", we mean support for the cluster of ideas that includes (among many other things) safe spaces, trigger warnings, affirmative action, "believe all victims", reduced burdens of proof specific for sexual crimes, tax exemptions for menstrual products, that the "tech" industry is especially sexist against women, gender quotas at conferences, affirmative consent, and that gender-blindness is an unacceptable approach for an individual or institution to take to gender politics. Assuming that you agree that ... [1/2]

Comment: @TylerH [2/2] ... this is a real and recognisable cluster of political ideas that many people label as "feminism" and embrace or reject as a whole, then what do you want those of us who oppose the entire cluster to describe ourselves as, if not "anti-feminists"? And are you also rejecting our characterisation of "welcoming" ideas on Stack Exchange (like "criticism of posts needs to be softened since it especially discourages women" or "it's offensive and alienates women for a question title to portray some female sexual behaviour as problematic") as belonging in this same cluster?

Comment: @TimPost Your fabric softener example is predicated on the problematic behaviour being one that ordinary people would find objectionable for non-ideological reasons. But these Twitter feminists' objection to the posts in question was that it was "sexist" for IPS to allow the two questions they screenshotted to be posted - as I understand it, because they portrayed female sexual behaviour negatively - and therefore alienating to women to allow that sexism to be visible on the main site. That's a uniquely ideological objection, and - given that none of the parties involved object to [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] discussion of problematic *male* sexual behaviour - a pretty objectionably sexist one, as well. There's a significant difference between "we acted on a complaint that just happened to come from a member of ideology X" and "we acted on a complaint that was inherently rooted in (a fairly extreme and openly discriminatory interpretation of) ideology X, while openly supporting the motivation behind it". It seems to me that Michael would have no beef with the former, but that's not what happened, and I think your dismissal fails to really engage with his complaint.

Comment: @MarkAmery No, simply claiming to support X doesn't make you X; your actions are more important. Everyone would hopefully claim to support equality between men and women but it's clear here and everywhere else that not everyone actually does. Also, I haven't dismissed anything; my comments here are criticizing the mischaracterization of women he used to lay out his position.

Comment: @TylerH Sure, I guess we could each define whether a person is feminist by whether we would personally characterise that person's beliefs as serving the ideal of gender equality. But even if we all agreed to that approach, it still wouldn't permit "feminist" to be a remotely useful term; it would just mean that the group that most of society labels as "feminist" would continue to go around calling themselves feminists, while people like me would go around claiming that actually *we* are the real feminists and the other side are highly anti-feminist. Doesn't exactly produce a legible debate.

Answer (score 71):

The fact that an entire site could be blacklisted from the Hot Network Questions list by *a single SE employee* because they saw someone complain on Twitter about the word "flirting" and the phrase "sleep with me" appearing on the HNQ list is *highly* disturbing. Using this new standard, we need to blacklist most of the other popular sites as well. In no particular order:

### Workplace

"How can I stop a college from flirting with me?"  - would be on topic as long as it related to workplace interactions. But let's not consider hypotheticals. There are some great examples of actual questions!

*"[How should I deal with an employee who has slept with my wife?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/7617)"* is the second highest voted question on the site.

There [are also questions about flirting](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/83572).

And if we're strictly talking about question titles looking bad out of context, there is *"[How can I prepare for getting hit by a bus?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9128)*".

Sure, these could be overlooked as not too serious. So let’s look at some other examples!

### Academia

Academia has some great examples as well:

*"[Had sex with a student of mine, how to proceed now?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/117263)"*

*"[I slept with my advisor's daughter and she is blackmailing me now. What can I do?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/116226)"*

This second one was actually on the HNQ list for a few days, before being closed - long after the question had gotten its attention.

### Travel

This site has a few titles that would look great out of context:

*"[Is it permitted to ask questions of female sex workers in Thailand to be familiar with their real life as a tourist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/19564)"*

*"[Are laws about sex outside marriage less rigorously enforced in Dubai for people on layovers?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16040)"*

### Role-Playing Games

Not as bad, but still an example:

*"[As a DM, is it improper of me to flirt with one of my players 'off the clock'?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132667)"*

### Movies

*"[Are Terminator robots able to have sex?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/57339)"*

*"[Mimi knows she has HIV but still wants to have sex with Roger?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/24856)"*

### World Building

*"[How can a demon who feeds on sex survive in the modern world without exposing itself?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/81202/9186)"*

*"[How can a parasite that feeds on sex take over a human biochemically?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/121248/9186)"*

*"[how can you place limits on sex-fueled magic?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/122506/9186)"*

### Science Fiction & Fantasy

*"[Artificial organ on humans for sex?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/151158/43794)"*

*"[How does human-robot sex work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/19323/43794)"*

*"[Can Bruce Banner Have Sex Without Becoming the Hulk?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59344/43794)"*

### Parenting

This answer is to make the point that IPS was not a problem, it was merely an indicator of the flawed HNQ system. I hesitate to bring up these next examples because with the various changes SE has been making recently, they *might actually* blacklist Parenting.

*"[My son is 5 years old and sexually active](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/6283)"*

*"[How do parents have sex when there's a toddler in the house?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/8258)"*

*"[Sex play in young children](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/3557)"*

*"[My daughter is having sex with her cousin](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/20237)"*

*"[Is it possible for an 8 year girl to be sexually abused and enjoy it?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/23611)"*

*"[My son's girlfriend has been cheating with my best friend's son. Should I get involved?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/34934)"*

*"[How do I change my son's views, after he confessed to me that he rather be with prostitutes over having an actual girlfriend?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/32468)"*

### Law

This is another site that I hesitate to bring up in light of the recent decisions made by SE, but it has great examples.

*"[Did my girlfriend rape me? Sexual assault? Nothing?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/28105)"*

*"[If an adult is raped by a minor, is it statutory rape?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15018)"*

*"[Is it rape to have sex with a man without disclosing that one is a male-to-female transgender?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/23845)"*

*"[If two individuals who are too drunk to give consent have sex are both guilty of rape?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/17646)"*

*"[Posting Sex Offender Information Online](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/14782)"*

*"[The legality of fictional stories involving sex with minors](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/3664)"*

---

The statement "Let's ignore sites with these titles" isn't being applied fairly. It seems that all we need to do now is start posting on Twitter about how *offended* we are. After all - if the above sites contain content like *that* and can still appear on the HNQ list, someone might post a similar question, it might get on the HNQ list, and someone who doesn't want to take the effort to look at the context of the question could be ***offended!***

### Is this a side effect of trying to be "welcoming" to everyone?

Comment: Don't even get me started on Arqade; we positively *delight* in misleading titles.

Comment: How can you not mention [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66538)? That site was literally classified as porn at one point. :P

Comment: @Laurel I wasn't aware of that happening to Mathematica - was it because of a bunch of question titles that would fit here? XD

Comment: I like your point but, to be honest, there is definitively title here that I wouldn't want to see on my HNQ list (the ones about sexual assault) and I absolutely hope that they are *already banned* from the HNQ list.

Comment: @Noon I fully agree that questions like that shouldn't be on the HNQ list, since they absolutely *do* look bad out of context. But my main point was that if SE seriously wants to use the logic that they stated in the question, "Now that we have gotten to the point where we've gone from saying 'Let's ignore titles with these words..' to 'Let's ignore sites with these titles..'" They'd have to ignore most of the well known sites on the network, because basically any site could have titles that look bad out of context.

Comment: My word! That's some question list you've compiled there! I really hope no-one tweets it out!

Comment: @X-27: I don't understand the purpose of this answer. The question is not stating that banning IPS or a few keywords is expected to fix everything. The question is asking about ways to move forward in a way that things like this don't happen. That is, how to *fix* the HNQ so that it has the effects they want but without the downsides like what happened with IPS. They're *going* to overhaul it; the question is merely how to do that.

Comment: I was expecting controversial question titles from mathoverflow as well, bummer. That would be hilarious xD

Comment: a recent example from Writing.SE: [What is a subtle way of mentioning one got an erection?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/39983) (title was edited after it has been sitting _erected_ for about a day at the top of the hot questions list)

Answer (score 68):

**Put the decision to participate in the hands of the community**

Some sites have asked to be excluded from the HNQ. Giving sites the choice to put themselves onto the existing blacklist might be useful, and would involve the community that has to shoulder most of the negative side effects into the decision.

**Give the community a way to experiment with the exact formula**

This might not be possible with a reasonable amount of effort, but it would be very interesting to have the ability to simulate alternative HNQ formulas. It would probably have to be based on a snapshot of data because it's expensive, but even that could help to find better ways to select HNQ.

**Allow users to collapse the HNQ sidebar**

Currently users don't have a choice whether they see the HNQ or not. Give them a choice, and there are fewer reasons to complain about inappropriate titles. If you don't want to see the HNQ, simply switch them off.

**Limit the self-reinforcing aspect of the formula**

A question with a lot of activity has a better chance to get into the HNQ. A question in the HNQ list often gets drastically more activity and votes than without it. Maybe only counting votes from users that have contributions on the site could help.

**Normalize between the sites better**

Some sites are clearly overrepresented in the list. Normalizing the formula for differences in voting behaviour and other factors might help to avoid focusing on the problematic sites so much, and bring some smaller sites into the spotlight.

Comment: For your first point, do you mean "Let sites choose whether their questions appear in the HNQ" or "Let sites choose whether the HNQ sidebar appears on their site by default"?  Both seem potentially reasonable to me.  Most people on SO are there to solve a programming problem and probably don't want to see questions about flirting in the sidebar.  People on worldbuilding.se are probably more open to seeing an interesting title and going "ooh that looks fun let's read it."

Comment: @A_S00 let the site choose whether their own questions appear in the HNQ.

Comment: +1 for "Maybe only counting votes from users that have contributions on the site could help."  That's a great idea.

Comment: Please let me turn it off. its a major distraction. I'm easily distracted.

When I go to a programming site. I don't want to see questions about aliens, dating, physics, especially when I'm interested in the click bait title. The network is now far to diverse for my intrests to align with many others. The goals of HQQ is in direct conflict with the goals of getting information about my chosen reading field.

Comment: @Wildcard At first glance, yes, but that would make the query even more expensive with the temporal aspect dependent on other factors. In relational terms, a left outer join with a null check in addition to date filtering on an entity level. Worth it? Maybe.

Comment: @Physics-Compute designing according to what’s easiest to implement instead of what produces the most desirable result is the basis for all of HNQ’s problems of today.

Comment: @Wildcard Agreed. Correctness first.  I'll retract the "maybe" part. I definitely like the idea. Will just add that it may be a lot more expensive.

Answer (score 53):

#### Allow us to hide/show the HNQ sidebar and control which sites are allowed in it!

Like some others are saying, start with the HNQ list hidden, something like:

```
Hot Network Questions (show) ⚙️
```

On clicking "(show)," the usual list will drop down, showing only "non-controversial" sites (excluded sites like those you list in the main question). On clicking the settings gear, the user is taken to their "Site Preferences" page and scrolled down to the "HNQ Sidebar" section.

Here they can set whether the list is by default shown/hidden when the site is visited. They may also see which sites they allow to be shown and which they don't in their HNQ sidebar. Perhaps those sites we deem "controversial" will be marked so in the list (maybe with a link to see what some of those controversial questions may look like?).

This solution will do a couple things: it'll let those who like what we have now to keep what we have now, while letting those who want less HNQ in their lives to *have* less HNQ in their lives. This could also allow you to see **more** questions you like. Maybe you have the same length HNQ list regardless of how many sites you're watching, so now questions with fewer hotness points that would normally not make the full HNQ list will make your custom list!

<sup>**Note:** I think the contents of the HNQ list itself definitely need to be revisited as has been detailed in other answers, but this answer is focused on how we'll view that list.</sup>

Comment: It goes without saying that this has been [highly requested for many years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222721/how-to-avoid-hot-network-questions-on-the-sidebar); SE point-blank ignored the request, and a whole garden of client-side Ignore HNQ solutions sprung up. Imagine if it had been implemented back in 2014 - all those oodles of useful UX data about who likes the list and when that would be there when things came to a head.

Comment: +1. I like this approach, giving user the control to show and hide sites selectively. They may even go ahead and provide much finer control, such as giving us two lists with one curated for professional/academic environment and the other for non-professional environments. A drop down menu could help with selecting any list on the fly. However, this still doesn't address the clickbait questions in HNQ which gives a wrong impression of the quality content a site hosts.

Comment: @Firelord that to me seems like a Very Hard Problem. But I think regardless of how we solve that, I'd still want these additions. I'll edit my answer to make it clear I'm not addressing what should be considered a "HNQ"

Comment: One important thing to remember about a setting is it relies on people to know it exists and care enough to use it. While our power users might benefit from this, the majority of people who visit won't. They'll see uncomfortable or nonsense looking question titles in the sidebar and just be upset, because well, they *already saw them* and that leaves an impression regardless of what tools are available to hide them after the fact. Development time is usually better spent on prevention rather than curing. Would this feature be necessary or even useful if it didn't happen in the first place?

Comment: @animuson note that I’m advocating for the sidebar to default to both hidden and to not include “controversial sites.” Essentially if they want to prevent the average user from seeing these kinds of questions, then make it reversible for those users who want it or are curious enough to find it and give us some customization perks while you’re at it.

Comment: @animuson Then [make it discoverable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316934#comment1038685_316937). You guys are great at it, and you've already got plenty of tools that can be adapted to make this work well.

Comment: This. I use an adblock rule to hide the HNQ, to avoid endless browsing and heavy loss of productivity. Unfortunately, I only set it up on SO. As soon as I'm looking for an answer in another site, I slip and fall for a long time.

Comment: I currently use uBlock Origin to block HNQ. Firstly, I use SO extensively at work, and a good proportion of HNQ has no business showing up on my work PC. Secondly, HNQ is actively damaging to my ability to concentrate on the task I have at hand, at work or at home.

Comment: Joined just to agree with @ClementCherlin's point.  People unfamiliar with SE sites looking at your browser just see "Playing with the musical turtle", "When/how did Harry Truman give the order to bomb Hiroshima?", "How to increase a monster's CR without adjusting its flavour too much?" (picking the least work appropriate from my current HNQ list - it looks like you're browsing something inappropriate, or just skiving.

Comment: I use [this Tampermonkey script](https://gist.github.com/dmolesUC3/5c72950d2bf25d6e036e39b61a443686) to block the top 20 or 30 most annoying sites for HNQs, FWIW. (This should totally be an actual site feature.)

Answer (score 43):

HNQ is intended to show users other sites. There's no assumption that they'll be experts on the topic; the assumption is that they are simply interested. With that end goal in mind, some suggestions:

### Showcase older questions rather than currently active ones

Why does good content have to be current content? More often than not, current questions are undergoing some form of discussion to figure out what the questioner wants, and the traffic from HNQ just muddies that discussion. A two-day old, well-received question (upvoted question, upvoted answers) is probably a better way to showcase the site's best content.

### Choose just a few sites, show upvoted front page content there

Rather than choosing "hot network questions", only showcase a few sites (3-5) each pageload. On the next pageload you could showcase a different few sites. Over time each visitor will see a wide variety of content from a wide variety of sites.

Choose from either well-received current questions or—as per previous recommendation—well-received older questions. This rotation will still benefit sites, and over time visitors will see that there's more to this place than just <site they happen to be on>.

Comment: I like the first suggestion, I'm not sure on the second suggestion. Do you mean show rotate through all the sites but only show 3-5 at a time or only show 3-5 sites? The former isn't a bad idea though I'm not in favour of it, I don't like the latter at all.

Comment: This is unusual yet convincing. It would be very interesting to see what the rationale for choosing only new questions (less than 30 days old, if I recall) as HNQs. One of the arguments against HNqS is that wrong FastestGunInTheWest answers rise to the top, but if the question has been sitting there for a week (or so), it's likely that experienced/knowledgeable members have seen the content and reviewed this, which can, to a certain extent, prevent wrong content from rising unchecked if the question goes HNQ after that.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - Thanks for comment, sorry the second one is confusing. Edited to clarify.

Comment: To clarify, I'm voting up specifically for the first suggestion. I'm indifferent to the second.

Comment: first part looks like an original and promising approach, worth a bounty. "A two-day old, well-received question (upvoted question, upvoted answers) is probably a better way to showcase the site's best content" -- I am not sure about concrete value of proposed timeout but it certainly would be interesting to try delaying exposure of questions for few hours, to give hosting site community chance for initial evaluation and polishing before advertising the question to inexperienced network-wide audience

Comment: ***A two-day old, well-received question*** Who gets to select the two-day-old question? The system? Users with 10K or the mods? There's no guarantee that a highly upvoted question that survives longer than 48 hours  should be showcased. I know plenty of posts that attract 10 or more upvotes because they are fun to answer but show absolutely no effort on behalf of the OP and no research. Qs can be hugely popluar if they are spurred by current events (i.e. controversial)...

Comment: How often would this rota occur.  Once a week? Every three days?  What would be the criteria? If the mods choose, will they select the Qs according to personal preferences? (Watch the number of users complaining on meta about biased and prejudiced mods rise). Number of upvotes? Number of visitors? Number of answers? The quality of a single answer? Aren't we going back to the HNQ query again?

Comment: Two days cooling period is a great idea for absolutely most of the questions on the HNQ list. There are a few sites that discuss current events, for example [politics.se] may talk about current news, [security.se] about a recent vulnerability, or [movies.se] about a new film or episode. These aren't common and don't represent even the majority of questions on these sites, but it'd be a shame losing these questions, and it will be weird displaying them two days "late" - it might make the HNQ list stale.

Answer (score 42):

I'll add my 0.02€.

As prompted by the question, I'll start saying that I came to Aviation, the site I am now a mod of, through the HNQ.

I think that the list is a good tool to discover new sites, but given the following conditions:

- the user is in a setting that allows them to look for new sites, i.e.: not in an office
- the user is open to experience new sites
- the user is familiar with the network and knows/can guess before clicking where the question comes from

I'll expand on the last one, since I think it was behind the message that started this.

If a user only ever visits the network to go on SO, and has no idea that there are other sites beyond that, or is not even aware of the concept of "network sites", those questions tell them "this are good questions for a professional website like SO".
This is fine if they come from SU, or any other IT-related site, as the userbase will greatly overlap with SO, but is already less fine with sites like mine or Politics or Skeptics (examples of sites I frequent) because these can be seen as odd, given the environment.
"I am here to work, what is a question about the elections of a country I don't care about doing on the side of the page?" "I don't care about aircraft, why is that question there?".
At the end of the spectrum you have the reactions that started this: "oh, great, the site I come to for technical advice is filled with male tropes, how nice"

**Possible solution:**

1. hide the sidebar for new users by default
2. have a small panel saying "SO is part of a network of several sites, would you like to know more?"
3. if they want to know more, bring the user to a page where you clearly explain that in the network there are technical sites, as well as less technical ones
4. explain what the HNQ is and what they will see if they opt to see it
5. let a user opt-in the HNQ based on the macro categories you have [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions):

   - All
   - Technology
   - Culture / Recreation
   - Life / Arts
   - Science
   - Professional
   - Business

Comment: There would be another discussion to have then, and I am aware of it. e.g.: what's Academia doing in "Life/Arts"?

Comment: As to 5, frankly those macro categories can be quite inaccurate and also seem lacklusterly maintained, primarily based on the problem of many sites actually belonging to multiple categories equally well. I do professional technology business and watch cultural arts for recreation.

Comment: @ChristianRau sure, the categories are far from perfect and I'm the first to acknowledge that some sites could be miscategorised (see my comment above yours), but they are at least something.

Comment: I was about to write an answer essentially saying what you've got as point 2 - in this particular instance, there are later tweets (I think by a different tweeter) saying things like "website for dev questions" and "corner of SO" in the context of the HNQ, so part of the issue does seem to be that people aren't aware that SE is a network *which isn't just for devs and isn't just SO*

Comment: I agree with all of this except the categories.  Those are busted.  Maybe instead when they first opt in we show them sites with good affinity from the current one (SE has that data), and then they can take a second action to say "open the fire hose".  Or maybe we just jump to the fire hose.  But not the categories; there's more harm than good there.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm fine with those categories not being the ideal solution. This post wants to be a suggestion, if then we have better options, I'm ready to support those.

Answer (score 42):

There are plenty of answers here that explain problems with the almost NSFW nature of some of the questions, the promotion of click-bait titles and the positive feedback cycle introduced by the HNQ.

They are all about how the quality of one site is hurt by having inappropriate links to another site.

However, I want to emphasize at one particular aspect that bothers me more: the cost to the target site.

**While the HNQ might help a site by attracting new users to it, it is often actively harmful to the particular question that it links to.**

Even if the question is a genuinely good question that isn't click-bait, it can be hurt by making an appearance on the HNQ.

The HNQ attracts a lot of users who aren't from the target community. Their votes are wildly distorting and their answers and comments don't follow the community standards.

The site I frequent most, Skeptics.SE, gets hoards of users upvoting unreferenced, theoretical answers - especially if they are politically partisan - which is an anathema to the entire reason for the site.

But we are not alone. I see comments above such as these that I want to highlight:

> +1 The HNQ absolutely optimises for controversy. On RPG.SE the effect of a HNQ is often also pretty bad: if we've got a controversial, difficult topic it needs careful community cultivation, expert answers, and highly knowledgeable voters more than ever... Then it hits HNQ and we see an influx of dozens of votes upvoting poor advice in exponential proportion to whatever the scores already were, amplifying the fastest gun and drowning out up-and-coming better advice completely. That effect is a disservice to everyone and degrades the quality of help RPG.SE provides. – @doppelgreener [Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha?cb=1#comment1038363_316937)

and

> @doppelgreener: Philosophy has this problem as well. Controversial questions that have "God" in their title are regularly on the HNQ, even if they are ill-stated, unclear, etc. and attract a high number of opinionated comments and answers of which two-thirds have to be deleted. The only other things popping up there are similarly bad questions on evolution and quantum mechanics/free will. I have yet to see a well-stated question on philosophy in this list. Yes, it helps with traffic for smaller sites. But I doubt that it is traffic we want to have on these sites. – @PhilipKlöcking [Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha?cb=1#comment1038408_316937)

Many of the programming-related sites have the benefit that upvoting tends to be clear cut. Questions are only of interest to relevant experts, answers *tend* to be clear cut (they objectively work or they don't), and non-experts have no desire to jump in and express opinions or vote. They may welcome questions appearing on the HNQ, knowing that they will only attract other experts. Some of the other sites don't have that luxury.

---

What's the solution?

- The community needs a way to say "This question is receiving bad attention - stop advertising it."
- Reconsider approaches that don't assume people are experts in every field just because they are programmers - e.g.:

  - [The association bonus should not enable users to vote on every site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183109/the-association-bonus-should-not-enable-users-to-vote-on-every-site)
  - [Prevent 101 rep users from voting and commenting until 105 rep](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/prevent-101-rep-users-from-voting-and-commenting-until-105-rep)
  - [Prevent questions on Hot List from being upvoted by casual visitors (only rep is from association bonus)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238420/prevent-questions-on-hot-list-from-being-upvoted-by-casual-visitors-only-rep-is)
- Perhaps apply limits to what people can do when they come through the HNQ link.

Comment: some evidence of how HNQ hurt the target site can also be found in SE.SE meta discussion: [Recent Trouble With Popularity](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7525/31260). "While these questions were open, they were widely advertised on the Hot Network List and gained relatively high scores despite piling on of close votes. All of them are now closed, but due to their high scores they present appealing examples for newer site visitors to try their luck asking similar questions.

High scores send a fairly strong signal that those sorts of questions are welcome here..."

Comment: See also [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286015/164922) to *Let's Plan the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project!* and the links therefrom.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Yes, thanks, and that brought me to Sklivvz's [suggestion](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3288/prevent-101-rep-users-from-voting-and-commenting-until-105-rep) which I looked for but couldn't find earlier.

Comment: speaking of troublesome answers, a while ago I studied these matters at SE.SE and reported my findings in much details at meta: [Answers quality in hot questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5413/31260). "Summing up, I would downvote about 101-118 of 218 answers I reviewed per above research..."

Comment: Another possibility for you to consider (same thing different flavour): https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238420/prevent-questions-on-hot-list-from-being-upvoted-by-casual-visitors-only-rep-is

Comment: @DVK: Excellent. I am going to edit it into the answer.

Comment: +1 the vast number of answers contributed by people drawn to RPG.SE from a HNQ are bad answers from people who don't know an RPG from a DMZ, requiring downvotes and sometimes deletion and moderation, causing consternation and hurt feelings and - more importantly - crappy answers for the querent.  Which is supposed to be why we're here.

Answer (score 34):

This has already been brought up tangentially in some answers, but:

#### Do HNQs really need to be that fresh?

The vast majority of the problems arise from HNQs being selected by an algorithm only.
The only reason I see for having it done this way is that you want eligible questions on the list as soon as possible.
While I can understand that advertising yesteryear’s questions there is against the point, I don’t see why we cannot wait a while to let humans decide.

As a brief sketch, I would suggest the following:

- Once a question has acquired enough hotness, place it in the moderator queue of that site, where moderators can forward it to the actual HNQ list or reject it.
- Provide moderators with some guidelines regarding titles, content, and so on.
- Of course, moderators can also use this opportunity to polish the question (in particular the title), perform some comment clean-up, or protect it pre-emptively.

On most big sites, this should impose a delay of a few hours to half a day. On slower sites, it may take a while longer, but then those sites are slower anyway, so the delay doesn’t matter that much to them.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: *Would it be fair to leave all the decisions to a small team?* – Well, the alternative are regular reviewers and given robo-reviewing and other bad decisions made by them, I really wouldn’t trust them with this. Mods can at least be held accountable to some extent. Also, keep in mind that the main point of this is to filter out the really bad stuff. That being said, some bias is unavoidable, but that also applies to all methods of choosing HNQs.

Comment: Instead of mods; maybe xxxx+ rep users. Finally something serious to do as a 10k user ;-)

Comment: There's a feature request for your first bullet point at [Add a Hot Network Question review queue for cleaning up questions that are about to become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298396/191265).

Comment: [eykanal answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha/316996#316996) also touched this sensible point. Isn't one of the goals of the network to build an encyclopedia of knowledge? It doesn't really matter if something was posted last year or yesterday, does it?

Comment: Thanks @Wrzlprmft you said this better than I would have. Since moderators for a site are most likely to have the best idea of what questions would promote their site (rather than put people off) I think they are in the best position to decide what questions should be eligible for the HNQ. I agree that 10k users might also be worth adding into the mix though too.

Comment: From another angle, I've long thought smaller sites are most harmed by the freshness factor - even moreso sites where good answers often take a lot of work to compile (science/math/certain programming/etc). I'll often bookmark a Q and come back to it months later to put together a quality answer. But I know no matter how good the answer is, it'll never gather much interest. A fair % of users in the community will see it back active and assume it's just the same old question. But no matter how many users at the site upvote, it still fails the 1 month rule for HNQ. All certainly discouraging

Answer (score 33):

I do think keeping it is a good thing. I know for myself, it's introduced me to sites and topics I'd not have expected to see on SE, and I know for younger sites, it can be yet another way to get a critical mass of people in the days when you *really* need them because no one knows about you yet. Sure, not all of those people stick around, and sure, not all of those people are there for more than like...rubbernecking at what feels like an impending drama storm, but there *is* good in it.

I know what happened to cause this, but I feel like the reaction was kinda throwing the baby out with the bathwater. A lot of sites have problems sometimes with "offputting" sorts of titles (I moderate Arqade, so I have some awareness of how an honest title can sound highly weird to people who don't know what's going on, and on the flip side, I have experience with having to bop things over the head when people (myself included!) sometimes have a little too much fun with titles), but I think there are ways to potentially deal with that beyond just going "this sucks lets toss it out".

I think there are a few problems, though - number one is that anything controversial is going to pop up there. Which causes more eyes, which causes more...everything, which causes more "hotness" and thus it lurks in the list when it might not be the best and brightest that site has to offer.

In a way, maybe we should be looking less at "hotness" and more like, perhaps, some sort of curated list of "the best and brightest"? I am not sure how much filtering can be done, but if there was a way to be like "these are actual good examples of current questions that are a good example of the awesome we are bringing to the SE table", that would go a long way.

Also, I think there needs to be a way for individual questions to be pulled based on the community/mods/whoever going "okay nope, this is not what we want to be known for". I think something like that might have helped this last issue. And if we can get some sort of notification that something has *hit* HNQ, that would also be good - then no one is surprised at the sudden attention, we know what potholes we might fall into if something that needs some title nudging/editing gets there so we can work with it, etc. Right now, there's not much we can do short of closing a question, and that's not always the best fit - title alone might not make it a bad/unworthy site question, it just might not work as something shoved to people who didn't ask to be here in the first place.

Also, I have seen a number of proposals that maybe HNQ should be opt-in/opt-out, or at the very least, collapsible or something - so I can interact with it if I *want*, but if I am only here for my cooking questions/programming questions/dog care questions, I don't have to worry about seeing something from Parenting/Workplace/IPS/Arqade etc that might not be my jam so much.

Comment: Re "the best and the brightest": I suggested something much the same (sorry for not seeing yours first!), and it makes a whole lot of sense. Hot != best.

Answer (score 32):

> I have added some more analysis on IPS meta using (give or take) two weeks of data. This can be found [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/on-the-hnq-and-its-effects-on-the-site-stats).

---

To give an idea what the presence/absence of HNQ does to a site, these are the Google analytics data for pageviews for IPS the last week:

```
date        page views  visits  new visits
2018-10-10  24496       9315    2718
2018-10-11  31098       11335   2748
2018-10-12  33044       12596   2781
2018-10-13  11883       6289    2271
2018-10-14  12796       7059    2518
2018-10-15  40497       16328   3491
2018-10-16  29594       12672   3350
2018-10-17  13698       5801    2608
```

Halfway through Tuesday the 16th the removal happened, making Wednesday the 17th the first full day of data we have. Comparing that to the Monday before, the traffic is ~33% of what it used to be, comparing to the same day a week before, it is 54% of what it was.

That is however including the traffic generated by this incident, so the final numbers might be even lower.

---

Let's compare this Wednesday to Wednesdays in the past:

```
    Week `page views`
   <dbl>        <int>
 1    25        31861
 2    26        29288
 3    27        26134
 4    28        50706
 5    29        49773
 6    30        32966
 7    31        41723
 8    32        30800
 9    33        19670
10    34        35570
11    35        20137
12    36        28289
13    37        27842
14    38        29110
15    39        40004
16    40        20902
17    41        24496
18    42        13698
```

[image]

Lower, but those values are kinda all over the place, so let's compare it with what we might expect based on how this week started.

---

I am comparing Monday to Wednesday, because Monday is the last complete day of this week *with* HNQ, and Wednesday is the first complete day *afterwards*.

```
    Week Monday Wednesday RatioWedToMon
   <dbl>  <int>     <int>         <dbl>
 1    26  22842     29288         1.28 
 2    27  28242     26134         0.925
 3    28  39476     50706         1.28 
 4    29  43726     49773         1.14 
 5    30  44029     32966         0.749
 6    31  42273     41723         0.987
 7    32  34528     30800         0.892
 8    33  31826     19670         0.618
 9    34  26157     35570         1.36 
10    35  30651     20137         0.657
11    36  23212     28289         1.22 
12    37  24193     27842         1.15 
13    38  25534     29110         1.14 
14    39  44303     40004         0.903
15    40  26644     20902         0.784
16    41  24323     24496         1.01 
17    42  40497     13698         0.338
```

[image]

That's a **stark** difference. Looking at the summary statistics of the ratio before this week, we can see that week 42 is a definite outlier.

```
     Ratio       
 Min.   :0.6180  
 1st Qu.:0.8651  
 Median :0.9971  
 Mean   :1.0061  
 3rd Qu.:1.1678  
 Max.   :1.3599
```

On average, the traffic is equal between Monday and Wednesday; this week that was a third.

---

Fitting a simple linear model on the previous weeks: `lm(data = train, formula = Wednesday ~ Monday)`

```
Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept) 6185.6933  7634.4636   0.810  0.43136   
Monday         0.7978     0.2316   3.445  0.00395 **
```

It's not a perfect model, but I don't have an awful lot of data to work with. Based on this, we would predict a traffic of ~38500. In reality, this was 13698, or 65% lower than expected.

[Gist with my code](https://gist.github.com/JarkoDubbeldam/2a43302ddfd2e7a46cf1d923de4ebdde). I don't think I'm allowed to share the Google Analytics data sadly.

Comment: @NicolBolas:  The 13th and 14th are weekends, and it's not an unresaonable pattern to note that traffic across the network sags on the weekends.

Comment: It will be interesting to see if the quota of questions asked per day, currently at 4.2, will shrink in the coming week/s.

Comment: @mariloua I'd guess the effect on number of questions is relatively lower, but we will definitely be keeping an eye on the site stats.

Comment: Related to this, [here is a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/interpersonal/query/914705/number-of-question-ask-per-monday) to check how many questions per Monday we usually get (this Monday isn't in it yet but, for now, 0 question have been asked).

Comment: (1) The effect on IPS is likely atypical - for a small site it had a lot of HNQs. (2) If the drop-off in views is due mainly to the loss of people looking at just the HNQs before leaving again, it's perhaps not to be much lamented. Counting questions asked, as @Mari-LouA suggests, or the number of new users signing up might be more telling.

Comment: @Scortchi it's definitely worth taking a second look at the wider sitestats. The number of questions per day vary a lot more though, so it's better to wait a little while to gather more data.

Comment: Is it too soon to ask for an update?

Comment: @Mari-LouA not at all. I'll see if I can cook something up when I get home.

Comment: @Mari-LouA posted it [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3380/on-the-hnq-and-its-effects-on-the-site-stats).

Comment: If I've understood correctly, `17 42 40497 13698 0.338` refers to 17 October. Your stats only refer to the previous weeks (am I right?) What has happened since then, in the two weeks after IPS was "banned" from HNQ? My impression, from just looking at the number of questions posted on IPS, is that things have actually improved. The number of questions posted is higher but I have no idea about the number of views. To recap, are the stats in your answer updated, i.e 1 November,  or not?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92736/interpersonal-skills   Now if only there was a way to get the stats from two weeks ago. Would there be any difference?

Comment: @Mari-LouA the stats in the answer have not been updated. I did make a more in-depth post based on two weeks of data on IPS meta, which I have linked to in the top of this answer. As for the A51 stats, from the top of my head, the views/day have dropped, the answers/question have dropped, but the other stats appear to have remained stable.

Comment: But if you managed to produce (interesting) stats for weeks 26 to 42, what happened to week 43 and 44? Surely *that* is the most relevant data, we would see a trend of some sort, wouldn't we?

Answer (score 31):

> The titles of these questions, out of context, are just too likely to be inappropriate on our professional and academic sites, so we took the site out of the contributing list.

To be honest, when speaking just for myself (and probably a part of the IPS community too)... I don't mind being 'the one site that's out of the mix' for a while. It offers some interesting opportunities for IPS, such as some breathing room to actually moderate our questions and answers, and see just how much voting coming in from HNQ skews the view on what a quality answer on IPS is.

That said... This would've gone much, much better if there had been some warning, some discussion, on IPS first. Even if that means a programmer from SO coming into our meta, saying 'HEY! your question titles could be improved upon a lot, that would really make my day'. I guess we wouldn't be having the entire discussion right now then.

But now that we're having it, you have a set of goals... let's see if there's other ways to meet them.

> They help with discovery. User interviews continue to reveal that folks simply don't often discover just how big of a resource we've become collectively. The list boosts engagement in quite a few ways (we'll admit some of them aren't optimal)

Perhaps a thing to do this would be to feature some sites, some topics, instead of questions? Have some kind of sidebar 'advertisement', that invites people over to discover the site, instead of reading it's currently most contentious question? Have a list of 'featured' sites? Of 'Hot Network Sites'?

A personalized list, like [Glorfindel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316935/369802) suggests, sounds great but it constructs some kind of 'social media bubble': it doesn't get you out of your comfort zone the way HNQ currently does. It's okay, but then you'd probably have to give up on the goal of reaching new people with new stuff. I'm personally quite fond of that functionality. It's made me discover more of the SE network than just StackOverflow, and I wouldn't be a moderator on IPS now without HNQ breaking into my bubble and introducing me to a part of the network called 'Interpersonal Skills'.

Linking just the site instead of a post would mean that there's no huge reputation gains for people asking a question or writing an answer anymore, instead, hopefully, traffic to a site is distributed more evenly across posts, instead of just among the three posts in HNQ. This could be a blessing and a curse, I don't have any data to back up this claim, just thoughts.

> They often remind communities to have discussions about scope. If folks see a clear demand for certain kinds of questions, it's worth revisiting conversations about how valuable finding ways to meet those needs might be.

This one is hard. Perhaps the people that do land on a site due to an advertisement will start asking their own questions, will write answers to the questions of their interest, will feel free to ask 'Hey, your site was advertised to me, can I ask about X here?'

To be honest, I again don't see much difference here between either advertising the entire site vs. just a question. Even if people see just a question, it's going to give them pretty much the same impression as a good advertisement for your site will do.

> Hot questions are extremely great fodder for evangelists, the kinds of people that reach thousands of folks that are likely to identify with the way we do Q&A.

Those people likely need a way to keep track of what's hot across the network. Perhaps this doesn't need to be featured in a side-bar though. You could feature the 50 hottest sites right now, and have more sites (and thus questions) in your Hot Network Sites than you get posts in your Hot Network Questions. You can have a list of hot questions per site? Let's face it, there's more sites than just IPS that generally have more than 1 question in HNQ. The only downside to this would be that whatever happens, really really low traffic sites will still end up on the short side of the bargain and not gain much exposure.

All in all, I'm sure there's other ways to reach out to your evangelists. Try and find out how much work those evangelists are willing to do to get their material, what would they like to see? If they know where to find HNQ, perhaps a single link (instead of a list of question links) to the [general HNQ site](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) may work fine. Or make that list collapsible.

> Automatic selection simply will not scale if we continue to push the limits of subjective topic spaces, and we need to continue to do that for the network to grow and remain relevant to the issues folks want to use our software creatively to solve.

I would warn against making too much of the selection manual though. Currently, the algorithm relies heavily on actions taking by the community (voting on question/answers and answering the question) to get a question into HNQ in the first place. Taking that away from the community and putting it in moderators hands may be less than ideal. But I also don't know if you can expect the community to *manually* keep coming up with good posts to put in HNQ, the 'best answer of the past three months' contest on IPS died out due to lack of interest.

Suggestions like 'allow moderators to pick what reaches HNQ' carry the big downside that if moderators do get that power, we basically can decide who wins the imaginary internet points lottery and who has to scrounge through dustbins for next points. That's not really fair to users, and it's not really fair to moderators either. I'm expecting a lot of complaints if people are given too much power to select what can reach something like HNQ.

I prefer being able to blame *something* automatic when someone complains about reputation from HNQ not being fair ;)

The same goes for [some of the points Monica mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316937/369802), like giving moderators the power to exclude questions from HNQ. Maybe the question asker really, really wants their question out of HNQ. But is it really fair for us to take down a question, just because a single person wants to? We'd be robbing honest answer writers of their exposure too.

Excluding protected questions carries a risk too. People already find it 'elitist' sometimes that they can't answer a question due to it being protected. How would people like it if three nasty people with malicious intent answered a question, just to get their answers downvoted/deleted, and the community user to protect a question, which will lead to it's protection and it being taken out of HNQ? As long as the metrics for protection are visible, and every community member with a certain amount of reputation can protect/unprotect stuff... I'm expecting a lot of trouble by implementing such a system.

Comment: I wouldn't see deHNQification (patent pending!) as a power to be used willy-nilly at the request of a user, even the asker. I'd treat it more on the scale of closing/deleting, which are actions with important repercussions, but which we *do* lay into the moderators' hands *and* trust them to use them only when necessary. If someone complains about it, you better had a good reason to do it.

Comment: @ChristianRau perhaps. But then, if that really, really good reason is already present, we can even just close the question for a while (and that's something that a community can do, even). Making it *easier* to get questions in or out of the current HNQ carries a lot of problems, especially if that power is just in a mods hands. Having a question in or out of HNQ carries a lot more consequences than having it open/closed/deleted. Even those are preferably still always done by the community. Having mod power to do that would still seem like a lot of willy-nilly to me

Comment: Closing an on-topic question that somebody wants to get answers to *just* because some network-wide algorithm is currently doing bad things with its *advertising* seems really unfair to site users.  I don't think mods (or anybody else) should close a question that shouldn't be closed just to dodge HNQ.

Comment: @MonicaCellio That might be true... it was more to illustrate that there is a way to take stuff out of HNQ (and that that already is unfair). I don't see how giving moderators a way to just jank questions out of there that we don't like improves the situation. You're still silencing people, still censoring perfectly fine on-topic questions. (only now you have the tool to do it)

Comment: No, yanking a question from HNQ while leaving it open and answerable isn't silencing anybody.  It's putting that question in the same situation as all the other questions on the site that *weren't* pushed into HNQ.  Think of HNQ as advertising, not entitlement.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm more than willing to think of it as advertising... I still don't feel comfortable with the idea of being able/having the power to decide 'you go, you don't.'. Especially when taking questions that are already in HNQ out of it again. But also in the proactive stage. You're essentially saying 'you're not good enough for HNQ' to that particular question, which makes it different from all those other questions that didn't reach HNQ (because hey, there were already 5 IPS posts in there at the time they were asked, and nr 6 didn't reach the heavier threshold).

Comment: By being able to say 'you're okay for HNQ, you're not'... you're not putting questions in the same situation.

Comment: There's also the perspective of users who wrote answers for the HNQ: they may be hoping for the rep and they've technically put in the work for it. It's sticky to have other people decide that the content isn't appropriate to be exposed to potential voters; this could be used competitively.

Comment: I am glad to hear you say that Tink... I agree HNQ is not necessarily IPS's friend, to understate it to the extreme. HNQ turns IPS into Springer.  (a tawdry daytime TV talk show host who showcases dysfunctional relationships, often with spectacular reveals of paternity tests).  I think without HNQ's "help" IPS has a better chance of discovering its own natural identity and role.

Comment: Simply linking a site instead of questions makes it far less useful. I don't know how many people click on those community ads, but I never have. OTOH, almost every non-SO community I'm part of I found via the HNQ list, and I often like to read topics on sites I'm not a part of.  I essentially use it as an "interesting question list" aggregated across a dozen or more sites.  Simply linking sites would lose that benefit because not every site is discussing something interesting all the time.

Comment: For example, while I generally find the Worldbuilding HNQs to be interesting, the WB homepage is _not_.  Most of those homepage questions have lingered around for weeks, months, or years (so I've already read them), and a large portion of the new ones are downvoted or on their way to closure.  Seeing a question on the HNQ list is a sign that "hey, finally some new stuff to check out!"  (Well, ideally, though in practice questions can linger in HNQ for days.)  I don't think linking to the site would serve as that kind of signal.

Comment: Good answer, upvoted, but disagree that a valid function of HNQ (or any site feature really) should be "taking people outside of their comfort zone". I think I see what you mean by this, but honestly my comfort zone is something I need respected, especially on a site I'm using at work.

Answer (score 31):

I really like the HNQ, and have often learned about interesting topics because of it. I would hate to see it go, and I don't think it actually has serious problems. The fact that SO felt the need to remove some items from it after a random person on Twitter complained about it seems like an overreaction to me.

*(Those IPS questions looked genuine, asked in good faith, on-topic for the site and correctly titled. I hope you're not going to censor contentious subjects; one of the most interesting questions I saw in the HNQ recently was titled "My 3 year old thinks she's white; should I correct her?")*

Having said that, there is one thing about the HNQ that annoys me immensely: the fact that I can't choose to hide certain sites. I have no interest whatsoever in Gandalf, Dumbledore or R2D2, or what type of stone victims of the Petrification spell turn into, or whether it is a sin to ride a unicycle on Tuesdays in a certain religion.

The fact that a lot of the tiny site icons are similar and hard to recognize means I'm often halfway through reading a title in the HNQ when I realize it's from one of the nonsensical sites.

So please, let me click somewhere so I never have to see Role-Playing Games, Science Fiction & Fantasy, Christianity, Buddhism, ... ever again. (But don't group them into categories, because I quite enjoy World Building, e.g.)

*(Of course you don't have to agree with my selection of uninteresting sites, because that is part of the point I'm making: everyone will have a different selection.)*

Comment: There are user scripts to filter HNQ.

Comment: For the filtering by sites, see [this meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225297/225764).

Answer (score 26):

> And in the spirit of causing tons of people to flood into a single discussion, I'm going to feature this; I just can't help it.

There you go, you already have the solution. Give trusted users the ability to tag questions as featured. Then apply the arbitrary hotness points calculator to the featured questions to determine which ones to show in the HNQ list.

Alternatively, create a featured review queue where questions that have enough arbitrary hotness points get placed. If enough trusted users vote to make the question featured, it automatically gets the tag and shows up in the HNQ list.

If a site wants a question off the HNQ list, all they need to do is remove the special [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag.

Comment: Not the biggest fan of a tag-based solution (for technical reasons), but the idea of a review queue is neat. However, opt-in on per-question scale might require a little too much manual effort, especially on smaller sites. But for notification purposes (and opt-out), it would be quite useful.

Comment: How do you decide who is trusted and how would we keep this from being abused by trusted users? A question that hits the HNQ can easily get 10x as many upvotes as one that doesn't so the motive for abuse is certainly there

Comment: @StrongBad sounds like an idea, but given the title issue that got IPS out of HNQ, would you solve this by reviewing? The titles are, in a sense, representative of their posts, but out of context they look off. Those questions certainly weren't HNQ unworthy (to phrase it one way), it's the titles that caused the problem. They may end up being voted into your list this way?

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh a trusted user is a term for a 20k+ user of a full site and a 4k+ user on a beta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: @Tinkeringbell sure so the review queue has two questions: *Does the title contain anything that when taken out of context could be considered offensive* and *Is this question representative of your site*.

Comment: This is possible at the moment in a way, you just need 5 users to close. However the apparent amount of effort people seem to put in before VTC doesn't give me a whole lot of confidence that this would work even with the higher reputation threshhold

Comment: There is already a Featured list, and users already can earn the privilege to put questions on it (by placing bounties). And there is already a list of questions with high hotness points that might get selected by HNQ - the Hot tab on the front page. They're not quite functional equivalents to your proposals (and they might occupy the semantic space you'd want for a different feature), and you probably want to build something different (more review-queue-y, say), but lots of what you're discussing here is already out there in some form or another.

Comment: A review queue was proposed as part of [Add a Hot Network Question review queue for cleaning up questions that are about to become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298396/191265).

Answer (score 24):

Well this has whole debacle been saddening and enlightening.

As a silly example:
[image: deleted meta SO question]

If that or [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289089/278094) was a twitter rant instead of a meta post we never would have had another hat that depicts meat. No "Taco Tuesday Any Day," no "Extra Toppings" etc. Contrast that with what actually happened there.

Can we just take a step back here and think about what happened to spark the HNQ change.
**A non SE user complains on twitter and nearly instantly the "offending" site is blacklisted.**
Just read that last sentence there again. Persons, issues, money and politics aside that is crazy.

---

I am very disappointed in how SE handled this situation. Putting aside the end result,  (the end does not justify the means) what SE did was shameful. In about 40 minutes SE had decided to unilaterally dis an entire site in the network, to placate an offended person on twitter. SE did not stand up for itself, for its (perfectly acceptable and on topic) content, for its mods, or its users. We got nothing but a knee jerk reaction along the lines of "*Eek a semi famous self proclaimed feminist activist said something bad about SE. We don't want to look bad. Quick throw IPS under the bus, and pull everything.*"
To quote a line from a post Monica Cellio wrote about this:

> I feel like placating one person on Twitter is more important to you *[SE]* than doing right by your moderators and communities.

I would have much more faith in SE, and feel better about this if you (SE) had either responded from the company, and had a meta and or blog post for what you are going to do about the "HNQ issue". Or skipped responding on twitter (remember phases like "adding fuel to the fire" and "don't feed the trolls") and just went straight to a community post. (This question would of been a *much* better way of starting.)

No instead we get a really bad taste in our mouth, and a feeling that SE cares more about its inclusive and diverse image then about its users and content.

---

Now Tim I know you will read this, I'm not upset at you, in fact I'm glad that there is a messenger between the inner workings of SE and us. I know you had to handle a pretty ugly situation. I trust that everybody responding had the best of intentions. However actions speak louder then any words. By SE's swift and decisive response, unfortunately SE's priorities have become clearer.

---

As an aside I waited over a week, and have read through everything that transpired so I could detail my thoughts with a clear and cool head. There were some tweets, that were very upsetting.

How do we move forward as a community? I do not know. The damage has been done. Regaining trust is a tricky process.

Comment: Don't agree.  The outsider perspective is worth its weight in gold.  It is exactly how 99% of humans see you, and *you only get it once in a lifetime*.  How quickly we forget.

Answer (score 23):

I would start by leveling the playing field between the narrowly focused and the overly broad questions **by reducing the number of answers that go into the hotness equation.**

Right now of these two types of questions,

1. Narrowly focused with one right well researched answer.
2. Broad question that has many possible answers and everyone gets to weigh in with their opinion but not broad enough to be closed.

Arguably type 1 questions are better but **right now the broader questions have a better chance of getting onto the list** and staying on it for longer **since it has more answers to upvote** and therefore gain more hotness points.

Comment: how do you propose this playing field is leveled?

Comment: @WillBarnwell Right now the score of the question plus up to 10 answers go into the hotness score. If it was reduced to say 5 or maybe even 1 answer, then the advantage of broad questions would be much less

Comment: or you could normalize the answer score (i.e. sum the answers, but divide by the number of answers)

Comment: @Federico That would incentivize protecting hot questions right away because otherwise, one good question with one good answer would have it's hotness points cut in half by the addition of one more answer.

Comment: Perhaps include a view count or at least age factor in the normalization.

Answer (score 23):

Here is one concrete proposal on how to give sites a chance to control the quality of HNQs.

Whenever your automatism detects an HNQ candidate, put it into a dedicated review queue.

- Explain to the reviewers what the purpose of the queue is: polish the candidate and make sure it's representative of the best the site has to offer.
- High-rep users

  - can edit titles, tags, and posts to shine, and then
  - accept or reject the candidate for publication via HNQ.

The votes needed for/against need to be calibrated carefully, of course.
*Never* should a question go "hot" without the approval of the community.

Ideally, all mods and accepting reviewers should get a notification once the question goes hot so they can closely monitor and, if need be, moderate the incoming traffic.

Comment: This is a popular suggestion: it's very similar to the exclude-from-HNQ idea suggested in [Monica Cellio's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316937), and I'm quite sure it's been suggested even more directly somewhere else.

Comment: I like the idea of sending it to a review queue.  This lets the community review and improve likely-to-be-popular posts *regardless* of whether they actually hit HNQ in the end.

Comment: This is a *brilliant* and extraordinarily simple suggestion, and *very* nicely fits in with the ethos of the Stack Exchange network—community-driven, automation-assisted collaboration in building a knowledge base.

Comment: This was previously suggested as part of [Add a Hot Network Question review queue for cleaning up questions that are about to become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298396/191265).

Comment: Related: [Encourage active users to edit hot questions especially titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286248)

Comment: +1, while I have posted [my own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316998/149055) suggesting human curation, the specific method you propose also has the advantage of making use of the existing mechanism of the review queue. I would still argue that the preselective algorithm should be tweaked to be less indicative of "what catches people's attention", but overall a great idea.

Comment: +1 This is what I was going to suggest as well, though you've fleshed the idea out a bit further than I had in my own mind. Glad I scrolled down enough to find it!

Answer (score 22):

#### What's in a name?

The *Hot* network questions cause a problem right from the first word. Why do we care if a question is "hot"? Don't we want "good" or "informative" or "searchable" or anything other than hot questions? A dumpster fire is hot, that doesn't mean that it will draw me over to look at it.

#### Show Users Good Network Questions (GNQs)

Wouldn't it be better to bring new users to a site via [good], [great], exceptional, or outstanding questions? Or to use more adjectives, maybe [popular], [notable], [famous]? Some of those already have badges that are associated with them. This seems like a very easy way to find the best questions for a site and show them to the outside world. These questions are likely on-topic and show what a site has to offer.

#### Make a List, Rotate Through It

Use the badges noted above to create a list of possible questions for each site, and then rotate through them. This keeps the same questions from popping up all the time and should be easy from a performance standpoint.

Give each site an equal chance to have a question on the list or base it off of some other metric so that the advertising potential of the GNQs list is spread out.

This gives the sites a chance to make sure that questions are friendly through the natural progression of a site instead of having to jump on the new questions.

Comment: Questions with these badges (1) are typically already exhaustively answered, so there's little chance of having something to contribute yourself (which sometimes happens with HNQ), (2) may not be that relevant any more, (3) are much less likely to appear on smaller sites (where we may miss even really popular questions) and (4) I'm, without much data, inclined to say are the less interesting questions (and yes, interesting is good - something that every person and their dog finds via Google is probably very *useful*, but (a) I'd find it if I cared and (b) I probably don't even use those tools)

Comment: Everyone has different reasons for visiting sites, but I most of the time I click on HNQs because they look interesting. I usually visit sites to learn, not to answer.

Comment: How can "goodness" be measured? ...

Comment: SE already captures some good measures of question quality, e.g. views and votes. Those stats are used at the basis of the question and answer badges already, so SE thinks that those are acceptable values to base rewards upon. This proposal extends what is already done to also aid in populating a list of good questions.

Comment: @user202729, I think Monica Cellio and gnat's answers give very good ideas on how to measure it

Answer (score 21):

While I'm working at my job (which accounts for probably 90%+ of my use of Stack Exchange sites), after probably the 20th+ time that I was distracted from a work task by an interesting link in the Hot Network Questions sidebar, I decided to hide that section of the sidebar, via a change to my client browser.

(Various methods for doing that can be found in answers to this question: [How to avoid "Hot Network Questions" on the sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222721/134729))

So, while I'm at work, I personally wouldn't mind at all if the Hot Network Questions just went away -- since that's the situation I've already set up for myself anyway.

When I'm browsing Stack Exchange sites for fun in my free time, I do find the Hot Network questions very interesting, in a good way; however, that use case is of secondary importance for me personally.

Comment: Exactly. This feature is counter to the ethic of the network.

Answer (score 20):

## Break the feedback loop by ignoring all interactions from the HNQ

If we ignore all interactions coming from people who visited the Q&A from the HNQ, there is no longer any "positive" feedback and people from those communities can more easily regulate if the site is on the HNQ list by not voting at all.

This makes the system still automatic, but prevents a ruh of new people who visit a site in the HNQ making the question more likely to stay inside the list

Comment: Do you mean like a hell ban, or visibly say "Thanks for riding in on the party bus; unfortunately we can't let you get off at this stop because we know you're gonna litter" sort of thing?

Comment: @TimPost More like that the system also keeps track of a number that increases for the number of HNQ visits and a number that keeps track of the HNQ upvotes, and then subtracts that number from the real upvotes and visits before calculating the HNQ score. Doing it this way also prevents most abuse by serial voters

Comment: A simpler method - have the algorithm take a user's reputation **on that site** into account.

Answer (score 19):

#### The general problem

- HNQ needs improving. Let's continue discussing that long term.

#### The specific problem

- Someone made a public complaint out of context. It is claimed that person does not have a Stack Exchange account.

---

This makes me ask, why are we showing HNQ in the sidebar to users who are not signed in? Is a significant amount of the benefit HNQ brings coming from such users?

How about only showing HNQ in the sidebar when signed in? Users who are not signed in already see more advertising (which spares signed in users from it). Why not show reasonably non-distracting adverts in the sidebar, and replace them with HNQ when signed in?

This is not a fix for the many other problems that need discussion. It's just one simple suggestion for one simple problem.

Comment: From the list of goals in the OP it seems that exposing questions from sites that the user is unfamiliar with is central to the purpose of HNQ. Excluding non-signed-in users may shrink the problem but would also shrink HNQ's usefulness at all in pretty much direct proportion.

Answer (score 18):

All debate of who did what and why aside, you asked for

> We want some ideas on ways we can continue to meet our goals of getting the right sites in front of the right people who are likely to appreciate them and participate.

Determining what is the best content is not a new problem. If all our algorithms fail, we could fall on good old human curation. Which is really the gold standard in the "choose relevant information" field.

I don't think that an automated solution based on behavior will ever be very good, simply because what you want to showcase is not behavior, but the self-image of a community, and these are two different things. For a comparison, look at how people decorate their living rooms. They put in objects which reflect who they are and what they value. This might include things like a happy picture of the extended family, or a piano. In everyday life, family reunions may happen at Christmas only, and the person might spend more time vacuuming than playing the piano. But still, they want the piano to be placed prominently and the vacuum cleaner to stay in a closet. Similarly, when a community shows itself to new users with self-advertising purpose, it will want to choose its nicest questions and not the ones which happen to elicit most activity.

1. Questions would better reflect what the community considers "the best example of what we are about".
2. We have enough users interested in coming here and spending their time on reading questions, answering them and voting on them, so there is a good chance they would also be willing to vote for the "best representative question of this week". We have an example of this functioning with Photography's picture of the week.
3. It can even increase engagement, if people who don't visit a site else start coming back for the weekly vote.
4. We don't actually have a need for automated mining of preference data. The advantages I can think of (e.g. that it eliminates sampling bias) are not really relevant for this specific use of the data.
5. Sites will have equal representation, eliminating the bias towards sites where everybody has an opinion on every question (which coincidentally punishes sites where expert answers predominate).
6. The questions will be only shown after they have spent almost a week on the parent site ** . This means that, when the influx from outside comes, the community will already have cast its votes on the existing answers, downvoted nonsense into oblivion, made its comments and requests for clarification, etc. Once the nonexperts come in, they will at least see some guideposts, instead of drowning out the community's actions.
7. The community will be able to prepare for the question becoming HNQ, e.g. by making the title understandable outside of the site's context.

SE will obviously have to spend resources to get the system in place (and this doesn't have to involve writing their own poll functionality, we can live with setting up something parallel for the voting process), but once it is in place, the actual effort of keeping it going can be shouldered by the community.

Of course, the idea is not without drawbacks. My largest concern is: will the results be any different from just picking the highest upvoted question of the past week? My hunch is that there will be a difference, since question upvoting is not necessarily done with "I want the users of other site to know me by this content" in mind. Still, a low-resource pilot test will be needed to see if this actually the case.

---

* the time period can of course be chosen differently

** We could for example implement a lag time such that questions posted very shortly before voting are only eligible for next week's voting

Comment: The human curation part seems like the most ideal approach because of the reasons you listed, _and_ it would allow sites to opt-out as long as they wished by simply not nominating anything for the list. For instance, Server Fault would _much_ rather not be on the list, but it'd be neat if they _could_ be if they wanted to, if perhaps a legend in the industry swooped in and provided an epic answer to something, and it was already protected, etc. Of all the selection mechanisms, this one seems the most ideal to me, but we have to see what's possible.

Comment: @TimPost At the same time, I've learned things because I've followed links to Server Fault from HNQ, and it would be unfortunate if that didn't happen anymore because Server Fault would prefer people not know they exist. It's not clear to me that turning HNQ into an explicit promotional opportunity for sites that want traffic (and for sites that want to maintain exclusivity to avoid exposure) is inherently in everyone's best interest, and it potentially creates incentives for sites to game their curation for exposure over quality.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of "Hot Network Questions", here's what I'd actually like to see:

**Highly up-voted, unanswered questions** - these are interesting to a lot of people, but an answer isn't inherently clear

**Highly up-voted answers** - answers that a lot of people appreciate

**Bounties** - people are willing to spend rep to get an answer, I think we could be better at getting eyes on these

I also personally think that there should be an age requirement for questions to appear on these lists.  I don't know what the correct answer is, but a week would probably prevent most forms of abuse happening as at that point it should have been caught on each community.

Comment: Bounties weighing heavily into what gets picked up definitely introduces a new and interesting dynamic. It not only makes it more likely for those questions to still need answers but also makes the bounty mechanism itself more powerful.

Comment: And it allows for positive self-feedback. Place bounty on question, have it hit HNQ, HNQ effects eclipse rep spent on question.

Comment: I think highly up-voted unanswered questions should definitely be advertised, but they should be advertised *within the site they're on.* If I'm looking through the HNQ list, I want to learn something interesting about aviation or philosophy. Reading a good question alone (especially if I'm not familiar with the subject) doesn't really give me much (and I'll likely forget to go back and reread it days later when it has a solid answer).

Comment: I kinda like the upvoted-and-unanswered suggestion. Who knows, maybe someone on Physics will see an unanswered question from Astronomy and think "Hey, I can answer that!" Honestly, the unanswered questions may not get *any* attention unless they're bountied. But I also think @scohe001 has a point, too.

Comment: I don't like the idea of showing bounties outside the relevant site. Giving people outside the community a strong incentive to post answers, at the same time as inviting people who aren't familiar with the site to vote, seems likely to cause the answers to appear in an order that is not useful to the community.

Comment: @trichoplax with the current HNQ people ALREADY tend to post answers that aren't relevant or aren't helpful, so what's the difference?

Comment: @DForck42 I agree people are already posting unhelpful answers. I don't see that as a reason to provide them with further incentive.

Comment: @trichoplax all i am saying is that you're pointing out a problem that is already a current problem, and will most likely be a problem no matter HOW we aggregate things for the HNQ, or whatever ends up replacing it.  There will always be people abusing such a system.  It will ALWAYS fall to each individual community to enforce their own rules when an aggregator attempts to pull in people that aren't already a part of that community.

Comment: Bounties are a useful filter: the question is interesting enough for somebody to invest in *and* the question has been live for at least two days, so any initial train wrecks/clickbait titles/etc have probably already been fixed.  Bounties are supposed to be payment for advertising; let's make that advertising more effective by reaching beyond the home community.  This could especially benefit smaller communities, where the handful of experts on that tag who are on the site have already seen the question but there might be more out there in greater SE.

Answer (score 17):

**We already know that Stack Overflow is different.  Let's act on that.**

Stack Overflow is the flagship site, the one that gets the *vast* majority of the Google hits and activity.  It's *designed* for that.  Its stated purpose is to be a place for expert programmers to get in, get answers to their questions, and get on with programming.

Stack Exchange is the rest of the network, a mix of high-end professional, amateur-tolerant professional, hobby, entertainment, and very miscellaneous sites, about 170 of them.

We already treat Stack Overflow differently.  It has features no other site has, and it has needs that no other site has.  Why should we treat it as if its HNQ needs are the same as those of other sites?  They're not.

**In deciding what to do with HNQ, we should make a distinction between SO and SE.  The behaviors might need to be different.**

Here are some possible applications of that principle:

- On SO, don't show HNQ to people who aren't logged in.  Those swarms of Googlers will never see HNQ and thus won't be upset by what they find therein.  Do those swarms of Googlers even *click through* on HNQ enough to be relevant?  I don't have the data, but SE does.
- On SE, include all sites by default like we do now.  On SO, *exclude* sites by default; SO should use a curated list of technical sites.
- On SO, apply more stringent gatekeeping -- more excluded words in titles, more hotness needed, a requirement on answer scores, or other factors I haven't thought of yet.  Basically, let SO tune the definition of "hot" to SO's needs.

I mean these as independent suggestions, though they could be combined.

SO already has a different top bar, a different left nav, triage, careers, different ad handling, and probably other things.  Clearly it's ok to be different, so let's add HNQ treatment to that list.

Meanwhile, Stack *Exchange*, the rest of the sites, can continue to benefit from the cross-pollination and advertising that (a hopefully reformed) HNQ can bring.

Comment: Amen! And why stop with the HNQ list?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to avoid *too* much scope creep on this question. :-)

Comment: given how many votes on HNQ go from SO visitors I think this will practically mean that only curated sites will be in the list. Unless this is somehow combined with ignoring votes from HNQ visitors that was proposed in some other answers here

Comment: Good observation.

Comment: @gnat?  This should, as a side effect, solve the vote-inflation problem, if those floods of upvotes are coming mainly from SO.  So SO gets its curated list and everybody else operates on a more-balanced footing.

Comment: Monica, my point is that floods of SO votes to "curated" sites questions will make them score so much higher than other sites that as a result "more-balanced footing" intended for the rest of the network will look almost completely the same as one shown to SO. Think of it, if 100 questions from "curated" sites get their 100-200 upvotes each from SO users, they will rank much higher than anything else - so these same questions are essentially guaranteed to get to the "other" list that is supposed to be shown to the rest of the network

Comment: @gnat oh, I see.  So we'd probably need two hotness numbers, one for SO and one for the rest of the network.  Or just don't show hot questions from other sites on SO at all, I guess.  Ok, that part requires more thought.  (But I still think separating SO and SE is worth considering.  Even if we don't do that one, we can look into the other changes I suggested and I'd bet others have more ideas.)

Answer (score 16):

Whatever you do, **please make it simpler and more transparent than what we have now**.

There is an unbelievable amount of conflicting information about the HNQ criteria throughout the network but particularly on MSE.  Most people – even experienced people – just don't know how it works.

- Is there a difference between HNQ and the hot questions tab?
- Do questions 51–100 ever appear in the sidebar?
- Can a question that is several years old appear in the HNQ list?
- Do self-answers count toward the calculation?
- Are all sites (other than SO) weighted equally?
- Why doesn't my question appear? (a.k.a., What aspects of the calculation of hotness points are cached?)

Given that HNQ is something that serves as a major source of traffic and new users for many (smaller) sites, it's worth coming up with something simpler and more transparent, whether that is a simplified formula or a manual process.  When it's in place, put a **help page** for it on every site that describes the goals and functionality.

We need to take the mystery out of HNQ.

Comment: This could easily lead to HNQ optimization by people who want their questions show up in the list.

Answer (score 16):

### HNQ is there to entertain, to educate and to promote

I have the feeling that HNQ in its current form mainly focusses on the entertainment. The algorithm favours questions with many different answers, which either come from sites like IPS or Puzzling/Code Golf, where everyone has a different opinion / solution, or from highly controversial posts. A single, good answer is often sufficient and there's no need for 10 more, but this doesn't show up in the algorithm.

Promotion of small sites is virtually impossible, because on Beta sites, it is difficult to get a lot of views and votes in.

### The Solution

Why not

- **guarantee each site on SE one, and only one spot in the HNQ** (Yes, that would lead to 174 HNQ posts, but currently we already are at 100, so I don't think the list would explode)
- **pick** a rather **new post** from each site, and **only factor in the score of the question and the score of the answer**. Much discussion isn't a good indicator of hotness, it's an indicator of errors in answers that needs to be fixed, or a great controversy. Some option for a formula would be `(QuestionScore + Top-AnswerScore) / Time[since max-vote answer posted]` and exclude questions with the top answer older than 36 hours or so
- **Sort the HNQ list by relative viewcount.** As an example, use `Qviews  / AverageSiteViews`, this way you get a relative hotness, and smaller sites get a bit more visibility.

This way, small sites are promoted, and good questions from larger sites are promoted. With only one HNQ-Question per site, it is far more easier to review them to ensure the title is not out-of-context-clickbaity.

### Essentially, the *Hot Network Questions List* should become a *Recent Great Network Questions List*

Comment: *…Promotion of small sites is virtually impossible, because on Beta sites, it is difficult to get a lot of views and votes in….* IPS is a beta site. It receives between three and five questions per day. I have to check that estimate... be back in a sec. Yep. 4.2 questions per day. It attracts a very small number of questions.

Comment: ParentingSE is worse, it has 2.4 questions per day, yet it manages to get into the HNQ. Who knows what the algorithms are on these beta sites.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Questions on IPS have ~600 views within the first 24 hours, at least from checking their front page, and there wasn't a HNQ recently. They have a high view-count. Parenting.SE is a bit different, questions are ~300 views. This is why popularity based on initial view count is a bit unfair. But I agree - when there are 2.4 questions asked per day, one question on HNQ is a bit out of proportion.

Comment: But if the question's interesting (and useful) what does it matter if the site is small and the number of views modest. Every site should be represented at least once a week.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the [HNQ formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/323179)? If yes, then please explain why you think your formula will be an improvement over the current one, since they seem pretty similar to me. Except you're making views a huge factor. Views aren't currently a factor at all, so there is no "clickbait factor", for any definition of clickbait I'm familiar with (assuming people don't vote for questions and answers based off the title of the question).

Comment: @Laurel True, I actually memorised part of the formula wrongly. **The main change is that it's 1 question per site**,  always, and that instead of *capping the benefit of many answers at 10*, I've excluded it entirely.

Answer (score 15):

Allow the community to control what represents them in HNQ.

I see Monica has already mentioned this, but I want to focus on it as one possible solution.

On IPS at least, and I suspect on most SE sites, a core part of the community and moderators hang out in a chat room and leverage some clever bots to make moderation a breeze. Either through a chat bot system or through a review queue, allow the active and curating members of the community decide when a question will show up on HNQ. This would follow a flow somewhat like this:

1. Question meets criteria to make HNQ (what these criteria are is a can of worms I will not be addressing)
2. Question enters review queue (bot alerts community chat)
3. Some set of voting rules (3 promote votes from normal users with 1 or less dissenting block vote, diamond votes are instant promotion/block)
4. Questions representative of the community but not as 'controversial' show up in HNQ and attract users interested in these 'good' questions

Potential drawback is that this allows active participants in this process to suppress the "scope re-evaluation" factor from HNQ.

This system need not be in place for all sites, I don't think hot questions coming from Physics are going to cause a fuss.

Comment: I agree that questions from Physics are unlikely to cause a fuss for folks elsewhere, but we're plenty unhappy with the current selection. Try e.g. searching our chat room for the reaction when *yet another* flat-Earth question got on the list.

Comment: Also, not all sites are active on their chat rooms. Though then again, even if they aren't, bots that post there can still be useful.

Comment: oh no, i forgot about the flat earth questions. \*dramatic cry\* "is nowhere safe?!"

Comment: Physics is certainly not safe from folks looking to abuse the SE Q&A engine to push incorrect content (in fact, we have a much bigger problem with that than other sites). Fortunately most of the pseudoscience stays out of the HNQ list, but Flat Earth does have a habit of bucking that trend.

Comment: There's a feature request for #3 in [Add a Hot Network Question review queue for cleaning up questions that are about to become hot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298396/191265).

Answer (score 13):

My feelings are mixed. I'd prefer not to lose the feature, but it's not good in its current incarnation.

On one hand, it has made me aware of (a very very few) sites I might not have found otherwise that are relevant to my interests. (However, most sites in which I participate, I found via good quality answers searchable on Google and targeted at a specific current need.)

On the other hand, it doesn't seem to go a good job of publicising good questions and/or small sites that would benefit from the traffic. It's dominated by sites that already have high traffic (I guess that's the nature of 'hot') and prioritises (as others have commented) 'controversy rather than quality,' as well as anodyne questions on sites that attract a high volume of answers, which may not be the most attractive questions for much of our wider population of users (although they're clearly valuable to the person asking).

If the sites eligible to participate in HNQ is increasingly restricted, we'll end up with a worse mixture of pap and click-bait.  One of the small sites I participate in prides itself on curating high quality questions (yes, we get rubbish but it's usually down-voted/closed/improved pretty quickly) but we've never featured on HNQ, I suspect because we're too small --- so we'll never be discovered that way.

And on the gripping hand, I'm eternally grateful that HNQ introduces me to sites that I am very happy not to visit again, unless I'm having a spare ten-minutes when my eyebrows have already been combed! The questions might be "hot" but I'm old enough to mutter under my breath and move on... naming no sites (there's more than one).

What to do?

- First thing I'd do is abandon 'hot questions' and move to 'network-wide featured questions' or 'you might be interested in' -- let individual sites choose what they'd like to publicise within certain constraints (it would be nice to extend this to the Twitter feeds as well, and within sites as well -- don't just feature questions with a bonus). This is assuming (a big if?) that SE wants to bring attention to its lesser-known nooks and crannies. Yes, more work on the moderators -- or you could base it purely on question up-votes (within the context of individual site) rather than on answers....
- Then I'd look at the algorithm to ensure that the sites that already get plenty of traffic don't swamp the ones that really need the exposure. SO already gets the traffic -- does it need more? Will it really be disadvantaged if it doesn't 'feature'?
- Then I'd look at specific workplace concerns -- turn the list on by default but allow people to opt out.

This contribution is almost certainly too late to matter, but anyway...

Comment: I think looking away from 'hotness' (or an arbitrary score for how likely something is to become wildly popular) is definitely a good idea for the next implementation. We have some caps in place, but not nearly enough, and the ideal implementation would allow people to (at the least) block a site from showing up in their hot list, but that directly butts heads with needing to be performant and thus easily cached. All good input, thank you!

Answer (score 12):

I [commented my visions for the Hot Network Questions sidebar during a previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285909/306894). There was a lot of consensus, but from the people with an actual say in the site, it sounded like that wasn't the time for addressing that feature. Here we are again, so please put some consideration into giving us an ability to filter out what sites we want to see on there. There are so many that people don't care about, and it isn't the same for any two users.

Comment: We need to figure out if we can give people more granular control _and_ keep the feature performant (it's currently one heck of a query that relies heavily on caching, and even work that could be done on a cache list to not display certain sites when a page is rendered would incur a sizeable hit at our scale). We haven't ruled anything out, but it's a hard nail to hit.

Comment: Understandable. But, like was said in the OP, a completely different approach to populating that list needs to be made. Scaling is definitely an issue, but I'm sure there's a decent way to try and do it. Solving how to get this data is the first step, and then filtering out a user's choices _should_ be rather trivial after that.

Comment: @TimPost Please address [gnat's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316960/253521) debunking that claim before continuing to use it as a reason for inaction.

Answer (score 10):

A lot of good suggestion has already been made here but I have others too, so here it goes:

<sub>For the record, "I found my favorite site through that list, you gotta preserve that somehow!" but that doesn't mean the HNQ list can't be improved.</sub>

Several people have already suggested it, but I'm all for allowing trusted users (meaning, users with enough rep that understand the site policy) to vote for what question should be on HNQ (and, maybe, which one shouldn't).

But the important point here is that the user posting the question should also have the possibility to remove their question from HNQ at any point (I, myself, had several questions on HNQ and having the possibility to remove them from there would have been nice).

Also, from the beginning we are talking about good *question* but nominating a question for HNQ thanks to a good *answer* might also be an interesting idea (but maybe I'm just rambling here).

---

Also, regarding the issue of users seeing HNQ questions that they don't want to see, we have several solutions:

- By default, only show an HNQ list of related site. For example, when you are on Interpersonal Skills (IPS), you can see questions from The Workplace or Parenting but not from Stack Overflow. When you are on Stack Overflow, you can see Ask Ubuntu and Server Fault but not Christianity, etc...

  - With this suggestion, we might also want to adjust the number of HNQ slot a site get based on the "distance" the two site have between them. For example, if you are on Stack Overflow, you can only see one HNQ question from The Workplace but two from Ask Ubuntu, two from Server Fault, etc...
- Having a none default setting that allows the user to see HNQ question from *every* network site.

**Edit, some (obviously awesome) new ideas**

Related to the previous idea, we could also show questions (that won't have pop otherwise) based on the tag/key word they are using. Here are some examples:

- I'm on the Veganism & Vegetarianism site, I can see an IPS question about veganism (like, "How can I inform my futur host that I'm vegan?").
- I'm on The Workplace, I can see an IPS question that use a "workplace" tag.
- Etc.

Comment: I'm on StackOverflow, I can see Veganism & Vegetarianism ("Does cocoa fit in a vegan diet?") and Islam ("Is cocoa halal?"), but not Christianity or Physics or Philosophy or Worldbuilding ... sob.

Comment: I was having thoughts similar to this. Group the stacks by category, [like SE already does](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday). `Technology, Culture, Recreation, Life, Arts, Science, Professional, Business`, and by default only show that category on HNQ but allow users to _opt-in_ using their profile to select individual stacks (or whole categories) at once.

Answer (score 10):

As per the question:

> We want some ideas on ways we can continue to meet our goals of getting the right sites in front of the right people who are likely to appreciate them and participate.

#### One idea is to [Display other SE site links in the linked questions sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59569/397504) - when users link to other SE sites's questions.

The right tool is already in place, but for some reason it's limited to one particular site, instead of leveraging the existing network of sites.Let the community get the right questions in front of the right people, regardless of the site. This will help users discover other sites, not in a clickbait way, but in an organic way.

You can also possibly leverage this to show only HNQ from sites linked to the current question.

Comment: Good work linking to the original suggestion so people can vote up/down there too. If only there was a way to make that link easier to find. Oh wait...

Answer (score 10):

If a site is not an entertainment site, then the HNQ has no place there for the same reason that entertaining questions have no place on those sites.

HNQ questions may as well be featured questions. They are directly in the sidebar, almost exactly lining up with the first answer.

On sites where entertainment questions are absolutely banned, the HNQ should also be summarily banned as it serves no purpose. This has been true for a long time, and deviating from that just causes problems.

Disagree? Take it [straight from the horse's mouth (Jeff Atwood), **The Trouble With Popularity**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/01/31/the-trouble-with-popularity/).

[image: horse meme]

> Popularity is a tough thing. I’m tempted to call it a curse, but what we try to do at Stack Exchange is **make sure that questions and answers are popular *for the right reasons* — because they are amazing resources for learning from your peers**. If you want to slip a few jokes in there with the learning, that’s fine, but when the question devolves into little more than entertainment, I hope you can understand why our community moderators are obliged to step in and protect the community from, well … itself.

And Atwood was correct. However, what we have today isn't entertainment questions, we have entertainment exchanges. They need to be placed in a separate place.

> We know that closing the cookie jar is painful. We feel your pain. Nobody likes having their fun taken away. But it’s too addictive and too easy, and in the absence of any moderation, the community would do nothing but add and upvote the easy, fun stuff.

This is literally the situation being faced at present except on an exchange level. Even the exchange metas point this issue out themselves.

Closing the HNQ off altogether may not make much sense, but it should be separated into entertainment, and **not** entertainment.

Comment: I like the premise, but I don't know where to draw the line. Sometimes I search SO for the solution to a coding problem, and then open an HNQ Physics question for later, so the Physics question is the entertainment. For someone else a Physics problem may be their work, and an unnecessary (for them) but interesting SO question may be what they open for entertainment. It can't be just separated into jokes and not jokes. Even a very serious question can be an unwanted distraction (for some people a joke is easier to ignore...).

Comment: I think it would make more sense to separate sites into domains. If you're on SO, seeing questions on SU, SF, SE, and similar sites is great. If you're on Physics, seeing questions on Chemistry, Biology, and similar sites makes sense. Of course, such separation means that the HNQ list can only drive users so far afield; while I personally might be interested in an Arquade question despite being on SO, it wouldn't make categorical sense to link the two of them.

Comment: What then do you do with decidedly entertainment questions on non entertainment sites? I've been plenty entertained by some of the shenanigans people on money.SE and serverfault and superuse have been up to.

Comment: @Magisch if you think of it, it is probably even more weird than that. Let's see, Code Golf and Puzzling are entertainment while IPS and Worldbuilding are non-entertainment. That means folks at Stack Overflow ("where entertainment questions are absolutely banned") won't see the former pair and will see the latter pair. I somehow doubt that approach like this will make them happier

Comment: You are absolutely out of your mind if you think IPS or Worldbuilding falls into the non entertainment category; two exchanges where fake stories are almost encouraged. I would take 100 CG questions over 1 IPS question. Perhaps entertainment is not the best word choice since pendants will take it far too literally. I think Nicol makes a good point in that regard. Either way, advertising junk at Stack Overflow is a burden. Exchanges used to be able to stand on their own without clickbait ads in other places, and if an exchange cannot drive traffic on its own, perhaps it should be shut down.

Comment: no matter how you twist it, labeling "entertainment" will have ugly side effects. Here is a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312873/165773) where Code Golf moderator insists that this site is recreational so you would have to label it entertainment. and your personal perception of it won't matter. Labeling "junk" seems to be even less practical: I've seen statements that SO questions in HNQ are [junk](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287163/839601), would that mean it should be blocked, gimme a break

Answer (score 10):

### We should actively seek feedback from many more users than we're seeing here.

When the twitter/HNQ/IPS fiasco hit and it became clear how easy it would be to pull a site from HNQ, the RPGSE mod-team discussed the possibility. For us HNQ questions tend to get an influx of low-quality (read: untested, speculative, any-old-person-with-an-opinion) answers, strange voting patterns, friction with daily/established site-users, and tend to require mod-work to caretake. (And [something like a third of our questions hit the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315017/311001)--this is not a small issue.) I suspect we are not alone among sites' mod-teams in feeling that way about when a "hot" question rears its head.

So we [posted a site-meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8568/23970) asking for community input on whether we should withdraw. One mod did a nice job laying out what we usually see when HNQs get problematic, and their initial "let's leave" answer gained some decent traction: +13/-4 the first day, then +4/-4 the second day.

Then, hoo-boy, did we see something interesting. The first "let's stay" answer came in later that day and ended the day at +8/-2. Next day: +15/-1, then +12/0.

But that's not what catches my eye. What catches my eye are the other answers and, especially, the comments on most of the "let's stay" answers: many of them are from users whose names I *don't* recognize. And they're telling stories about positive interactions with HNQ that, frankly, I'm not seeing anywhere else--not in the Teacher's Lounge, nor in the Tavern, nor in this Q/A.

---

There are answers, votes, and comments here from (SWAG, here) a few hundred SE/SO members. A lot of us [posted angry](https://madisonmutual.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/4325225157_37ce7bfe91_o_d.jpg) in the first few days, reasonably so. But I'll also note that it's a lot of meta.SE regulars and mods/power users from other sites providing a lot of this commentary.

Tens of thousands (an even wilder SWAG, there) of users interact with the HNQ on a regular basis. I submit, respectfully, that **asking on meta isn't a good way to find out what's good or bad about HNQ. HNQ requires well-designed UX research in order to understand how it's even being *used* right now, never mind how to make it better.**

Comment: "We've always done it this way, hashing it out on meta" (because that's cheaper than doing actual research)   ;)

Comment: We're seeing [a similar dynamic on Workplace Meta](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5754/325).  Initially "do it yesterday" was way in the lead, and now "we new users found you that way" and "it's not broken" are beating it.  For all the griping that we hear on TWP about hot questions, it appears there's a large, silent contingent with a different perspective.

Comment: On the other hand, "it's not broken" arguments that "it brings [this Stack] new users" don't address the original reason for asking about it: that questions appropriate for [this Stack] are not always appropriate to appear unsolicited on [all Stacks]. It's relevant that the HNQ brings new users to Stacks, but that doesn't negate the problem of every Stack being subjected to some of every *other* Stack's weirdest and most provocatively-phrased questions. Seems like "opt-out" should be for Stacks to remove the HNQ list from their site, not to remove their questions from other sites' HNQ lists.

Comment: But then you also have to consider that those "tens of thousands" of people who found your site by the HNQ and do *not* think there's a problem with it are the exact same people whose unsolicited opinion and inappropriate votes you (according to the first paragraph) do not want on those questions. Either you let the masses decide what's best for them or the people who have the bigger picture in mind. Both approaches have their pros and cons, but you have to keep the consequences in mind. You can't have your cake and eat it, too.

Comment: @MonicaCellio And this large silent contingent are the people that the HNQ detractors complain about, so there's not really much that's surprising here. If *only* the people that are concerned about the problems HNQs can cause with regards to answer quality and voting would answer and vote on HNQs, those...problems wouldn't actually exist.

Answer (score 10):

### Not "hot" but "good".

I was happy to see your [thoughts on HNQ reform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319357/162102) in another answer.  In particular, you mention review and more moderator control, which are essential if you're just going to pull current active questions like you do now, optimizing for controversy.

But your thoughts got me wondering if we should go one step farther.  What, exactly, is the value of hotness?

What I hear from users of smaller sites, and even some larger ones, is that the HNQ list is important for **site promotion**.  Even on The Workplace, where complaints about the HNQ have been loud and numerous in the past, it looks like the community as a whole would rather stay on the list (and pay the cleanup cost) than opt out.

But is the HNQ list the best way to promote sites?  Supported by the answers and voting here, I'm gonna say **no**.

SE used to run single-question "ads" in the "community ad" slot, interspersed with the regular ads.  These showed the title of a question, along with its site logo *and name*, and linked to the question.  I haven't seen those in a few years, so I don't know if they faded away or were removed in favor of HNQ or were removed for some other reason.  Why not bring that back, and feed it from a query of sites' **good, recent questions** instead of hotness?  Make it easy for sites to advertise their best content instead of their most-controversial content and they can still draw in new users without all the downsides of HNQ.

Criteria will need to be developed.  It'd be nice to know what they were for those ads; that'd be a good starting point.  I think we are looking for significantly-upvoted questions with upvoted answers.  "Significant" should be evaluated in the context of the site, not globally, or Astronomy will never be able to compete with the trilogy.  To avoid seeing the same old questions all the time, there's probably also a time component -- qualifying questions asked within the last week (month?), maybe.

Comment: This is basically what Codidact does now, yes?

Answer (score 9):

Is this discussion only about the sidebar, or is it about HNQ in general?

I've been subscribed to [HNQ's RSS feed](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions) for many years and it's probably my favourite. Every day I get to read high quality answers on a *very* wide variety of subjects. It is interesting, entertaining and educating. I would be very sad to see it go.

I have no opinion on the sidebar: I rarely use it or even notice it because I've seen all those questions in my RSS feed before.

Whatever happens to the sidebar, I really hope that the [full HNQ list](https://stackexchange.com/), along with its RSS feed, never goes away. In fact, I would love for it to be modified to have more entries with a faster turnaround. I would also suggest that any sort of keyword or site blocking be disabled on it. The sidebar may lack context while being very visible, but this doesn't apply to the full list nor the RSS feed.

Comment: Yes, the InterPersonal Skill site (which is the one who no longer is on the HNQ list) is also excluded from the full HNQ list.

Comment: @Noon Thanks, I've reworded the last paragraph.

Answer (score 8):

> Let's say we agree to take out the hot network questions entirely. But, we want something else in its place that continues to pull in some of the benefits, without being such a mindless pain in the neck.

I feel like this is entirely inappropriate. Taking it out all entirely.

Sometimes when I feel bored and feel like surfing some Q&A away from SO, HNQ is my way to do it. I even decided to join some other communities just because of that. Taking it away will reduce the traffic a lot and would kill some other SE's sites that I(we) never knew that they existed (somehow).

If the whole idea is to hide those inappropriate titles, here's a way to do it. Let the users do it themselves. Hopefully this isn't something that is already featured.

My suggestion is based on the famous phrase from SE: *This site is moderated by you*.

My idea is to let each one of us choose which Q&A's sites he would like to see in the HNQ list. Here's some scenarios:

- All current Q&As will be added to the list.
- A new Q&A will automatically be added to the list. Let the light shine!
- User will be able to filter them out from his profile settings.

The whole idea is because if 1000 people find something "rude" or "inappropriate", there might be less or even more people that don't, and would actually like to see such a title. Plus it gives each user the ability to choose which Q&A to follow without having 10+ tabs opened. For example, I might be interested in following the Puzzling Q&A, yet not the chemistry, despite that usually none of them have any bad titles, just, not interesting.

**Update**:

Lawrence made a good comment about offline users that I didn't think about.
Here comes my suggestion about that, which, apparently, can also be used for online users.

Give a new privilege to all users at 3K (maybe?) reputation and moderators on each site to access a HNQ Review Queue. 
Voting will be simple, keep in HNQ or remove, while of course preserving the right to edit immediately.

What will be inside the queue? Just the questions that will already make it to the HNQ, and each time that a question is added to that queue, give it a RED FLAG to directly check it.. I mean that red circle we see when a queue is "full".

If removed, it won't be shown to offline people, and might as well be hidden from the online users even if they opted in for that particular Q&A.

Comment: If the issue is with non-SE users finding fault with HNQ titles, there's a deeper problem - the main [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) list is available even if you're not logged in.

Comment: @Lawrence I see your point... I will make sure to add an idea according to this in few hours.

Comment: A HNQ Review Queue was proposed in [Add a Hot Network Question review queue for cleaning up questions that are about to become hot (or rejecting them altogether)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298396/191265)

Answer (score 8):

Please allow the moderator team from any site(s) to control, or be able to ask to opt-out of the HNQ for the site they represent.

That visibility option should be decided by the site community itself.

Comment: @DeNovo My point was more, for the time they do something or fix it, let us control who want to be inside the HNQ. As SF want to be out of it from a long time ago. Will remove that wording.

Answer (score 8):

Simply remove HNQs from the side-bar, leaving only a [link](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot).

This should be quick & easy to implement; SE developers surely have more urgent calls on their time than designing algorithms or voting systems for HNQs. (Completing [the roll-out of new site themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314979/225179), expanding [responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/225179) to more pages, making the sites [more accessible for people with disabilities](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8391/role-playing-gamess-updated-site-theme-is-live/8407#comment27157_8407), working on [the "Ask a Question" wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682/1864816), ...)

Any kind of non-automatic way of deciding what goes in & out of the HNQ list will distract users from creating/curating/reading content. (And likely add another source of grievances.)

We can then browse HNQs if & when we want to, without having to worry whether clients or colleagues might be offended or disconcerted by seeing question titles like [How can a person be kept alive while being periodically drained of blood?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/128120/how-can-a-person-be-kept-alive-while-being-periodically-drained-of-blood) (example from today).

To some the HNQ side-bar is no more than intrusive advertising, & these are therefore going to be predisposed to annoyance at its content; sinking resources into trying to ensure this is quite unexceptionable just might not be worth the candle.

Comment: If they worked on those priorities backwards (quality and content first, view and feels later) I would agree with you, but it doesn't look like that.

Comment: @Braiam: Didn't mean to suggest an order of priority there, though I'd hazard a guess that developers' finishing off what they're already in the middle of would make good sense.

Answer (score 8):

I like HNQ the way as it is now. I like some of the suggestions given here, especially those concerning breaking the positive feedback loop and diversifying the sites displayed. I also have a strange but strong feeling I've read about that very problem and community suggestions on this very site a while ago. Obviously, the burning hot problem is not how HNQ list appears to the community, so I won't write about that and hope it will get incrementally better in the following 6-8 weeks.

What *is* a problem is how it appears to outsiders. I'm going to align with one answer here which suggests hiding it for anyone not logged in is a proper solution. Put a "StackExchange network hosts answers to many more topics" link or something like that instead. Then, redirect it to main SE site, which by default shouldn't provide a list of hot questions, but rather something representative of good quality questions on the network. This can be a much more slow-moving list -- use a review queue or special tag to feature questions here. After all, primary audience for this are those not familiar with any site on SE who won't drop by more than once or twice, and not someone who would refresh the list waiting for something interesting to pop up.

For new users, set the HNQ to off by default and bury it somewhere in preferences. After they obtain some rep on the site (50, 100, whatever) and get familiar with how things work, show a tip somewhere, asking them whether they'd like to enjoy the obscenities that HNQ (occasionally) provides. That way, no outsiders or newbies get hurt by mentions of threesomes in the sidebar, and even if/when they decide to become a part of the community, it's optional. All that time, a representative sample of questions from all over the network is just a click away.

---

<sup>**Venting box, feel free to ignore**</sup>

<sub>This is one of the most annoying posts here, dancing around "the site" for no apparent reason, which hurts comprehension and readability. Only thing more annoying than that is staff's "(Potential, but probably not given the anger) customer is always right" attitude on Twitter, with no intention to defend or at least explain the controversial titles in picture.</sub>

---

Answer (score 8):

One easy solution would be to give out a "nominate as great question" privilege at a certain amount of rep and/or tag participation. Something that works similarly to close votes, but instead in a positive way. With enough such votes, the question would then go to a pool of candidates that may eventually get their moment of fame in the HNQ.

That way we would pick questions based on content rather than the title. Moderation and appropriateness would already be handled by the privileged users prior to nomination, polished with edits if needed.

If this means we end up with questions that have more/less "click baitiness" appeal, or with questions which titles might appear weird out of context... then so be it! The spirit of the SE communities is that we *only* care about the quality of the post content.

Comment: I like this option, because it would also have the side-effect of having an easily-accessible list of the site's "gems".  This would help users new to the site to easily get an idea of what constitutes a great question on that particular site.

Answer (score 7):

Since HNQ is there to promote sites, *not* to attract attention to a particular question, I would suggest to:

- automatically protect the question once it goes HNQ. Presumably, it already received several good answers, so there's little chance that another answer from someone seeing the site for the first time will make a difference.
- ideally, also protect it from (up)-voting by new users. Since newcomers can mostly only upvote, that's what they do, often ignoring the site's quality standards. Even very poor answers (downvoted to a negative score) get their share of upvotes, making posting them worthwhile.

As I see it, "promoting" a site means that newcomers get to know what the site is about, then decide to contribute **where their contribution is needed**, which would be asking a new question or answering a recent unanswered question, not heating up the HNQ entry. That's what we should encourage them to do. Additionally, breaking the positive feedback loop (more popularity - more answers and upvotes - more popularity) should help with making controversial questions manageable.

Comment: I don't see how this solves the problem of HNQs giving potentially skewed images of the site.

Comment: @Chair By preventing the skewed voting pattern inherent to the HNQ, where most users can only vote up. The community would then have a chance to promote better questions which are currently eclipsed by controversial / fun fact / otherwise appealing questions which made it to the HNQ first. Though channelling contributions from new users towards unanswered questions is a more important side effect IMO.

Comment: This is based on the assumption that HNQ are only upvoted because new users upvoted them. I think this is a very bad assumption. Probably the questions that triggered this were upvoted because they were interesting questions to the community. This discussion has nothing to do with the quality of the questions, its about how appropriate they are for the workplace/general public.

Comment: There are plenty of times when the HNQ has attracted experts from outside the community, this would prevent them for answering with their really good answers

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Just going through today's HNQ I see questions where poorly received answers ([1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/118750/32934) [2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/436032/83721) [3](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/469363/124877)) posted by newcomers are still upvoted, giving them a net positive rep. Do you have an example from recent HNQs where a question attracted an expert outside the community?

Comment: @AnderBiguri This assumption is based on simple statistics: new users are much more numerous, and half of them can upvote thanks to the association bonus. Additionally, I observe the results of this behaviour every day (see examples in my comment above). I fail to see a single reason why to assume that those upvotes come from experienced users.

Comment: This https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/15140/8794 would be an example of an expert from the HNQ answering

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh Good find, I take your point. I would note that (1) your example is 8 months old while mine were on HNQ yesterday, so the two effects don't have the same scale; and (2) this answer looks like a fortunate outlier: it's the only contribution from that user in 8 months.

Answer (score 7):

### Initial Response

I know we can't go back and change it, but I think it is important to discuss what should have been done. This absolutely should have been to temporarily remove HNQ from the sidebar, not remove IPS from the HNQ. Ideally, this action should have been taken after a review instead of immediately. The problem, for the most part, was where the information appeared and (as pointed out in the question) the design of HNQ itself. This is the response that would have addressed that issue.

### Going Forward

As a long-time user of the HNQ, I hate to say it, but I'm tempted to say do away with the HNQ completely. That said, there are two main things that I would still like to see that I would lose without the HNQ:

1. I like seeing a summary of useful, fresh questions across the site.
2. I like the publicity sites get--though as pointed out by many, there are problems with the kind of publicity they currently get.

I don't really know how to address either. In regards to #1, I suggest we try different queries on each site to see if we can get a better list. Maybe something like "starred, recent questions"? That might even encourage more people to star.

Also, moderators and/or askers could be granted the ability to temporarily disable the star feature so if the question is controversial or otherwise problematic, it won't hit the list (hopefully). Even that may be too similar to what we have today, or it may break the star feature in some way I'm not thinking of, but I suggest we start thinking of alternatives like this.

In regards to #2, I like finding new sites without having to go to Area 51 or search for them manually. Maybe we could have a random "featured site" spot somewhere?

### In Closing

I just want to say--I don't often get as riled as some with SE's handling of things, but this one really ticked me off. I respect Adam and Tim, but they both responded poorly here. It makes me fear for the future of this site. I'm tempted to say Adam's response seems knee-jerk and Tim's seems coordinated.

If true, the latter fact makes me worry if those doing the coordinating understand what happened here: I get not wanting to make it about IPS, but Adam made it about IPS by responding to the tweet in the way he did. You can see it didn't take long for the answers here to turn to that fact.

Comment: Downvoted as I disagree with "Initial Response: This absolutely should have been to temporarily remove HNQ from the sidebar". I don't think there was a need for any such action. I tend to agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: Agree there are borderlines cases and that after a thorough review it might have been the right decision, but the initial and immediate response did not need to be more than a social media post to the twitter like outlined in [Monica Cellio's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317101/397504). Maybe we just disagree on the word "initial"?

Comment: @JayCe I made some edits to hopefully clear this up.

Answer (score 7):

### **"When in doubt, cut it out."**

-- surgical aphorism

**I propose eliminating the HNQ sidebar entirely** and putting the HNQ somewhere else, possibly a tab on stackexchange.com because:

- It's distracting and doesn't add value to people who are visiting a non-related SE who would just as soon not disappear down a link rabbit hole.
- It is now being manipulated so that so it's not *really* HNQ but "HNQ that we think won't offend anybody."  Best of luck with *that*.
- It takes up screen real estate that could be used for info relevant to the SE that the user is visiting.

Answer (score 6):

I notice a lot of people in various "answers" are suggesting keeping the list collapsed by default for new users. I simply wish to point out that there is a downside to that: it could very well reduce discoverability because the content is no longer in the new users' face.

If our goal is to help smaller sites be noticed, or good questions to be noticed, or anything else about noticing, collapsing the list may have detrimental effects.

I'm not saying it shouldn't be done, but that I do believe this should be factored into suggestions.

Comment: The discoverability of a collapsed-by-default HNQ list isn't very hard to fix. Add something like [the placeholder Watched Tags box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VasdC.png) with text along the lines of "See great questions from some of our other nice sites!", with the added advantage that you can then link directly to a customizing checkbox list that puts the which-sites-do-you-want choice right in front of new users.

Comment: @E.P. My only problem with opting into specific sites is that you might not discover a site you weren't paying attention to is actually interesting. I wouldn't have rated e.g. the Finance site as one of my top interests for hobbyist reading, but sometimes I find Finance questions in HNQ to be educational and relevant to my situation.

Answer (score 6):

I don't see why you want to show "hot" questions.

I think that "hot" means, "this question is currently being answered -- perhaps you'd like to answer it?"

But, unfortunately, displaying "hot" questions apparently means that:

- It's impossible for humans to supervise
- It's computationally expensive to implement, you say
- It attracts answers from new users -- which may be a <strike>curse</strike> mixed blessing, requiring that the question be "protected" (since new users don't know what the site's policies are for what a good answer is).

I'd suggest that, instead, you select and display "good" questions -- i.e. topics where the site's community (users) agree that, "Yes, this is an exemplary topic, a good advertisement for our site."

A selection process could be something like:

1. Select some candidate topics

   - Automatically select candidates e.g. based on votes, date, etc.
   - And/or let the community (users) select (nominate) candidates manually
2. Candidate topics must be approved by a site moderator (this lets a moderator decide that a topic isn't suitable; you could e.g. ask all site moderators to exclude topics related to sexuality)
3. Approved topics are displayed as before.

You might have fewer topics (because it's more work), OTOH the quality will hopefully be higher.

The process would generate a pool of topics which can be displayed on the HQN space, also [re]used as a "Best of *sitename*" for any other advertising purposes -- for new/potential users, for Twitter, and so on...

Do you even need to find new candidate questions every day (which you're doing at the moment, by selecting "hot" questions)? Perhaps instead it's enough to have a pool of a few hundred exemplary questions per site, which might be recycled occasionally. If there were 300 questions per site, for example, you could display (on HNQ) a different question for each day of the year -- and don't necessarily display several questions from the same site at the same time (maybe one good question at a time is enough to advertise each site).

Comment: "I don't see why you want to show "hot" questions." - Pageviews, obviously.

Answer (score 6):

### Weight high-rep users votes more to decide HNQ status

I know this can be a heavier burden to the system, but high-rep users usually know more about what constitutes a good question in their site (after all, their peers voted them up).

How to weight users rep must be tried and tested, but starting with the square-root of their total earned rep might be a good start. This also adds value to reputation.

Conversely, new users and associate bonus-only users votes shouldn't sway a question hotness.

Comment: This is already done, because usually high rep users are the only ones who downvote answers

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh It's not enough. High-rep users upvotes should weight more as well.

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh ah, no, because every Tom, Dick and Harry with an association bonus can upvote, so high-rep users are easily outnumbered.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some of my ideas of how to "improve the HNQ"

Classify the 170 sites with metadata.

Professional, social, volatile topics, academia, etc...

Then have a HNQ list built up for each site depending on "related relevant sites".

IPS would get suggestions from Scifi, Workplace, etc...
Stack Overflow from Server Fault, Software Engineering, Blender, etc...
Academia from Latex, Mathematica, etc...

This way the "hot network questions" are relevant to the visitors of the website and encourage exploring.
Software Engineering could lead to Workplace, Workplace could lead to IPS, IPS could lead to Scifi and that way when people start exploring and return to HNQ on relevant sites would explore more sites.

That way you free up competition space for hot questions by limiting the pool where to gather them from whilst still allowing browsing through the different topics by visiting more sites on the network, whilst making the question/topics also more relevant in my opinion.

I'm not sure if this is doable with the amount of data Stack Exchange processes, or wished, because part of the "exploring" will be harder to jump from one site to a totally new and fresh site. But it might encourage intersite exploration on the smaller sites.

**edit**

I removed the references to NSFW and SFW. Stop focussing on specific small part of my answer please, try to see the broader picture for categorising websites and showing related overlapping websites. And yes, it might be helpful for a person to see a relationship question on how to come out as gay, except if you're a Muslim coder working in a strong Muslim faith company where such things are seriously frowned upon.

For a professional, using a site with such risky questions can pose serious problems if a chief watches over your shoulder.

Comment: How is SciFi relevant to IPS? :o (and conversely)

Comment: @Jenayah I could imagine that they'd have matching tags. Honestly i just blurted out the site names I knew without giving much thought to reality based links

Comment: IPS deals with real-life situations implying consequences, actual problems etc... Whereas SciFi is "a bunch of nerds wasting our life in front of the computer trying to help people we've never met with questions about universes that don't exist" :D ([source](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39865176#39865176))

Comment: Would it even be possible to meaningfully split sites into NSFW and SFW? As [another post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317142/323179) mentions, a surprising number of apparently professional sites have NSFW questions.

Comment: @Laurel generally speaking that might be too broad unless we're taking a site themed rule34-explained or sex-ed. They're just top of the head metadata tags, not to be taken literally. What the actual tags for sites would be would have to be decided after making summaries of sites in keywords and then seeing where the overlaps are.

Comment: I've recently [proposed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317153/287315) something similar but I think much easier to implement and run in a [different answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317153/287315).  What do you think of that proposal?

Comment: "Don't seek nails on low water"  What does that mean?  A search did not provide any help...I'm not sure if this is a mistranslation, a local saying, or something else, but it may make sense to rephrase this.

Comment: it's a dutch proverb, the meaning is Meaning: Being pedantic about small details, nitpicking, getting stuck on one detail ignoring the rest, modified the answer @beska

Comment: One way to build such a graph of SE sites's closeness would be to leverage data made avalaible following [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316997/397504) (ie ratio of questions linking from site X to site Y, etc.)

Comment: @Laurel everything humans can write is offensive to another human (OOC)

Answer (score 5):

I would like to see *some* degree of siloing in HNQ.
First, SE sites are already [sorted](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) into the following categories:

- Technology
- Culture / Recreation
- Life / Arts
- Science
- Professional
- Business

One simple solution would be that on any given site, the HNQ list is filtered to other sites in that category.
However, I think this would reduce the effectiveness of the discovery support goal.

**I propose that each launched site has a mod-team-controlled blacklist of other SE sites which are excluded from the HNQ sidebar on that site.**  I propose this as a blacklist rather than a whitelist so that new sites can be automatically added as they come into being.

As a starting point, I would propose that blacklists would be empty for all sites, except the "Big 3" (SO, Server Fault, Super User) which would show only questions from sites in the "Technology" category.  The links to related questions on the same site might be expanded, and mods can remove sites from the blacklist as they deem fit, probably after some community discussion.

I would also propose that sites in beta do not have such a blacklist as they are in the process of being integrated with other sites in the whole network, and often have less of a full elected mod team.

Also, when a question reaches HNQ, I would really like to see a record of this stored with the question data, like when a question is Tweeted or similar.  It throws off so many metrics so far off that it's impossible to meaningfully do research about what makes a good question without accounting for the HNQ effect.  More on that to come.

From a technical side, I also propose that **instead of caching question titles, the long and expensive query cache only the site identifier and question *number***.  A secondary cache can map question numbers to names and be updated when there is an edit to the question name.  This secondary cache that stores only question names should be large enough to hold all the HNQ questions from that site, all the questions on the common front/load/landing pages, and a few more for buffer.  Then if there's a problematic title, it can be edited and the edited version will propagate pretty quickly to additional user views.

Comment: This smells of elitism, sorting ‘good’ computer sites from ‘bad’ touchy-feely sites. Even the most hardened cynical computer engineer has emotions, relationships and kids. A Q on the HNQ might actually help them understand a personal problem. Why would someone on Server Fault or Super User not be interested in Great Outdoors or Hinduism? Who are "we" to say which site is relevant or not? Which should be blacklisted or not? We have to expand our interests and be more accepting of one another. But if a user really dislikes a site they should be given the option not to see any of its questions.

Comment: [*I propose that each launched site has a mod-team-controlled blacklist of other SE sites which are excluded from the HNQ sidebar on that site.*] It should be based on individual preferences not dictated by nameless external authorities.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Mods are not "nameless external authorities" but elected leaders of their communities. On my [profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/420593/wbt?tab=accounts) you can see that I don't apply labels like 'good' computer sites and 'bad' touchy-feely sites. This whole issue came up *precisely because* somebody visiting a technical site felt offended & unwelcome on seeing questions from non-technical sites, & a SE dev agreed. Giving those decisions to elected community moderators who can lead discussions would be a big improvement over the status quo Twitter-driven SE-dev-led decisions.

Comment: Well, I don't know the name of every community manager or every single elected mod in the 173 sites. It seems to me, we should be discussing whether HNQ is an asset or not. But if we're going to skip that analysis and go straight to the solutions,  I dislike yours. I don't want to be told by anybody what I can see or cannot see.  How does a mod on Physics (for example) know that someone from EL&U is not interested?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The Physics mod doesn't have to know if EL&U readers are interested. The Physics mod just has to decide if Physics readers would benefit from seeing EL&U questions in the sidebar on Physics. S/he can do that by starting and/or listening to community discussions on the Physics meta, excluding a site if the community feels that it takes more than it adds to that site. There appears to be sufficient outrage about non-technical SEs ([not just IPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317142/287315)) to warrant exclusion even before community input; my suggest default satisfies this concern.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Also keep in mind that nobody's telling you what you can and cannot see. The list of HNQs from all sites is prominently featured on the homepage ([stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com)) and under my proposal anybody would be free to go there anytime. In some communities, especially technical communities, attracting and retaining traditionally minority groups can be hard but diversity is important & valuable. Elected mods + community meta discussions are a better way to determine the balance for what should be displayed in their communities than having SE devs make the call.

Answer (score 3):

Showing the hotness score on the question has been suggested as something that would be useful but performance heavy.  Assuming [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/912736/hnq-algorithm) accurately reflects the hotness score, I'm not sure that's true.  It requires the following data:

- Question ID.  Already shown.
- Answer count.  Already shown.
- Question score.  Already shown.
- Average answer score for the top three questions.

  - Individual answer scores on that question.  Already shown when ordered by answer score.
  - Number of answers.  Already shown.
  - Rank.  Easy enough to calculate if you have the answers.  Limits answers to top three by score.
- Question age.

  - Time of question creation.  Already shown.
  - Current time.  Available in ECMAScript.

It also checks post type, but we know the type is question on the question page.

All the rest of this information is already available on the question with the possible exception of average answer score.  We can approximate answer score by calculating the average for just the top three among the answers currently shown.

If the number is expensive to calculate on the back end, it is quite possible to calculate in JavaScript after the page is loaded from information already available on the page.

Only question age is continuously changing.  Updating post scores and answer counts can be done when people vote, answer, or delete answers.  Only the average answer score of the top three is not currently displayed.

#### Summary

What makes a hotness score expensive does not seem to be the data for the question but checking multiple questions at once.  But to show the hotness score on a particular question, you don't need to know the score for other questions.

#### Recommendation

Show hotness score on the question, either calculate on the back end or in JavaScript.  Modify the hotness score calculation if the current one is hard/expensive to calculate in terms of performance.

Comment: I don't know why that query is written the way it is, but it doesn't seem to reflect the true formula, per [How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page and in the sidebar on questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/300411)

Answer (score 2):

We have review queues for questions and answers of dubious quality. The same thing would be good for individual SE sites, where people could review hot questions and decide if they are problematic either for their titles or content, as an advertisement for SE.

***However***, if users were to review this queue on their own site, then they would likely remove from the review queue questions that they felt weren't good quality according to their personal predilections. That's not what we are trying to catch. So I would suggest ***trialling*** two things.

- Firstly, any hot question should be hot-question-flaggable for a set of specified reasons. (Not judged according to whether it is a good question for that site, does it show research etc). HNQ's would get a different flag list.
- Secondly, the reason that site-specific questions might be problematic taken out of context is something that users of that site are less likely to see. They tend to see the inherent usefulness of the question in context, and in the context of their own site. However, users of other SE sites will be able to judge pretty quickly whether certain question titles, or question content might be problematic to a wider non-specialist audience. Because there are a relatively small number of  HNQ's—only a few HNQ's per site—all questions for certain sites that are known to be problematic could enter a review queue to be passed or rejected by high-ish rep users of other sites.

I think that reviewing HNQ questions from different sites would be extremely interesting for most people, as these question tend to be more inherently interesting in the first instance. It would be highly participated in. It would certainly be more interesting than reading hundreds of poor and uninteresting questions that one finds in close-vote queues.

It would also be a good way to introduce a new incentive for getting higher rep on users' own sites. This is because you could raise a new privilege, for say 30,000/40,000 rep users, of being able to review HNQ's for SE-wide sites (not including their own).

If all questions on such sites had to go through ten *pass onto  HNQ* votes, then even if some great questions got eliminated, there would still be an HNQ list of interesting questions for all sites.

Answer (score 2):

HNQ is neat, but I can see why some of the questions might be a little odd in the context of, say, Stack Overflow. And why some Stack Overflow questions might seem a little odd to nonprogrammers too.

So I suggest: Don't display all of the HNQ on each site. Instead, use another expensive query to compute site/pair relation strengths based on question migration and/or shared user records and then display the HNQs from the most related ten sites, for some value of ten. And perhaps offer a per-user option to include all, and perhaps include some extra-bland sites.

Answer (score 1):

I have been a member of Stack Overflow for nearly 5 years, and find the Hot Network Questions to generally provide great knowledge.  Sometimes the knowledge is relevant to my work, and sometimes it is not.  On many occasions, I have seen questions and stack sites which do not capture my interest at all.  As we all know, this is the nature of the feature as it currently stands.

That being said, I have some suggestions about how we can improve the Hot Network Questions feature without outright removal of the feature *and* without the need to hide it by default when someone is visiting a stack site.

**Regarding Non-users/Not Logged In Users**

If a user has found their way to our site, do not make the Hot Network Questions available to them until they log in.  There is no guarantee that a question title from many of the stack sites won't have NSFW content, so this would be the single best way to prevent a Hot Network Question from turning potential users off from the site.

**Regarding Existing Users**

While hiding the Hot Network Questions by default would solve the problem of an out-of-context NSFW question title from appearing upon initial page load, it would still be problematic when the user decides to open the list.  Instead, the better alternative would be to put an *opt-in and opt-out system* in place for users, and, for new users, add it into the account creation process.

From within their profile, users should be presented with the option to opt into the Hot Network Questions feature.  After the user begins the opt-in procedure, they are presented with the list of existing stack sites along with a little description about what that site is about, and should be able to make a decision about which sites they might be interested in seeing additional questions from.  Upon reaching the conclusion of the opt-in process, that user should also be presented with a disclaimer which states that *"some questions may have potentially inappropriate or NSFW titles"*, and they must choose to accept this as a condition of accessing the feature.

After a user has opted into the feature, then the ability to update their list should be available at any time in the future until they decide to opt-out of the feature.  As for when a question *does* have an inappropriate or NSFW title, perhaps an option could be added to the sidebar which allows the user to add the question to a personal block list.

**Regarding the Hot Network Questions Query**

It is stated that making changes to the Hot Network Questions Query (The Query) could prove difficult.  I believe that we do not need to touch The Query for now.  Once a user has selected the stack sites that they would like to view, then use that as a filter for the list returned by the existing query when the user loads the page.  If they don't have any sites selected that appear on the current list, then they do not see any Hot Network Questions.  If only two selected sites are returned by The Query, then the user only sees two.

**Regarding Stack Site Visibility**

I have seen some people disagree with hiding or removing the Hot Network Questions sidebar because it would lower a user's awareness to other stack sites, and they have a point.  Many of the sites I have visited in the past, *including IPS*, I did not know of their existence until I saw them in the Hot Network Questions list.  Since I generally do not tend to explore links on sites, I would never have learned of their existence without this feature.

To alleviate this concern, I think a new feature should be introduced.  I think this feature would be beneficial to all stack sites, and is independent of decisions made to the Hot Network Questions sidebar.  This new feature would be something like *"Other Stack Sites You May Be Interested In"*, and it would present the user with a list of other stack sites.  The query for this feature could be set up in different ways, but, if set up so that sites with less traffic over a set amount of time are preferred, it would bring smaller sites that are unlikely to show in Hot Network Questions into public awareness.

**Regarding Stack Sites Which Do Not Want Hot Network Question Visibility**

While reading other answers, some people mentioned that some stacks may not want to be visible on the Hot Network Questions sidebar.  If the opt-in system is implemented, then administrators of individual stack sites could be given an option to allow or disallow their site to be opted into.

As an aside, if a site has disallowed users from opting in, this could potentially be worked into The Query to exclude these stack sites from the Hot Network Questions analyses and reduce the burden on The Query.

Answer (score 0):

#### HNQ is not so bad. Just tune a little bit that query.

I think the real problem of the most loud HNQ dislikers is that posting answers to HNQ questions is an easy way to get many rep.

My only problem with the HNQ is that they are mostly not so good questions.

But you could easily solve this problem, simply refresh the list more often.

Simply tune the algorithm, too. For example, having a low upvote/visit ratio should be a *strong* signature that a question is a bikeshed.

But it was only a single example. What you could most ideally do, is if you would utilize some machine learning to fine-tune the fixed parameters of the HNQ query. You have data scientists there, in the company, and I think it wouldn't be a very big work for them.

---

For example, what I can see in the image of your example:

- Latex SE, "Use counters...": good question, might not worth the HNQ upvotes but it is obviously a good one
- Physics SE, "Conservation of...": very good question (was already renamed)
- Music SE, I don't know, it is not my field
- two Workplace SE questions: they are bikesheds
- Politics SE, "Why is Elizabeth"... Particularly evil bikeshedding, it utilizes political sensitivity to attract visitors and votes. It should be voted down, deleted and sown with salt.
- Electronics SE, "What kind of socket". Clearly on-topic and interesting, might be disliked by the Electronics SE community on cloudy reasons. Also this has a significant bikeshed taste.
- Another MusicSE, I don't know
- Film SE, "Did Neil Armstrong...". Particularly disgusting clickbait, just like the PolSE above. It is also likely off-topic.
- MathSE, "How to tell if order matters..." Another disgusting, LQ clickbait.
- ELL SE, "Is it ok to say..." I don't know, I think it is not so bad, but probably doesn't worth a HNQ.

I am sure that you can do it better. Have a clear concept and follow it.

[image]

Comment: Some people in the industry try to pretend that data science is magical fairy dust that makes all problems go away; the folks who are gullible enough to fall for that are in for a sharp disappointment when they find out it's not. OP explicitly sets performance (on the extremely simple formula currently in use) as a limiting factor - how would adding in a ton of ultra-expensive processing help?

Comment: @E.P. No, it is not fairy dust, it is only the future of the IT. The future is not magic dust. Your argument would be strong, if I would see an SE fighting to tune its AI algorithms; but not this is what I can see. I see an SE using *exclusively* primitive algorithms and elementary school math. I can't name a single, for us visible feature of the software where they would use anything more intelligent. *Never.* And yes, it is enough in many cases, but not now. About the speed: the algorithm doing the real-time calculation can be much faster, if its fixed parameters aren't hardcoded, as always,

Comment: @E.P. everything is hardcoded in the SE software, but they are optimized off-line with machine learning. Furthermore, nothing makes for the SE obligatory to use that MSSQL everywhere. You know the SEDE, you have some queries, not even trivial ones, I think you know its limits well. But you know also the search function, which uses elastic search. Using some *different than MS-SQL* is not unheard even on the SE.

Answer (score -4):

I like HNQ as it is, quite a lot. ***EXCEPT*** for the damned spoilers coming from Movies and TV. What I would want to do with this thing is either choose a list of sites that are allowed in my HNQ, or at least a blacklist of ones that are not.

However, I recognize that this does not address the performance issues you're talking about.

So in the future, I'd like to see something that functions in a similar way: highlighting "interesting" content from across the network. It has that "get lost on Wikipedia" feeling. But I want some amount of control over what can come up in it.

As a developer myself, that does sound like a lot to ask for. But I'm asking for it anyway. :)

Comment: I wanted to post something along those lines, but what kept me off is the "_my_ HNQ". While I'm all for customizing my HNQ (goodbye, tags I really don't care about), it wouldn't work for logged-out users, which I guess represnt a lot of traffic too, and the base problem for "aw bummer, there's NSFW content on the right, visible by every coworker peeking above my shoulder" issue.

Comment: The performance issues can be addressed client-side if it's simply unfeasible to do on the server (which I find doubtful: the page already filters on user tags; another filter within a selection of 5-30 links is unlikely to add that much processing time); if done correctly the client-side overhead will be extremely minimal.

Answer (score -6):

### Prevent reputation abuse: If we let communities choose posts for the HNQ, maintain an element of automation in the selection process

Questions on the HNQ list get a lot of views and therefore a (usually) disparate number of *votes* compared to other questions on the site. Giving a site's users (or worse, only a subset of a their users) the ability to decide which of their site's questions are on the list, **we invite abuse of the reputation-generating effects of the HNQ.**

Keeping the selection process in the hands of an algorithm prevents this from happening. While it may be desirable/necessary to give communities the ability to select questions for inclusion on the HNQ, I believe we must maintain an element of automation for the purpose of mitigating abuse of the reputation HNQ questions inevitably gain.

Comment: That...is a problem of how the HNQ (indirectly) works. Solving it by refusing users control of it isn't the solution, fixing the HNQ is. Part of this might be just toning down that heavy reputation-skewing effect instead. This would also have other advantages, like not having users gain close-voting privileges after posting just a single question, something that e.g. IPS is genuinely struggling with.

Comment: @ChristianRau To clarify I'm *not* advocating that we deny users control of the HNQ, but specifically the process that gets questions on the list. I'm all for giving us the ability to *remove* questions.

Comment: Users *don't* self-select posts for the HNQ, do we? I thought HNQ selection was already algorithm-based. Or is your answer proposing to *keep* the status quo?

Comment: Ah, that makes a little more sense.

Comment: @Lawrence You're correct. But since everything's up for discussion, I want to draw attention to the reputation consequences of being able to pick which questions appear on the HNQ.

Comment: @Lawrence You're right. The answer is concerned about a possible *future* change of the HNQ system, though, and tries to prevent it going in this direction.

Comment: I don't understand what changes you're actually proposing. Could you be more specific in your post?

Comment: @E.P. See edit and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Not at all. I still have no idea what you're proposing. Are you proposing that the selection be done by "an algorithm"? Which algorithm? What would be its selection to the algorithm that's currently running? What data would that algorithm use, and what would be the relationship of that data to the site's userbase?

Comment: @E.P. The selection **is** currently done exclusively by an algorithm. At least one other answer purpose proposes [allowing a community to select questions for the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316948/271445). If this were granted, I'm concerned it would invite abuse for reputation gain, therefore, whatever changes get made, I'm advocating that an algorithm still be used in the selection process.

Comment: I visited and re-read the answer you referred because I generally dislike the approach of letting users "feature" questions to HNQ. And yeah, I didn't feel any urge to support it and it didn't look appealing to me. But frankly, what is proposed over there still looks better than current "fully automated" (and totally braindead) algorithm that allows a handful of clueless passers-by from Stack Overflow (armed with [bonus rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238420)) force network-wide advertising of any troll-bait that just didn't yet manage to get 5 close votes from smaller site regulars...

Comment: ...I recall a wile ago there was an [experiment](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week) at SE.SE meta that had an effect somewhat similar to proposed featuring in that it pushed many involved questions into HNQ. And while I wasn't entirely happy about that, it still felt so much better compared to current "fully automated", "100% unbiased", "clean algorithmic" way. Guess I would probably prefer automated / algorithmic way if it was not as brainless. But compared to what we have now even manual featuring looks better

Comment: To be fair, it's not even _that_ hard to predict the HNQ effect on sites you're active in.  I essentially "gamed" my top answer because while reading the question, and seeing it had gotten several votes quickly, I knew it was very likely to show up on HNQ.  It wasn't really abuse; but even without sites being able to pick their own, it's usually fairly apparent which type of questions are worth investing time in if the goal is to get easy reputation.

Answer (score -11):

On and on we go about HNQ again.

There are two sites that really need to be banned from HNQ altogether.

1) Interpersonal. The exact reason given in the question is good enough. Mostly the salacious questions end up on HNQ.

2) Skeptics. The site rule at skeptics.stackexchange.com about the level of backing of answers that is required would be overthrown if everybody coming over from HNQ voted on it. I have heard the repeated complaints of the moderators over every time there's a particularly hot question this fight breaks out again.

Comment: Welcome to me being controversial. This post is negative but I got positive rep anyway.

Comment: "The exact reason given in the question is good enough." - to me this reads more conformist than controversial. With regards to the question, 200 votes down I observe on it (as of now) may possibly somehow influence score of this answer which refers it to justify IPS ban

Comment: @gnat: This is the more like the tenth time. That one got voted down (probably due to the meta effect) but the others didn't.