# Should Stack Exchange hire someone to deal with off-platform interactions?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange

Sadly, SE doesn't have anymore the list of all their paid employees, so I can't verify that there is someone dedicated to this. Yet the recent events on off platform venues and the response of SE as company seems to be that there isn't a real coordination on the public off platform face of the company.

SE seems to have a very large team of community managers, but these are usually dedicated to manage SE own community, but no one to manage the communities that interact with SE outside of SE. This seems to be an oversight. [The current list of open positions](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) focus on the engineering and product selling aspects of SE. But this aspect of the business, the one that has to deal with off platform interactions, seems to be fallen into whoever employee happens to see and be able to respond to those.

Sometimes you have to deal with clients that don't really use the site as more engaged individuals nor pay for its use. Lets be serious and get someone to be a measured and corporate face to people that isn't the core clients.

This person should have close relationships with SE CM's. corporate, devs and sales/marketing. Remember this would be a person to represent the company to those outside of it, and having uncoordinated messages at all these levels was the thing this person is set to solve

Comment: I've seen tweets from employees who clearly have a twisted vision of what Stack Overflow is, when compared to the vision of its core users. A fixed position for off-site communications might indeed prevent certain inconsistencies (not so sure about preventing 1-hour-after feature requests, though).

Comment: @E_net4 You mean 0-day patchs?

Comment: Aye, you know what I meant. :)

Comment: What if the answer to your title is yes? Why do you think company policy and recruitment of staff is steered by Meta? Who (or at least the upvoters) do we think we are?

Comment: There is a public list of SE employees *somewhere else*... but it only lists the user accounts on MSE (doesn't really help since some of their "About Me"s are empty).

Comment: @rene I expect SE at least consider the option that maybe they are ill-equipped to deal with their image outside of the network. We can tell them that.

Comment: I thought that Jay Hanlon's blog post (heralding the golden age of madness) meant that they were exactly this person.

Comment: @AndrasDeak that they are filling the role, doesn't mean he's equipped to deal with the tasks that needs to be done.

Comment: Come to think of it, the company seems perfectly apt at responding to off-platform stimuli in a timely and extreme manner. So what we _really_ need is someone who will deal with what the _community_ is trying to say...

Comment: They dont need to talk on twitter if request are listened on there, so I would hire dev, and twitter drama will fall IMO

Comment: @AndrasDeak I think the kind of response leave more to be desired.

Comment: Anyway, this is part of the bigger request/discussion, closed as duplicate.

Comment: @ShadowWizard no. It's not part of a bigger issue. You can't have sensate policies if you don't have someone that, well, can tell you what the policies should look like. This should happen before SE even start thinking about creating policies.

Comment: They should hire Monica for this... (though I suspect she wouldn't take the job)