# Has anything been done to improve HNQ since October 2018?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

Refering to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316934/revisiting-the-hot-network-questions-feature-what-are-our-shared-goals-for-ha)

I and probably many people are not happy with the state of HNQ, and I personally wonder if, and if not, why there is nothing done about it.
My personal 3 most disliked features of HNQ are those:

- Imbalance of featured sites

Out of the 20-something HNQ question displays, I get WAY too many RPG, Code Golf, Puzzle or Travel questions, of which

- Most are irrelevant to **me**!

Seriously - we live in 2019, why can't we customize this awesome feature to our liking? I could spend HOURS browsing those questions, but I'm currently limited by the lack of

- Refreshing

No, I don't want to see the 16242nd question about code golf. If you can't let me hide ALL code golf posts, why aren't questions that I have ignored for days hidden? It's a sad moment when you're having fun browsing the network and then all of the HNQ posts are already old ones - why not have some shuffling?

I hope this isn't a repost, I checked but you never know.
Thanks in advance, also hoping for some other opinions!

Comment: For what it's worth, as a workaround a custom CSS file can easily block the specific sites that you don't want to see, or even the whole list.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Quick, someone make a userscript!

Answer (score 8):

As you well know, nothing has been done yet.

Instead of putting a patch here and a patch there, SE has decided to revamp the whole thing. As far as I can tell, they are currently planning the "next generation" of the Hot Network Questions, which might also mean removing it completely.

As Tim said:

> Suffice to say, the HNQ (as we know it) is now looking at numbered days, but that number is probably kind of high because it's going to take some work to figure out what voids would be worth filling if we yanked it as we know it now.

365 days is also an option, so I'll wait until October 2019 before starting to worry they forgot about it.

Comment: Ah, i didnt knew that something like this is planned, i didnt expect time to be a factor since the topic is being discussed for a long time now

Comment: @FlyingThunder eh, it's from the question you linked to.

Comment: 6-8 months, years, decades, but they're *working on it.*

Comment: @FlyingThunder Of course it's a known and discussed problem for years, but SE only woke up to the problem and that it needs to be worked on in October. Unless you mean *that* is already a long time, which...wouldn't be too unjustified either, I guess.