# Please don't let Stack Exchange die

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, moderation, moderators

With the recent flow of moderator resignations, I am quite worried. I have no right to be as I myself have made a couple of trash questions in the past, but I just feel like a lot of people have a strong connection with the SE family. Stack Overflow, Super User and Unix/Linux SE have helped me out so much. Trashy newspaper guides won't replace any of them. SE is not only a QA site; it brings people together. What other forum about **aviation** will you find? Where will you ask programming questions without the warmth of Stack Overflow? I don't know how, but I won't let it all just become a wasteland. SE is than Quora 2. We apologise for all the poor quality contributions recently, mods. We will do modding of our questions before we submit them.

How do you feel about the situation? 
If you are a moderator, how do **you** feel?

Comment: Long standing users who previously curated trash questions by closing, editing or whatever, are seen to be toxic and hence it all needs to be shutdown

Comment: You're being downvoted because this issue has relatively little to do with poor quality questions (those are perennial!) and everything to do with the way the company has treated its moderators, veteran contributors, and staff. If it makes you feel better, you couldtry writing an email to SE executive management. About the only people they seem to care about are newer users (well and likely future shareholders, as well)

Comment: I love SE and it's community, being said that, sometimes things have to go away for new better things to come, whether that means SE reborn, or a new site is born, only time will tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a moderator, and engaged user, I worry that you may be viewing Stack Exchange sites as:

- forums rather than focused Q&A sites; and/or
- social networks

My understanding is that the company and communities that designed and developed these sites have always wanted them to be very distinct from both of those things.

That is a large part of why I think they have worked so well and why I use them to find answers to questions, often instantly.

Answer (score 9):

Don't take this personally.

This isn't about *you*, or any other asker.

This is a long-running issue with thorny and overt implications on how we can cleanly interact with the company.  I consider myself to be quite optimistic on a lot of these things, but even on its face there [there are a *lot* of decisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316934/175248) made [without what I'd consider to be adequate time to get, digest and act on feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373160/1079354).  Sorry that you have to see our dirty laundry aired out like this.

At a minimum...I can assure you that Stack Overflow isn't going to *die* anytime soon.  Stack Overflow has a wealth of knowledge and is still **the** place people land on when Googling a programming question.  *That* much isn't going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: If anything survives, then Stack Overflow. But I'm afraid that's not enough for a lot of people (albeit comparatively not *that* many people, which is kinda the problem).